# Splitting a list based on another list values in Mathematica

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica

In Mathematica I have a list of point coordinates

```
size = 50;
points = Table[{RandomInteger[{0, size}], RandomInteger[{0, size}]}, {i, 1, n}];
```

and a list of cluster indices these points belong to

```
clusterIndices = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
```

what is the easiest way to split the points into two separate lists based on the clusterIndices values?

EDIT:
The solution I came up with:

```
pointIndices =
  Map[#[[2]] &,
    GatherBy[MapIndexed[{#1, #2[[1]]} &, clusterIndices], First],
    {2}];
pointsByCluster = Map[Part[points, #] &, pointIndices];
```

It there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
points[[
    Flatten[Position[clusterIndices, #]]
    ]] & /@
 Union[clusterIndices]
```

Comment: Interesting, what made you think of this?

Comment: Dunno. I use this kind of thing often (position lists to extract what I want).

Comment: Insteresting and very different from what others suggest.Thanks

Comment: I suspect that the sort (implicit in `Union`) and the number of list traversals (via both `Position` and `Part`) would cause this to be rather inefficient.  However, for a short list, it is definitely an interesting use of `Position`.

Answer (score 5):

As @High Performance Mark and @Nicholas Wilson said, I'd start with combining the two lists together via `Transpose` or `Thread`.  In this case,

```
In[1]:= Transpose[{clusterIndices, points}]==Thread[{clusterIndices, points}]
Out[1]:= True
```

At one point, I looked at which was faster, and I think `Thread` is marginally faster. But, it only really matters when you are using very long lists.

@High Performance Mark makes a good point in suggesting `Select`.  But, it would only allow you to pull a single cluster out at a time.  The code for selecting cluster 1 is as follows:

```
Select[Transpose[{clusterIndices, points}], #[[1]]==1& ][[All, All, 2]]
```

Since you seem to want to generate all clusters, I'd suggest doing the following:

```
GatherBy[Transpose[{clusterIndices, points}], #[[1]]& ][[All, All, 2]]
```

which has the advantage of being a one liner and the only tricky part was in selecting the correct `Part` of the resulting list.  The trick in determining how many `All` terms are necessary is to note that

```
Transpose[{clusterIndices, points}][[All,2]]
```

is required to get the points back out of the transposed list.  But, the "clustered" list has one additional level, hence the second `All`.

It should be noted that the second parameter in `GatherBy` is a function that accepts one parameter, and it can be interchanged with any function you wish to use.  As such, it is very useful.  However, if you'd like to transform your data as your gathering it, I'd look at `Reap` and `Sow`.

**Edit:**  `Reap` and `Sow` are somewhat under used, and fairly powerful.  They're somewhat confusing to use, but I suspect `GatherBy` is implemented using them internally.  For instance,

```
Reap[ Sow[#[[2]], #[[1]] ]& /@ Transpose[{clusterIndices, points}], _, #2& ]
```

does the same thing as my previous code without the hassle of stripping off the indices from the points.  Essentially, `Sow` tags each point with its index, then Reap gathers all of the tags (`_` for the 2nd parameter) and outputs only the points.  Personally, I use this instead of GatherBy, and I've encoded it into a function which I load, as follows:

```
SelectEquivalents[x_List,f_:Identity, g_:Identity, h_:(#2&)]:=
   Reap[Sow[g[#],{f[#]}]&/@x, _, h][[2]];
```

Note: this code is a modified form of what was in the help files in 5.x.  But, the 6.0 and 7.0 help files removed a lot of the useful examples, and this was one of them.

Comment: +1 This is a much better answer than @Mark Fisher's, and a couple of the others.  I'd throw in @Michael Pilat's suggestion of SplitBy too.

Comment: Very detailed explanations.Thanks!

Comment: @Max: you're welcome.  Another advantage of `Reap` and `Sow`, is that you can `Sow` multiple tags, i.e. if your datum fits into multiple categories, you can group your data as such.  To do this, remove the curly braces around `f` in `SelectEquivalents` and have `f` return a list of the tags that the datum falls into.

Comment: To the person who down voted this, why? It is common courtesy to let the person know what about the answer warrants the down vote. Any one going to own up to this?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a succinct way to do this using the new `SplitBy` function in version 7.0 that should be pretty fast:

```
SplitBy[Transpose[{points, clusterIndices}], Last][[All, All, 1]]
```

If you aren't using 7.0, you can implement this as:

```
Split[Transpose[{points, clusterIndices}], Last[#]==Last[#2]& ][[All, All, 1]]
```

### Update

Sorry, I didn't see that you only wanted two groups, which I think of as clustering, not splitting. Here's some code for that:

```
FindClusters[Thread[Rule[clusterIndices, points]]]
```

Comment: There were a lot of list utilities, like this one, that were added in 7.0 that I've never used due to my reliance on `Reap` and `Sow`.  But, this is a good one that I'll have to remember.

Comment: At first I've tried to use SplitBy myself, but this doesn't work. Try to execute SplitBy[{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2 }] and you will get  {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}} with the length of 4, while I have only two clusters and it need to be 2.

Comment: You still have the problem of clusterIndices = {2,1,...}. A sort is needed to be safe and ensure that the first gathered list represents the first cluster index.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood that you wanted clustering vs. splitting based on the list into smaller clusters at the transition points. Answer updated for doing that too...

Comment: Or yes, you could use `GatherBy`, but `FindClusters` is probably faster.

Comment: +1 For most legible answer, although the Reap Sow method is much more interesting.

Comment: +1, for illustrating two things about v 7.0 I did not know.  `FindClusters` is definitely an interesting answer.  But, looking through the docs, it may cluster indices that are too similar to each other, as the examples under both the `DistanceFunction` and `Method` options illustrates in help.  That is not to say it is not useful, and it works fine in this case. But, you have to be judicious in its use.

Comment: @Nicholas: a sort is only necessary if he is using more than 2 indices.  With only 2 indices, all he has to do is look at the first index to determine the order in which they will appear.  Alternatively, if he uses `Reap` and `Sow`, he can use `{#1, #2}&` for the third param in `Reap`.  Then the first element of the list is the index, and all of the points for that index are in the second element.  If they are then needed in a specific order, they can then be sorted much more quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about 'better', but the more usual way in functional languages would not be to add indices to label each element (your MapIndexed) but instead to just run along each list:

```
Map[#1[[2]] &, 
 Sort[GatherBy[
   Thread[ {#1, #2} &[clusterIndices, points]],
   #1[[1]] &], #1[[1]][[1]] < #2[[1]][[1]] &], {2}]
```

Most people brought up in Lisp/ML/etc will write the `Thread` function out instantly is the way to implement the zip ideas from those languages.

I added in the `Sort` because it looks like your implementation will run into trouble if `clusterIndices = {2[...,2],1,...}`. On the other hand, I would still need to add in a line to fix the problem that if clusterIndices has a 3 but no 2, the output indices will be wrong. It is not clear from your fragment how you are intending to retrieve things though.

I reckon you will find list processing much easier if you refresh yourself with a hobby  project like building a simple CAS in a language like Haskell where the syntax is so much more suited to functional list processing than Mathematica.

Comment: The part where you combine the two lists can be simplified to `Thread[{clusterindices, points}]`, as the pure function portion (`{#1, #2}`) is just wasted key strokes in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If I think of something simpler I will add to the post.

```
Map[#[[1]] &, GatherBy[Thread[{points, clusterIndices}], #[[2]] &], {2}]
```

Answer (score 1):

My first step would be to execute

```
Transpose[{clusterIndices, points}]
```

and my next step would depend on what you want to do with that; `Select` comes to mind.