# What is in your Mathematica tool bag?

Tags: resources, wolfram-mathematica

We all know that Mathematica is great, but it also often lacks critical functionality. What kind of external packages / tools / resources do you use with Mathematica?

I'll edit (and invite anyone else to do so too) this main post to include resources which are focused on general applicability in scientific research and which as many people as possible will find useful. Feel free to contribute anything, even small code snippets (as I did below for a timing routine).

Also, undocumented and useful features in Mathematica 7 and beyond you found yourself, or dug up from some paper/site are most welcome.

Please include a short description or comment on why something is great or what utility it provides. If you link to books on Amazon with affiliate links please mention it, e.g., by putting your name after the link.

---

**Packages:**

1. [`LevelScheme`](http://scidraw.nd.edu/levelscheme/) is a package that greatly expands Mathematica's capability to produce good looking plots. I use it if not for anything else then for the much, much improved control over frame/axes ticks. Its newest version is called SciDraw, and it will be released sometime this year.
2. David Park's [`Presentation Package`](http://home.comcast.net/~djmpark/DrawGraphicsPage.html) (US$50 - no charge for updates)
3. Jeremy Michelson's [`grassmannOps`](http://www.physics.ohio-state.edu/~jeremy/mathematica/grassmannOps/) package provides resources for doing algebra and calculus with Grassmann variables and operators that have non trivial commutation relations.
4. John Brown's [`GrassmannAlgebra`](http://sites.google.com/site/grassmannalgebra/) package and book for working with Grassmann and Clifford algebras.
5. [RISC (Research Institute for Symbolic Computation)](http://www.risc.jku.at/) has a variety of packages for Mathematica (and other languages) available for download. In particular, there is [Theorema](http://www.risc.jku.at/research/theorema/software/) for automated theorem proving, and the multitude of packages for symbolic summation, difference equations, etc. at the [Algorithmic Combinatorics group's software page](http://www.risc.jku.at/research/combinat/risc/software/).

**Tools:**

1. [`MASH`](http://ai.eecs.umich.edu/people/dreeves/mash/) is Daniel Reeves's excellent [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) script essentially providing scripting support for Mathematica v7. (Now built in as of Mathematica 8 with the `-script` option.)
2. An [`alternate Mathematica shell`](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/363500-mathematica-with-a-gnu-readline-input/) with a GNU readline input (using python, *nix only)
3. ColourMaths package allows you to visually select parts of an expression and manipulate them. http://www.dbaileyconsultancy.co.uk/colour_maths/colour_maths.html

**Resources:**

1. Wolfram's own repository [`MathSource`](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/) has a lot of useful if narrow notebooks for various applications. Also check out the other sections such as

   - [`Current Documentation`](http://reference.wolfram.com),
   - [`Courseware`](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Courseware/) for lectures,
   - and [`Demos`](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/) for, well, demos.
2. The [Mathematica Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Mathematica).

**Books:**

1. *Mathematica programming: an advanced introduction* by Leonid Shifrin ([`web`](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/), [`pdf`](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/download/MathProgrammingIntro.pdf)) is a must read if you want to do anything more than *For* loops in Mathematica. We have the pleasure of having [`Leonid`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/565518/leonid-shifrin) himself answering questions here.
2. *Quantum Methods with Mathematica* by James F. Feagin ([amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387953655))
3. *The Mathematica Book* by Stephen Wolfram ([amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521643147)) ([`web`](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/))
4. *Schaum's Outline* ([amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071608281))
5. *Mathematica in Action* by Stan Wagon ([amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387753664)) - 600 pages of neat examples and goes up to Mathematica version 7. Visualization techniques are especially good, you can see some of them on the author's [`Demonstrations Page`](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/author.html?author=Stan+Wagon).
6. *Mathematica Programming Fundamentals* by Richard Gaylord ([`pdf`](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5216/ProgrammingFundamentals.pdf)) - A good concise introduction to most of what you need to know about Mathematica programming.
7. Mathematica Cookbook by Sal Mangano published by O'Reilly 2010 832 pages. - Written in the well known O'Reilly Cookbook style: Problem - Solution. For intermediates.
8. Differential Equations with  Mathematica, 3rd Ed. Elsevier 2004 Amsterdam
   by Martha L. Abell, James P. Braselton - 893 pages For beginners, learn solving DEs and Mathematica at the same time.

**Undocumented (or scarcely documented) features:**

7. How to customize Mathematica keyboard shortcuts. See [`this question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209405/customizing-mathematica-shortcuts).
8. How to inspect patterns and functions used by Mathematica's own functions. See [`this answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091728/tips-for-creating-graph-diagrams/4092955#4092955)
9. How to achieve consistent size for GraphPlots in Mathematica? See [`this question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230823/consistent-size-for-graphplots).
10. How to produce documents and presentations with Mathematica. See [`this question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058854/using-mathematica-to-build-presentations-and-documents).

Comment: I find David Park's Presentation package invaluable and well worth the fifty dollars (and he does not charge for updates, which appear at regular invtervals). home.comcast.net/~djmpark/

Comment: Mathematica 8 is out with much better shell script integration. http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-8/mathematica-shell-scripts/

Comment: +1, for LevelScheme.  Its a little slow, sometimes. But, it has a sane method for creating tick marks, and it is much easier to create journal worthy layouts for graphics then `Grid`, or anything like it.

Comment: Wow, I just watched the mma8 promo videos. Impressive! Sadly not available for download yet.

Comment: @beisarius Excellent idea to collect those here as well

Comment: One other benefit to using LevelScheme: its functionality for generating tick marks is extremely powerful and easy to use. It is much simpler than what Mathematica provides by default.

Comment: @rcollyer> yup, before LevelScheme I used to use CorelDraw to manually change ticks...

Comment: As proposed by Alexey in the comments on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152551/how-to-close-initialization-cell-in-notebook, I proposed the tag rename for Mathematica here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81152/retag-mathematica-to-wr-mathematica-or-something-similar. Please take a look and upvote if you agree. I post it here because this question has a lot of favorites in the Mma community here.

Comment: All, this question really should be community wiki for all of the usual reasons: it has no correct answer and it is more of a list than anything else. I apologize to all who have profited handsomely in reputation off of this question.

Comment: Any word on the progress of Part 2 of Leonid's _Mathematica Programming_?

Comment: @casperOne, while not as old as the [freely available programming books](http://stackoverflow.com/q/194812/), it does have historical significance to the mathematica community here on SO. Instead of closing it, can we have it locked, instead?

Comment: @rcollyer Unfortunately, no, this is not a candidate for locking, as it is [information that should really be contained in the tag wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112910/do-not-lock-old-questions) if you deem it is that important.  Note that this post has many of the attributes in the cited meta post.  Also note that none of this prevents people from reopening as well as reflagging as NC when it is open, so please, cast votes wisely on this matter.

Comment: @Andrew MacFie I am working on it, but rather slowly alas - was quite busy at work recently (and also here at SO). I hope to get some more time on my hands soon. Meanwhile, I'd recommend to read through some past questions and answers here at SO Mathematica tag - those can also be quite an interesting read.

Comment: These answers to this question are constructive, it should be reopened.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I've mentioned [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695182/splitting-a-list-based-on-another-list-values-in-mathematica/2698832#2698832) before, but the tool I find most useful is an application of `Reap` and `Sow` which mimics/extends the behavior of `GatherBy`:

```scala
SelectEquivalents[x_List,f_:Identity, g_:Identity, h_:(#2&)]:=
   Reap[Sow[g[#],{f[#]}]&/@x, _, h][[2]];
```

This allows me to group lists by any criteria and transform them in the process.  The way it works is that a criteria function (`f`) tags each item in the list, each item is then transformed by a second supplied function (`g`), and the specific output is controlled by a third function (`h`).  The function `h` accepts two arguments:  a tag and a list of the collected items that have that tag. The items retain their original order, so if you set `h = #1&` then you get an unsorted `Union`, like in the [examples](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reap.html?q=Reap&lang=en) for `Reap`.  But, it can be used for secondary processing.

As an example of its utility, I've been working with [Wannier90](http://www.wannier.org/) which outputs the spatially dependent Hamiltonian into a file where each line is a different element in the matrix, as follows

```scala
rx ry rz i j Re[Hij] Im[Hij]
```

To turn that list into a set of matrices, I gathered up all sublists that contain the same coordinate, turned the element information into a rule (i.e. {i,j}-> Re[Hij]+I Im[Hij]), and then turned the collected rules into a `SparseArray` all with the one liner:

```scala
SelectEquivalents[hamlst, 
      #[[;; 3]] &, 
      #[[{4, 5}]] -> (Complex @@ #[[6 ;;]]) &, 
      {#1, SparseArray[#2]} &]
```

Honestly, this is my Swiss Army Knife, and it makes complex things very simple.  Most of my other tools are somewhat domain specific, so I'll probably not post them.  However, most, if not all, of them reference `SelectEquivalents`.

**Edit**: it doesn't completely mimic [`GatherBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GatherBy.html?q=GatherBy&lang=en) in that it cannot group multiple levels of the expression as simply as `GatherBy` can.  However, `Map` works just fine for most of what I need.

**Example**: @Yaroslav Bulatov has asked for a self-contained example.  Here's one from my research that has been greatly simplified.  So, let's say we have a set of points in a plane

```scala
In[1] := pts = {{-1, -1, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}, {0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, 
 {0, 1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}
```

and we'd like to reduce the number of points by a set of symmetry operations.  (For the curious, we are generating the [little group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_group#Orbits_and_stabilizers) of each point.)  For this example, let's use a four fold rotation axis about the z-axis

```scala
In[2] := rots = RotationTransform[#, {0, 0, 1}] & /@ (Pi/2 Range[0, 3]);
```

Using `SelectEquivalents` we can group the points that produce the same set of images under these operations, i.e. they're equivalent, using the following

```scala
In[3] := SelectEquivalents[ pts, Union[Through[rots[#] ] ]& ] (*<-- Note Union*)
Out[3]:= {{{-1, -1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}},
          {{-1, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}},
          {{0,0,0}}}
```

which produces 3 sublists containing the equivalent points.  (Note, `Union` is absolutely vital here as it ensures that the same image is produced by each point.  Originally, I used `Sort`, but if a point lies on a symmetry axis, it is invariant under the rotation about that axis giving an extra image of itself. So, `Union` eliminates these extra images. Also, `GatherBy` would produce the same result.)  In this case, the points are already in a form that I will use, but I only need a representative point from each grouping and I'd like a count of the equivalent points.  Since, I don't need to transform each point, I use the `Identity` function in the second position.  For the third function, we need to be careful.  The first argument passed to it will be the images of the points under the rotations which for the point `{0,0,0}` is a list of four identical elements, and using it would throw off the count.  However, the second argument is just a list of all the elements that have that tag, so it will only contain `{0,0,0}`.  In code,

```scala
In[4] := SelectEquivalents[pts,  
             Union[Through[rots[#]]]&, #&, {#2[[1]], Length[#2]}& ]
Out[4]:= {{{-1, -1, 0}, 4}, {{-1, 0, 0}, 4}, {{0, 0, 0}, 1}}
```

Note, this last step can just as easily be accomplished by

```scala
In[5] := {#[[1]], Length[#]}& /@ Out[3]
```

But, it is easy with this and the less complete example above to see how very complex transformations are possible with a minimum of code.

Comment: _The original Fortran77 code was restructured on Thanksgiving Day 1996, and hence for many years known as turkey.f_  ... :D Very nice graphics BTW. Remembered me the Falicov's monster ...

Comment: @belisarius, I hadn't read the history, that's funny.  I've just started using Wannier90, but it is some of the best organized and well written `Fortran` code I've seen.  Makes me almost consider using `Fortran` ...

Comment: I wonder if you could add a self-contained example of SelectEquivalents in action

Comment: @Yaroslav Bulatov, added an example, per request.  Let me know if this helps.  If it doesn't, we'll see what we can do.

Comment: You get the checkmark to this "question" for the most interesting code snippet contribution.

Comment: Just for the record: [Falicov's monster](http://cabbib2.cnea.gov.ar/fali/monstruo.htm)

Comment: @belisarius looks hand drawn, that is so cool.

Comment: @rcollyer It is from his post-doctoral thesis. The drawing was done by hand by Marta Puebla, an artist (and his wife, BTW).

Answer (score 59):

One of the nice things about the Mathematica notebook interface is that it can evaluate expressions in *any* language, not just Mathematica.  As a simple example, consider creating a new *Shell* input cell type that passes the contained expression to the operating system shell for evaluation.

First, define a function that delegates evaluation of a textual command to the external shell:

```
shellEvaluate[cmd_, _] := Import["!"~~cmd, "Text"]
```

The second argument is needed and ignored for reasons that will become apparent later.  Next, we want to create a new style called *Shell*:

1. Open a new notebook.
2. Select the menu item *Format/Edit Stylesheet...*
3. In the dialog, beside *Enter a style name:* type `Shell`.
4. Select the cell bracket beside the new style.
5. Select the menu item *Cell/Show Expression*
6. Overwrite the cell expression with the **Step 6 Text** given below.
7. Once again, select the menu item *Cell/Show Expression*
8. Close the dialog.

Use the following cell expression as the **Step 6 Text**:

```
Cell[StyleData["Shell"],
 CellFrame->{{0, 0}, {0.5, 0.5}},
 CellMargins->{{66, 4}, {0, 8}},
 Evaluatable->True,
 StripStyleOnPaste->True,
 CellEvaluationFunction->shellEvaluate,
 CellFrameLabels->{{None, "Shell"}, {None, None}},
 Hyphenation->False,
 AutoQuoteCharacters->{},
 PasteAutoQuoteCharacters->{},
 LanguageCategory->"Formula",
 ScriptLevel->1,
 MenuSortingValue->1800,
 FontFamily->"Courier"]
```

Most of this expression was copied directly form the built-in *Program* style.  The key changes are these lines:

```
 Evaluatable->True,
 CellEvaluationFunction->shellEvaluate,
 CellFrameLabels->{{None, "Shell"}, {None, None}},
```

`Evaluatable` enables the SHIFT+ENTER functionality for the cell.  Evaluation will call the `CellEvaluationFunction` passing the cell content and content type as arguments (`shellEvaluate` ignores the latter argument).  `CellFrameLabels` is just a nicety that let's the user identify that this cell is unusual.

With all of this in place, we can now enter and evaluate a shell expression:

1. In the notebook created in the steps above, create an empty cell and select the cell bracket.
2. Select the menu item *Format/Style/Shell*.
3. Type a valid operating system shell command into the cell (e.g. 'ls' on Unix or 'dir' on Windows).
4. Press SHIFT+ENTER.

It is best to keep this defined style in a centrally located stylesheet.  Furthermore, evaluation functions like `shellEvaluate` are best defined as stubs using [DeclarePackage](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DeclarePackage.html) in `init.m`.  The details of both of these activities are beyond the scope of this response.

With this functionality, one can create notebooks that contain input expressions in any syntax of interest.  The evaluation function can be written in pure Mathematica, or delegate any or all parts of the evaluation to an external agency.  Be aware that there are other hooks that relate to cell evaluation, like `CellEpilog`, `CellProlog` and `CellDynamicExpression`.

A common pattern involves writing the input expression text to a temporary file, compiling the file in some language, running the program and capturing the output for ultimate display in the output cell.  There are plenty of details to address when implementing a full solution of this kind (like capturing error messages properly), but one must appreciate the fact that it is not only possible to do things like this, but practical.

On a personal note, it is features like this that makes the notebook interface the center of my programming universe.

**Update**

The following helper function is useful for creating such cells:

```
evaluatableCell[label_String, evaluationFunction_] :=
  ( CellPrint[
      TextCell[
        ""
      , "Program"
      , Evaluatable -> True
      , CellEvaluationFunction -> (evaluationFunction[#]&)
      , CellFrameLabels -> {{None, label}, {None, None}}
      , CellGroupingRules -> "InputGrouping"
      ]
    ]
  ; SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, EvaluationCell]
  ; NotebookDelete[]
  ; SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Next, CellContents]
  )
```

It is used thus:

```
shellCell[] := evaluatableCell["shell", Import["!"~~#, "Text"] &]
```

Now, if `shellCell[]` is evaluated, the input cell will be deleted and replaced with a new input cell that evaluates its contents as a shell command.

Comment: @WReach +100! I wish I knew this earlier! This is *very* useful stuff, for me at least. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: This looks pretty spiffy!  `CellEvaluationFunction` could be used for low level syntax hacking as well I think.

Comment: @Leonid At least for the FrontEnd, is `CellEvaluationFunction` the hook you were looking for?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - For the FronteEnd, I'd say yes!

Comment: +1, wow. That is an awesome technique! Now I just need to find a nail to use this hammer on ...

Comment: In addition: there is another one `Cell` option that is related to cell evaluation - `Evaluator -> "EvaluatorName"`. The meaning of `"EvaluatorName"` could be configured through *Evaluation::Kernel Configuration Options...* dialog. I still do not know is it possible co configure it programmatically... This technique allows to use different MathKernels in different `Cell`s in one Notebook. These MathKernels can be from different versions of *Mathematica* installed.

Comment: Great! Do you use this in any situation where the other program ("kernel") does not quit and restart between evaluations but stays running? (e.g. python!)

Comment: @Szabolcs All of my own uses of this technique involve either a _stdin_/_stdout_ approach as illustrated above, or a self-contained remote request such as an SQL query or an HTTP operation.  You might try setting up a Python REPL web app (like [this](http://shell.appspot.com/)) and interacting with it using `Import`, or perhaps starting up an external Python process and communicating through its streams (e.g. using a Java [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)).  I'm sure there is a better Mathematica way -- sounds like a good SO question :)

Answer (score 41):

Todd Gayley (Wolfram Research) just send me a nice hack which allows to "wrap" built-in functions with arbitrary code. I feel that I have to share this useful instrument. The following is Todd's answer on my [`question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998561/mathlink-correct-handling-of-messages-generated-by-slave-kernel).

> A bit of interesting (?) history: That style of hack for "wrapping" a 
>   built-in function was invented around 1994 by Robby Villegas and I, 
>   ironically for the function Message, in a package called ErrorHelp 
>   that I wrote for the Mathematica Journal back then. It has been used 
>   many times, by many people, since then. It's a bit of an insider's 
>   trick, but I think it's fair to say that it has become the canonical 
>   way of injecting your own code into the definition of a built-in 
>   function. It gets the job done nicely. You can, of course, put the 
>   $inMsg variable into any private context you wish.

```
Unprotect[Message];

Message[args___] := Block[{$inMsg = True, result},
   "some code here";
   result = Message[args];
   "some code here";
   result] /; ! TrueQ[$inMsg]

Protect[Message];
```

Comment: @Alexey I have difficulties understanding this. Could you explain how this works? Shouldn't there be an Unprotect[Message] somewhere? And doesn't this example contain infinite recursion? And, ! TrueQ[$inMsg] does that make sense with $inMsg defined inside the Block scope and undefined outside of Block?

Comment: @Sjoerd  From what I understand, the `Unprotect` indeed has to be, was just left out. The point of `Block` (dynamic scoping) and `$inMsg` is exactly to prevent infinite recursion. Because `$inMsg` is undefined outside (this is an important requirement), at first, `TrueQ` evaluates to `False`, and we enter the function's body. But when we  have the function call inside the body, the condition evaluates to `False` (since the variable has been redefined by Block). Thus, user-defined rule is not matched, and the built-in rule is instead used.

Comment: I just have found that this technique was discussed by Robby Villegas of Wolfram  Research at the 1999 Developer Conference.  See ["Working With  Unevaluated Expressions"](http://library.wolfram.com/conferences/devconf99/villegas/UnevaluatedExpressions.nb) notebook posted [here](http://library.wolfram.com/conferences/devconf99/#programming). In this notebook Robby Villegas discusses this trick in "My Block trick for trapping calls to built-in functions" subsection.

Comment: I could not have answered Simon's bounty question without this.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard This is not the only way to do this. For a long time, I used a version where you redefine the `DownValues` at run-time, you can look at this post http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/c000439b48751078, for an example (`SetDelayed` redefinition). But my method is less elegant, less robust, more error-prone, and makes breaking from recursion  much less trivial to implement. So, in most situations, the method described by @Alexey wins hands down.

Comment: @Leonid let me echo: "Wow, that looks complicated." :-)

Answer (score 25):

This is not a complete resource, so I'm throwing it here in the answers section, but I have found it very useful when figuring out speed issues (which, unfortunately, is a large part of what Mathematica programming is about).

```
timeAvg[func_] := Module[
{x = 0, y = 0, timeLimit = 0.1, p, q, iterTimes = Power[10, Range[0, 10]]},
Catch[
 If[(x = First[Timing[(y++; Do[func, {#}]);]]) > timeLimit,
    Throw[{x, y}]
    ] & /@ iterTimes
 ] /. {p_, q_} :> p/iterTimes[[q]]
];
Attributes[timeAvg] = {HoldAll};
```

Usage is then simply `timeAvg@funcYouWantToTest`.

EDIT: Mr. Wizard has provided a simpler version that does away with `Throw` and `Catch` and is a bit easier to parse:

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] := Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ 
                     Timing @ Do[func, {5^i}]
                     ,{i, 0, 15}]
```

EDIT: Here's a version from [acl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559318/acl) (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242818/definition-lookup-speed-an-performance-issue/7243097#7243097)):

```
timeIt::usage = "timeIt[expr] gives the time taken to execute expr, \
  repeating as many times as necessary to achieve a total time of 1s";

SetAttributes[timeIt, HoldAll]
timeIt[expr_] := Module[{t = Timing[expr;][[1]], tries = 1},
  While[t < 1., tries *= 2; t = Timing[Do[expr, {tries}];][[1]];]; 
  t/tries]
```

Comment: Done it again and agin ... time to enter in my own bag. tnx!

Comment: never tried this.  mostly I just time the pieces separately, and then put them together.

Comment: One problem with this code (well, may be this is a perfectionist's viewpoint) is that we can catch something that we did not throw, and interpret this as an incorrect timing result. Both `Catch` and `Throw` should have been used with unique exception tags.

Comment: Timo, please see my version of your function here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961#5435872  Perhaps you wish to include it in your post, in which case I will delete my other answer.

Comment: Timo, I am glad you like my rendition enough to include it.  Thanks for giving me credit, too.  I am curious about the way you reformatted my code. I don't follow any particular guidelines in my own code, other than making it easy to read myself; is there a school of thought behind your reformatting, or is it just preference?  Mathematica does not encourage precise code formatting because of the way it reflows input, but posting code here is causing me to start thinking about it.  BTW, I think you mean "`Throw` and `Catch`" rather than "`Reap` and `Sow`."

Comment: @Mr. Actually, the Wolfram Workbench includes a standard for formatting ... using Eclipse

Comment: @Mr. thanks for the correction, I fixed the misnomer. As for formatting Mathematica code I just do whatever I feel is readable, generally indenting at functions that are important for understanding what the program does (e.g. `Catch` and `If` in the first version).

Comment: @Timo and @Mr., I tend to follow similar formatting to what I'd use in c++: inner expressions moved in with respect to their enclosures. Also, I tend to put each item in a comma delimited list (both `List`s and function arguments apply) on a separate line. This is especially useful when building `Graphics` directives or particularly involved pure functions. Additionally, I use postfix form almost exclusively (with each new function on a new line), and I think of each function in the chain as performing a transformation of the input data.

Comment: [Here's my version of TimeAv](http://pastebin.com/Nv7rH2vE). It returns `{{timeAvg, numberOfRuns}, result}`. The number of runs to find the average is determined on either a minimum total timing or a minimum number of runs.

Comment: @Timo & @Mr.Wizard: Your `timeAvg` code finds the average using `Timing[loop[fn]]` while mine uses `loop[Timing[fn]]`. These give quite different results because of the way the loop constructs optimize the evaluation. Which do you think is a truer evaluation of the timing? Compare, e.g., ``rand = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 50];
fn := Total[rand];
{Table[Total@Table[First[Timing[fn]], {300000}], {5}], 
 Table[First@Timing[Table[fn, {300000}]], {5}]}``, where the first method is like mine and the second like yours. Yours seems to give more consistent results...

Comment: @Simon I believe we cannot (effectively) avoid caching within a session, therefore none of the iterative timing methods are "true" in the sense of being equivalent to the first execution time.  Given this, and since each evaluation of `Timing` must have some overhead, I see no point in adding the uncertainly and overhead of additional insertions of this function.  I feel that within the caching environment, the best we can do is to time the total execution of all iterations.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Hmmm... I need to think about it some more. I'm comfortable with the fact that the `AbsoluteTiming` of my `TimeAv` function will be more than yours for the same amount of iterations, but I'm not comfortable with the difference in the calculated average timings.

Comment: @Simon, Mr.Wizard, I use this method to time differing versions of smallish functions which are going to be called a lot of times. Not necessarily in a loop structure but certainly within constructs that MMA optimizes. In this context timing the execution of a loop makes sense and the performance will be close to the real life application. For timing large complex functions (maybe even entire initialization cells) the method by Simon will give a better result. All in all though, I'm more interested in relative values and either method should work there.

Comment: There's now `RepeatedTiming` to do this.

Answer (score 21):

### `` Internal`InheritedBlock ``

I have learned recently the existence of such useful function as `` Internal`InheritedBlock ``, from [this message of Daniel Lichtblau](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/msg/0d1bf3f9053693ad) in the official newsgroup.

As I understand, `` Internal`InheritedBlock `` allows to pass a copy of an outbound function inside the `Block` scope:

```
In[1]:= Internal`InheritedBlock[{Message},
Print[Attributes[Message]];
Unprotect[Message];
Message[x___]:=Print[{{x},Stack[]}];
Sin[1,1]
]
Sin[1,1]
During evaluation of In[1]:= {HoldFirst,Protected}
During evaluation of In[1]:= {{Sin::argx,Sin,2},{Internal`InheritedBlock,CompoundExpression,Sin,Print,List}}
Out[1]= Sin[1,1]
During evaluation of In[1]:= Sin::argx: Sin called with 2 arguments; 1 argument is expected. >>
Out[2]= Sin[1,1]
```

I think this function can be very useful for everyone who need to modify built-in functions temporarily!

### Comparison with Block

Let us define some function:

```
a := Print[b]
```

Now we wish to pass a copy of this function into the `Block` scope. The naive trial does not give what we want:

```
In[2]:= Block[{a = a}, OwnValues[a]]

During evaluation of In[9]:= b

Out[2]= {HoldPattern[a] :> Null}
```

Now trying to use delayed definition in the first argument of `Block` (it is an undocumented feature too):

```
In[3]:= Block[{a := a}, OwnValues[a]]
Block[{a := a}, a]

Out[3]= {HoldPattern[a] :> a}

During evaluation of In[3]:= b
```

We see that in this case `a` works but we have not got a copy of the original `a` inside of the `Block` scope.

Now let us try `` Internal`InheritedBlock ``:

```
In[5]:= Internal`InheritedBlock[{a}, OwnValues[a]]

Out[5]= {HoldPattern[a] :> Print[b]}
```

We have got a copy of the original definition for `a` inside of the `Block` scope and we may modify it in the way we want without affecting the global definition for `a`!

Comment: +1 Very handy! One more tool in the bag, and 10 points closer to Edit privilege for you.

Comment: To me this appears as a variant of early or late or no and full evaluation.

Answer (score 20):

Mathematica is a sharp tool, but it can cut you with its somewhat [untyped behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558732/is-mathematica-an-untyped-language) and [avalanches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174791/preventing-avalanche-of-runtime-errors-in-mathematica) of cryptic [diagnostic messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176612/setting-up-diagnostic-error-messages-in-large-mathematica-projects).  One way to deal with this is to define functions following this idiom:

```
ClearAll@zot
SetAttributes[zot, ...]
zot[a_] := ...
zot[b_ /; ...] := ...
zot[___] := (Message[zot::invalidArguments]; Abort[])
```

That is a lot of boilerplate, which I'm frequently tempted to skip.  Especially when prototyping, which happens a lot in Mathematica.  So, I use a macro called `define` that allows me to stay disciplined, with much less boilerplate.

A basic usage of `define` is like this:

```
define[
  fact[0] = 1
; fact[n_ /; n > 0] := n * fact[n-1]
]

fact[5]

120
```

It doesn't look like much at first, but there are some hidden benefits.  The first service that `define` provides is that it automatically applies `ClearAll` to the symbol being defined.  This ensures that there are no leftover definitions -- a common occurrence during the initial development of a function.

The second service is that the function being defined is automatically "closed".  By this I mean that the function will issue a message and abort if it is invoked with an argument list that is not matched by one of the definitions:

```
fact[-1]

define::badargs: There is no definition for 'fact' applicable to fact[-1].
$Aborted
```

This is the primary value of `define`, which catches a very common class of error.

Another convenience is a concise way to specify attributes on the function being defined.  Let's make the function `Listable`:

```
define[
  fact[0] = 1
; fact[n_ /; n > 0] := n * fact[n-1]
, Listable
]

fact[{3, 5, 8}]

{6, 120, 40320}
```

In addition to all of the normal attributes, `define` accepts an additional attribute called `Open`.  This prevents `define` from adding the catch-all error definition to the function:

```
define[
  successor[x_ /; x > 0] := x + 1
, Open
]

successor /@ {1, "hi"}

{2, successor["hi"]}
```

Multiple attributes may be defined for a function:

```
define[
  flatHold[x___] := Hold[x]
, {Flat, HoldAll}
]

flatHold[flatHold[1+1, flatHold[2+3]], 4+5]

Hold[1 + 1, 2 + 3, 4 + 5]
```

Without further ado, here is the definition of `define`:

```
ClearAll@define
SetAttributes[define, HoldAll]
define[body_, attribute_Symbol] := define[body, {attribute}]
define[body:(_Set|_SetDelayed), attributes_List:{}] := define[CompoundExpression[body], attributes]
define[body:CompoundExpression[((Set|SetDelayed)[name_Symbol[___], _])..], attributes_List:{}] :=
  ( ClearAll@name
  ; SetAttributes[name, DeleteCases[attributes, Open]]
  ; If[!MemberQ[attributes, Open]
    , def:name[___] := (Message[define::badargs, name, Defer@def]; Abort[])
    ]
  ; body
  ;
  )
def:define[___] := (Message[define::malformed, Defer@def]; Abort[])

define::badargs = "There is no definition for '``' applicable to ``.";
define::malformed = "Malformed definition: ``";
```

The exhibited implementation supports neither up-values nor currying, nor patterns more general than simple function definition.  It remains useful, however.

Comment: +1 - this is really useful stuff. I have been using similar tools. Macros (as well as introspection and other meta-programming techniques) can be very powerful, but seem to be under-appreciated generally within Mathematica community, or at least this has been my impression so far.

Comment: I have just defined something similar. +1 for CompoundExpression support for doing multiple definitions, Abort[] (seems better than yet more messages) and Open (nice for e.g. constructors).

Answer (score 17):

### General PDF/EMF export problems and solutions

1) It is completely unexpected and undocumented, but *Mathematica* exports and saves graphics in PDF and EPS formats using a set of style definitions that differs from the one used for displaying Notebooks on screen. By default Notebooks are displayed on screen in the "Working" style environment (which is default value for the `ScreenStyleEvironment` global `$FrontEnd` option) but are printed in the `"Printout"` style environment (which is default value for the `PrintingStyleEnvironment` global `$FrontEnd` option). When one exports graphics in raster formats such as GIF and PNG or in EMF format *Mathematica* generates graphics that looks exactly like it looks inside Notebook. It seems that the `"Working"` style environment is used for rendering in this case. But it is not the case when you export/save anything in PDF or EPS formats! In this case the [`"Printout"` style environment is used by default](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/msg/7f5cb9e2d4677855) that differs very deeply from the "Working" style environment. First of all, [the `"Printout"` style environment sets `Magnification` to 80%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091553/font-sizes-print-smaller-than-indicated/6093089#6093089). Secondly, it uses its own values for the font sizes of different styles and this results in inconsistent font size changes in the genarated PDF file as compared with the original on-screen representation. The latter can be called [FontSize fluctuations](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/9ea5e78b181f9f6f/7f5cb9e2d4677855%3Fq%3D%2522Printout%2522%2BMagnification%2B0.8%2Bgroup%3acomp.soft-sys.math.mathematica%237f5cb9e2d4677855&ei=T-7ZTeGeLMPG_QbOz_SVCA&sa=t&ct=res&cd=1&source=groups&usg=AFQjCNHY6PZIvxkgjmMOo4f5xfcgNBbxdQ) which are very annoying. 
But happily this can be avoided [by setting the `PrintingStyleEnvironment` global `$FrontEnd` option to "Working"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093559/how-to-export-graphics-in-working-style-environment-rather-than-printout/6093783#6093783):

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Working"]
```

2) The common problem with exporting to EMF format is that most of programs (not only *Mathematica*) generate a file that looks nice at the default size but becomes ugly when you zoom it in. It is because [metafiles are sampled at screen resolution fidelity](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/msg/443befb422e4e25a). The quality of the generated EMF file can be enhanced by `Magnify`ing the original graphical object so that exactness of sampling of the original graphics becomes much more precise. Compare two files:

```
graphics1 = 
  First@ImportString[
    ExportString[Style["a", FontFamily -> "Times"], "PDF"], "PDF"];
graphics2 = Magnify[graphics1, 10];
Export["C:\\test1.emf", graphics1]
Export["C:\\test2.emf", graphics2]
```

If you insert these files into Microsoft Word and zoom them in you will see that the first "a" has sawtooth on it while the second has not (tested with *Mathematica* 6).

Another way through `ImageResolution` was suggested by [Chris Degnen](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/135321/280) (this option has effect at least starting from *Mathematica* 8):

```
Export["C:\\test1.emf", graphics1]
Export["C:\\test2.emf", graphics1, ImageResolution -> 300]
```

3) In *Mathematica* we have three ways to convert graphics into metafile: via `Export` to `"EMF"` (strongly recommended way: produces metafile with highest possible quality), via `Save selection As...` menu item ([produces much lesser precise figure](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/38776/280), not recommended) and via `Edit ► Copy As ► Metafile` menu item ([I strongly recommend against this route](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60972/280)).

Answer (score 16):

### Start without a blank notebook open

I was bothered by having Mathematica start with a blank notebook open.  I could close this notebook with a script, but it would still flash open briefly.  My hack is to create a file `Invisible.nb` containing:

```
Notebook[{},Visible->False]
```

And add this to my `Kernel\init.m` :

```
If[Length[Notebooks["Invisible*"]] > 0, 
  NotebookClose[Notebooks["Invisible*"][[1]]]
]

SetOptions[$FrontEnd,
  Options[$FrontEnd, NotebooksMenu] /. 
    HoldPattern["Invisible.nb" -> {__}] :> Sequence[]
]
```

I now start Mathematica by opening `Invisible.nb`

There may be a better way, but this has served me well.

---

### Customized `Fold` and `FoldList`

`Fold[f, x]` is made equivalent to `Fold[f, First@x, Rest@x]`

<s>Incidentally, I believe this may find its way into a future version of Mathematica.</s>

[**Surprise! This has been implemented, though it is presently undocumented.**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54784/121)  I am informed that it was implemented in 2011 by Oliver Ruebenkoenig, apparently not long after I posted this.  Thank you Oliver Ruebenkoenig!

```
Unprotect[Fold, FoldList]

Fold[f_, h_[a_, b__]] := Fold[f, Unevaluated @ a, h @ b]
FoldList[f_, h_[a_, b__]] := FoldList[f, Unevaluated @ a, h @ b]

(* Faysal's recommendation to modify SyntaxInformation *)
SyntaxInformation[Fold]     = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, _, _.}};
SyntaxInformation[FoldList] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, _., {__}}};

Protect[Fold, FoldList]
```

Updated to allow this:

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll]
Fold[f, Hold[1 + 1, 2/2, 3^3]]
```

> ```
> f[f[1 + 1, 2/2], 3^3]
> ```

---

### "Dynamic Partition"

*See [Mathematica.SE post #7512](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7512/121) for a new version of this function.*

Frequently I want to partition a list according to a sequence of lengths.

pseudo-code example:

`partition[{1,2,3,4,5,6}, {2,3,1}]`

Output:   `{{1,2}, {3,4,5}, {6}}`

I came up with this:

```
dynP[l_, p_] := 
 MapThread[l[[# ;; #2]] &, {{0} ~Join~ Most@# + 1, #} &@Accumulate@p]
```

Which I then completed with this, including argument testing:

```
dynamicPartition[l_List, p : {_Integer?NonNegative ..}] :=
  dynP[l, p] /; Length@l >= Tr@p

dynamicPartition[l_List, p : {_Integer?NonNegative ..}, All] :=
  dynP[l, p] ~Append~ Drop[l, Tr@p] /; Length@l >= Tr@p

dynamicPartition[l_List, p : {_Integer?NonNegative ..}, n__ | {n__}] :=
  dynP[l, p] ~Join~ Partition[l ~Drop~ Tr@p, n] /; Length@l >= Tr@p
```

The third argument controls what happens to elements beyond the split specification.

---

### [Szabolcs's Mathematica tricks](http://web.ift.uib.no/~szhorvat/mmatricks.php)

The one I use most frequently is the Paste Tabular Data Palette

```
CreatePalette@
 Column@{Button["TSV", 
    Module[{data, strip}, 
     data = NotebookGet[ClipboardNotebook[]][[1, 1, 1]];
     strip[s_String] := 
      StringReplace[s, RegularExpression["^\\s*(.*?)\\s*$"] -> "$1"];
     strip[e_] := e;
     If[Head[data] === String, 
      NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], 
       ToBoxes@Map[strip, ImportString[data, "TSV"], {2}]]]]], 
   Button["CSV", 
    Module[{data, strip}, 
     data = NotebookGet[ClipboardNotebook[]][[1, 1, 1]];
     strip[s_String] := 
      StringReplace[s, RegularExpression["^\\s*(.*?)\\s*$"] -> "$1"];
     strip[e_] := e;
     If[Head[data] === String, 
      NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], 
       ToBoxes@Map[strip, ImportString[data, "CSV"], {2}]]]]], 
   Button["Table", 
    Module[{data}, data = NotebookGet[ClipboardNotebook[]][[1, 1, 1]];
     If[Head[data] === String, 
      NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], 
       ToBoxes@ImportString[data, "Table"]]]]]}
```

---

### Modify external data from within `Compile`

Recently Daniel Lichtblau showed this method I had never seen before. In my opinion it significantly extends the utility of `Compile`

```
ll = {2., 3., 4.};
c = Compile[{{x}, {y}}, ll[[1]] = x; y];

c[4.5, 5.6]

ll

(* Out[1] = 5.6  *)

(* Out[2] = {4.5, 3., 4.}  *)
```

Comment: +1 A good collection! Regarding the external modifications from within  `Compile` - my whole post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246330/delete-repeating-list-elements-preserving-order-of-appearance/5251034#5251034, was to showcase this possibility in a non-trivial setting (There was a shorter and faster solution to the problem in question posted there already). IMO, the biggest win here is the ability to emulate pass-by-reference and break large Compiled functions into more managable and reusable chunks.

Comment: You can also adjust the syntax information of Fold and FoldList in your new definition:
    SyntaxInformation[Fold] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> { _ , _. , _}};
    SyntaxInformation[FoldList] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> { _ , _., {__}}};

Answer (score 13):

By popular demand, the code to generate the top-10 SO answerers plot (except [annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5744117/615464)) using the [SO API](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/usage).

[image]

```
getRepChanges[userID_Integer] :=
 Module[{totalChanges},
  totalChanges = 
   "total" /. 
    Import["http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/" <> 
      ToString[userID] <> "/reputation?fromdate=0&pagesize=10&page=1",
      "JSON"];
  Join @@ Table[
    "rep_changes" /. 
     Import["http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/" <> 
       ToString[userID] <> 
       "/reputation?fromdate=0&pagesize=10&page=" <> ToString[page], 
      "JSON"],
    {page, 1, Ceiling[totalChanges/10]}
    ]
  ]

topAnswerers = ({"display_name", 
      "user_id"} /. #) & /@ ("user" /. ("top_users" /. 
      Import["http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/tags/mathematica/top-\
answerers/all-time", "JSON"]))

repChangesTopUsers =
  Monitor[Table[
    repChange = 
     ReleaseHold[(Hold[{DateList[
              "on_date" + AbsoluteTime["January 1, 1970"]], 
             "positive_rep" - "negative_rep"}] /. #) & /@ 
        getRepChanges[userID]] // Sort;
    accRepChange = {repChange[[All, 1]], 
       Accumulate[repChange[[All, 2]]]}\[Transpose],
    {userID, topAnswerers[[All, 2]]}
    ], userID];

pl = DateListLogPlot[
  Tooltip @@@ 
   Take[({repChangesTopUsers, topAnswerers[[All, 1]]}\[Transpose]), 
    10], Joined -> True, Mesh -> None, ImageSize -> 1000, 
  PlotRange -> {All, {10, All}}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial-Bold", FontSize -> 16}, 
  DateTicksFormat -> {"MonthNameShort", " ", "Year"}, 
  GridLines -> {True, None}, 
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, FontSize -> 18] & /@ {"Date", "Reputation", 
      "Top-10 answerers", ""})]
```

Comment: Brett posted a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5745298/198315) asking for almost this exact code.  Maybe it is most appropriate there, with a tweak or two to fit the question.  I would actually be worth rep, as opposed to on this question.

Comment: @rcollyer is right. This is "Community Wiki"

Comment: @belisarius I just copied it in the answer to Brett's question...

Comment: @Sjoerd Your Plot here does not auto-update.

Comment: @belisarius Actually I was hoping you were going to take that task upon you...  ;-)

Comment: api 1.1 is down now :(

Comment: @masterxilo It's five years old. I have a new version somewhere on the Mathematica.se site, but no time to look for it now.

Answer (score 13):

### Caching expressions

I find these functions very helpful to cache any expression. The interesting thing here for these two functions is that the held expression itself is used as a key of the hashtable/symbol Cache or CacheIndex, compared to the well-known memoization in mathematica where you can only cache result if the function is defined like f[x_] := f[x] = ... So you can cache any part of a code, this is useful if a function is to be called several times but just some parts of the code must not be recomputed.

To cache an expression independently of its arguments.

```
SetAttributes[Cache, HoldFirst];
c:Cache[expr_] := c = expr;

Ex: Cache[Pause[5]; 6]
Cache[Pause[5]; 6]
```

The second time the expression returns 6 without waiting.

To cache an expression using an alias expression that can depend on an argument of the cached expression.

```
SetAttributes[CacheIndex, HoldRest];
c:CacheIndex[index_,expr_] := c = expr;

Ex: CacheIndex[{"f",2},x=2;y=4;x+y]
```

If expr takes some time to compute, it is much faster to evaluate {"f",2} for example to retrieve the cached result.

For a variation of these functions in order to have a localized cache (ie. the cache memory is automatically released outside the Block construct) see this post [Avoid repeated calls to Interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781981/avoid-repreated-calls-to-interpolation/7784989#7784989)

### Deleting cached values

To delete cached values when you don't know the number of definitions of a function. I consider that definitions have a Blank somewhere in their arguments.

```
DeleteCachedValues[f_] := 
       DownValues[f] = Select[DownValues[f], !FreeQ[Hold@#,Pattern]&];
```

To delete cached values when you know the number of definitions of a function (goes slightly faster).

```
DeleteCachedValues[f_,nrules_] := 
       DownValues[f] = Extract[DownValues[f], List /@ Range[-nrules, -1]];
```

This uses the fact that definitions of a function are at the end of their DownValues list, cached values are before.

### Using symbols to store data and object-like functions

Also here are interesting functions to use symbols like objects.

It is already well known that you can store data in symbols and quickly access them using DownValues

```
mysymbol["property"]=2;
```

You can access the list of keys (or properties) of a symbol using these functions based on what dreeves submitted in a post on this site:

```
SetAttributes[RemoveHead, {HoldAll}];
RemoveHead[h_[args___]] := {args};
NKeys[symbol_] := RemoveHead @@@ DownValues[symbol(*,Sort->False*)][[All,1]];
Keys[symbol_] := NKeys[symbol] /. {x_} :> x;
```

I use this function a lot to display all infos contained in the DownValues of a symbol:

```
PrintSymbol[symbol_] :=
  Module[{symbolKeys},
    symbolKeys = Keys[symbol];
    TableForm@Transpose[{symbolKeys, symbol /@ symbolKeys}]
  ];
```

Finally here is a simple way to create a symbol that behaves like an object in object oriented programming (it just reproduces the most basic behaviour of OOP but I find the syntax elegant) :

```
Options[NewObject]={y->2};
NewObject[OptionsPattern[]]:=
  Module[{newObject},
    newObject["y"]=OptionValue[y];

    function[newObject,x_] ^:= newObject["y"]+x;
    newObject /: newObject.function2[x_] := 2 newObject["y"]+x;

    newObject
  ];
```

Properties are stored as DownValues and methods as delayed Upvalues in the symbol created by Module that is returned. I found the syntax for function2 that is the usual OO-syntax for functions in [Tree data structure in Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097071/tree-data-structure-in-mathematica/6097444#6097444).

For a list of existing types of values each symbol has, see http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PatternsAndTransformationRules.html and http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/HTMLLinks/Tricks_Misc_4.html.

For example try this

```
x = NewObject[y -> 3];
function[x, 4]
x.function2[5]
```

You can go further if you want to emulate object inheritance using a package called InheritRules available here
http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/671/

You could also store the function definition not in newObject but in a type symbol, so if NewObject returned type[newObject] instead of newObject you could define function and function2 like this 
outside of NewObject (and not inside) and have the same usage as before.

```
function[type[object_], x_] ^:= object["y"] + x;
type /: type[object_].function2[x_] := 2 object["y"]+x;
```

Use UpValues[type] to see that function and function2 are defined in the type symbol.

Further ideas about this last syntax are introduced here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/999/66.

### Improved version of SelectEquivalents

@rcollyer: Many thanks for bringing SelectEquivalents to the surface, it's an amazing function.
Here is an improved version of SelectEquivalents listed above with more possibilities and using options, this makes it easier to use.

```
Options[SelectEquivalents] = 
   {
      TagElement->Identity,
      TransformElement->Identity,
      TransformResults->(#2&) (*#1=tag,#2 list of elements corresponding to tag*),
      MapLevel->1,
      TagPattern->_,
      FinalFunction->Identity
   };

SelectEquivalents[x_List,OptionsPattern[]] := 
   With[
      {
         tagElement=OptionValue@TagElement,
         transformElement=OptionValue@TransformElement,
         transformResults=OptionValue@TransformResults,
         mapLevel=OptionValue@MapLevel,
         tagPattern=OptionValue@TagPattern,
         finalFunction=OptionValue@FinalFunction
      }
      ,
      finalFunction[
         Reap[
            Map[
               Sow[
                  transformElement@#
                  ,
                  {tagElement@#}
               ]&
               , 
               x
               , 
               {mapLevel}
            ] 
            , 
            tagPattern
            , 
            transformResults
         ][[2]]
      ]
   ];
```

Here are examples of how this version can be used:

[Using Mathematica Gather/Collect properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974544/using-mathematica-gather-collect-properly/6987982#6987982)

[How would you do a PivotTable function in Mathematica?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099866/how-would-you-do-a-pivottable-function-in-mathematica/8105565#8105565)

[Mathematica fast 2D binning algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178714/mathematica-fast-2d-binning-algorithm/8183307#8183307)

### Internal`Bag

Daniel Lichtblau describes here an interesting internal data structure for growing lists.

[Implementing a Quadtree in Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691491/implementing-a-quadtree-in-mathematica/6795762#6795762)

### Debugging functions

These two posts point to useful functions for debugging:

[How to debug when writting small or big codes using Mathematica? workbench? mma debugger? or something else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167291/how-to-debug-when-writting-small-or-big-codes-using-mathematica-workbench-mma/6168036#6168036) (ShowIt)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459735/the-clearest-way-to-represent-mathematicas-evaluation-sequence/5527117#5527117 (TraceView)

Here's another function based on Reap and Sow to extract expressions from different parts of a program and store them in a symbol.

```
SetAttributes[ReapTags,HoldFirst];
ReapTags[expr_]:=
   Module[{elements},
      Reap[expr,_,(elements[#1]=#2/.{x_}:>x)&];
      elements
   ];
```

Here's an example

```
ftest[]:=((*some code*)Sow[1,"x"];(*some code*)Sow[2,"x"];(*some code*)Sow[3,"y"]);
s=ReapTags[ftest[]];
Keys[s]
s["x"]
PrintSymbol[s] (*Keys and PrintSymbol are defined above*)
```

### Other resources

Here's a list of interesting links for learning purpose:

[A collection of Mathematica learning resources](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/0014d2ca042a76c2#)

Updated here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/259/66

Comment: Related: "[The best way to construct a function with memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287817/the-best-way-to-construct-a-function-with-memory)". WReach has given there an amazing example of simple function that not only remembers its values but also writes them to a file and reads backward on restart.

Comment: Related: "[Mathematica: How to clear the cache for a symbol, i.e. Unset pattern-free DownValues](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5086749/421225)". This question shows how to clear the cache using standard `f[x_] := f[x] = some code` memoization.

Comment: +1 There is a nice notational convenience that eliminates the need to repeat the left-hand side of the definition in a caching function, e.g.: `c:Cache[expr_] := c = expr`.

Comment: Nice variant of `SelectEquivalents`. I think, I'd keep `TagOnElement` as the second param defaulting to `Identity` as it is the most used of them, though. I don't think I'd included `FinalOp`, either, as it can be handled within `OpOnTaggedElems`. I'd also shorten the option names, as their length makes it awkward to type out. Try `TagFunction`, `TransformElement`, `TransformResults`, and `TagPattern` instead. Both, `TagPattern` and `MapLevel` are great additions to the functionality, and a good rewrite, overall.

Comment: Thanks for your comment rcollyer. I took it into account and improved also the readability of the code. I keep FinalFunction because it operates on the result of Reap, for example if you want to sort your final result by tags if you keep them.

Answer (score 12):

My utility functions (I have these built in to MASH, which is mentioned in the question):

```
pr = WriteString["stdout", ##]&;            (* More                           *)
prn = pr[##, "\n"]&;                        (*  convenient                    *)
perr = WriteString["stderr", ##]&;          (*   print                        *)
perrn = perr[##, "\n"]&;                    (*    statements.                 *)
re = RegularExpression;                     (* I wish mathematica             *)
eval = ToExpression[cat[##]]&;              (*  weren't so damn               *)
EOF = EndOfFile;                            (*   verbose!                     *)
read[] := InputString[""];                  (* Grab a line from stdin.        *)
doList[f_, test_] :=                        (* Accumulate list of what f[]    *)
  Most@NestWhileList[f[]&, f[], test];      (*  returns while test is true.   *)
readList[] := doList[read, #=!=EOF&];       (* Slurp list'o'lines from stdin. *)
cat = StringJoin@@(ToString/@{##})&;        (* Like sprintf/strout in C/C++.  *)
system = Run@cat@##&;                       (* System call.                   *)
backtick = Import[cat["!", ##], "Text"]&;   (* System call; returns stdout.   *)
slurp = Import[#, "Text"]&;                 (* Fetch contents of file as str. *)
                                            (* ABOVE: mma-scripting related.  *)
keys[f_, i_:1] :=                           (* BELOW: general utilities.      *)
  DownValues[f, Sort->False][[All,1,1,i]];  (* Keys of a hash/dictionary.     *)
SetAttributes[each, HoldAll];               (* each[pattern, list, body]      *)
each[pat_, lst_, bod_] := ReleaseHold[      (*  converts pattern to body for  *)
  Hold[Cases[Evaluate@lst, pat:>bod];]];    (*   each element of list.        *)
some[f_, l_List] := True ===                (* Whether f applied to some      *)
  Scan[If[f[#], Return[True]]&, l];         (*  element of list is True.      *)
every[f_, l_List] := Null ===               (* Similarly, And @@ f/@l         *)
  Scan[If[!f[#], Return[False]]&, l];       (*  (but with lazy evaluation).   *)
```

Comment: For the "each" function, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160216/foreach-loop-in-mathematica

Answer (score 12):

One trick I've used, which allows you to emulate the way most built-in functions work with bad arguments (by sending a message and then returning the whole form unevaluated) exploits a quirk of the way [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html) works when used in a defintion. If `foo` should only work with one argument:

```
foo[x_] := x + 1;
expr : foo[___] /; (Message[foo::argx, foo, Length@Unevaluated[expr], 1]; 
                    False) := Null; (* never reached *)
```

If you have more complex needs, it's easy to factor out the argument validation and message generation as an independent function. You can do more elaborate things by using side effects in `Condition` beyond just generating messages, but in my opinion most of them fall into the "sleazy hack" category and should be avoided if possible.

Also, in the "metaprogramming" category, if you have a Mathematica package (`.m`) file, you can use the [`"HeldExpressions"` element](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/Package.html) to get all the expressions in the file wrapped in `HoldComplete`. This makes tracking things down much easier than using text-based searches. Unfortunately, there's no easy way to do the same thing with a notebook, but you can get all the input expressions using something like the following:

```
inputExpressionsFromNotebookFile[nb_String] :=
 Cases[Get[nb],
  Cell[BoxData[boxes_], "Input", ___] :>
   MakeExpression[StripBoxes[boxes], StandardForm],
  Infinity]
```

Lastly, you can use the fact that `Module` emulates lexical closures to create the equivalent of reference types. Here's a simple stack (which uses a variation the `Condition` trick for error handling as a bonus):

```
ClearAll[MakeStack, StackInstance, EmptyQ, Pop, Push, Peek]
 With[{emptyStack = Unique["empty"]},
  Attributes[StackInstance] = HoldFirst;
  MakeStack[] :=
   Module[{backing = emptyStack},
    StackInstance[backing]];

  StackInstance::empty = "stack is empty";

  EmptyQ[StackInstance[backing_]] := (backing === emptyStack);

  HoldPattern[
    Pop[instance : StackInstance[backing_]]] /;
    ! EmptyQ[instance] || (Message[StackInstance::empty]; False) :=
   (backing = Last@backing; instance);

  HoldPattern[Push[instance : StackInstance[backing_], new_]] :=
   (backing = {new, backing}; instance);

  HoldPattern[Peek[instance : StackInstance[backing_]]] /;
    ! EmptyQ[instance] || (Message[StackInstance::empty]; False) :=
   First@backing]
```

Now you can print the elements of a list in reverse order in a needlessly convoluted way!

```
With[{stack = MakeStack[], list},
 Do[Push[stack, elt], {elt, list}];

 While[!EmptyQ[stack],
  Print[Peek@stack];
  Pop@stack]]
```

Comment: +1 for `HeldExpressions` element in packages, was unaware of that. I was usually importing as string and then using `ToExpression` with `HoldComplete` as last arg. Regarding using `Condition` for messages - this has been a standard technique in package writing since at least 1994. Regarding persistence through `Module` vars - I have had a long post on that on Mathgroup a while ago: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/5eff6213a0ab5f51 (my third post in that thread), this is along the same lines and has links to a few nontrivial examples of use.

Comment: @Leonid Shifrin: I picked up the `Condition` thing as lore, probably from a coworker, but didn't realize it was a standard technique. The link about using `Module` symbols as reference types is interesting!

Comment: +1, I never thought of that. The more I learn about this language the more powerful it seems.

Comment: @Pillsy what is the purpose of doing a stack that way?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I just chose one of the simplest mutable data structures I could think of to illustrate the technique.

Answer (score 12):

### Printing system symbol definitions without context prepended

The `contextFreeDefinition[]` function below will attempt to print the definition of a symbol without the most common context prepended.  The definition then can be copied to Workbench and formatted for readability (select it, right click, Source -> Format)

```
Clear[commonestContexts, contextFreeDefinition]

commonestContexts[sym_Symbol, n_: 1] := Quiet[
  Commonest[
   Cases[Level[DownValues[sym], {-1}, HoldComplete], 
    s_Symbol /; FreeQ[$ContextPath, Context[s]] :> Context[s]], n],
  Commonest::dstlms]

contextFreeDefinition::contexts = "Not showing the following contexts: `1`";

contextFreeDefinition[sym_Symbol, contexts_List] := 
 (If[contexts =!= {}, Message[contextFreeDefinition::contexts, contexts]];
  Internal`InheritedBlock[{sym}, ClearAttributes[sym, ReadProtected];
   Block[{$ContextPath = Join[$ContextPath, contexts]}, 
    Print@InputForm[FullDefinition[sym]]]])

contextFreeDefinition[sym_Symbol, context_String] := 
 contextFreeDefinition[sym, {context}]

contextFreeDefinition[sym_Symbol] := 
 contextFreeDefinition[sym, commonestContexts[sym]]
```

---

### withRules[]

**Caveat:**  This function does not localize variables the same way `With` and `Module` do, which means that nested localization constructs won't work as expected.  `withRules[{a -> 1, b -> 2}, With[{a=3}, b_ :> b]]` *will* replace `a` and `b` in the nested `With` and `Rule`, while `With` doesn't do this.

This is a variant of `With` that uses rules instead of `=` and `:=`:

```
ClearAll[withRules]
SetAttributes[withRules, HoldAll]
withRules[rules_, expr_] :=
  Internal`InheritedBlock[
    {Rule, RuleDelayed},
    SetAttributes[{Rule, RuleDelayed}, HoldFirst];
    Unevaluated[expr] /. rules
  ]
```

I found this useful while cleaning up code written during experimentation and localizing variables.  Occasionally I end up with parameter lists in the form of `{par1 -> 1.1, par2 -> 2.2}`.  With `withRules` parameter values are easy to inject into code previously written using global variables.

Usage is just like `With`:

```
withRules[
  {a -> 1, b -> 2},
  a+b
]
```

---

### Antialiasing 3D graphics

This is a very simple technique to antialias 3D graphics even if your graphics hardware doesn't support it natively.

```
antialias[g_, n_: 3] := 
  ImageResize[Rasterize[g, "Image", ImageResolution -> n 72], Scaled[1/n]]
```

Here's an example:

[image: Mathematica graphics] [image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that a large value for `n` or a large image size tends to expose graphics driver bugs or introduce artefacts.

---

### Notebook diff functionality

Notebook diff functionality is available in the `` <<AuthorTools` `` package, and (at least in version 8) in the undocumented `` NotebookTools` `` context.  This is a little GUI to diff two notebooks that are currently open:

```
PaletteNotebook@DynamicModule[
  {nb1, nb2}, 
  Dynamic@Column[
    {PopupMenu[Dynamic[nb1], 
      Thread[Notebooks[] -> NotebookTools`NotebookName /@ Notebooks[]]], 
     PopupMenu[Dynamic[nb2], 
      Thread[Notebooks[] -> NotebookTools`NotebookName /@ Notebooks[]]], 
     Button["Show differences", 
      CreateDocument@NotebookTools`NotebookDiff[nb1, nb2]]}]
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: All would be nice, but this does not really *localize* variables, as you can see by assigning say `a = 3; b = 4;` prior to your example call, and then calling `withRules`. You can save it by instead using the following: `SetAttributes[withRules, HoldAll];withRules[rules_, expr_] := Unevaluated[expr] /. Unevaluated[rules]`. The differences w.r.t. semantics of `With` then: 1. r.h.sides of rules now are *not* evaluated 2. `withRules` does not resolve the naming conflicts with inner scoping constructs as `With` does. The last one is pretty  serious - being good or bad thing depending on the case.

Comment: @Leonid You are completely right, it seems I never learn about checking code properly before posting ... when I use this I practically never assign values to the variables, but that is a pretty serious problem, you're right.  What do you think about the corrected version?  (I don't really care about not handling nested `With`s. This doesn't always work with the builtin localization constructs either, e.g. `With[{a=1}, Block[{a=2}, a]]`.  Do you think there's  good reason why the nested `Block` doesn't localize there, like nested `With` and `Module` does?)

Comment: @Leonid I didn't simply use `Unevaluated[rules]` because I wanted `x -> 1+1` to evaluate the RHS.

Comment: @Leonid You are actually right, the nested localization issue can be quite serious.  I think nested `With`s are easy to spot and avoid, but patterns aren't: `With[{a = 1}, a_ -> a]` localizes the inner `a` while `withRules` doesn't.  Do you know if there's any way to access Mathematica's internal localization mechanism and create new constructs (similar to `Rule`) which also localize?  I will probably delete this answer later as it's more dangerous than useful, but I'd like to play with it a bit more first.

Comment: I think your use of `InheritedBlock` is pretty cool and solves the problem very elegantly. As for the scoping conflicts, normally bindings for lexical scoping happen at "lexical binding time", which is - before run-time, while dynamic scoping binds at run-time, which might explain it. You can contrast this with the similar case for `Module`, which allows a constructive use (see e.g. here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394113/defining-a-function-with-an-optional-value-that-is-by-default-a-function-of-anot/7394668#7394668). The problem is that `Block` needs some symbol to ...

Comment: ..localize, but `With` does not create any new symbols. Still, I am not sure that this corner of the language (`With` - `Block` situation) was carefully looked at by those who designed it (may be it was). Your last comment: no, please don't delete this answer, it is very interesting! As to localization mechanism - in a way, yes. We can not *directly* access the built-in one, but we can roll our own that would localize. I have no more time right now alas, but I've done this a few times. I still find it easier to reuse parts of built-in mechanism when possible. Hope we discuss this again soon.

Comment: Rather than deleting this answer, you may clearly mark it as experimental (or otherwise mention its possible limitations) with the bold font at the top of it. Regarding scoping, you may find this discussion interesting: http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/May/msg00206.html, although my posts there are mostly based on guesses and intuitive feelings.

Answer (score 9):

Recursive pure functions (`#0`) seem to be one of the darker corners of the language. Here are a couple of non-trivial examples of their use , where this is really useful (not that they can not be done without it). The following is a pretty concise and reasonably fast function to find connected components in a graph, given a list of edges specified as pairs of vertices:

```
ClearAll[setNew, componentsBFLS];
setNew[x_, x_] := Null;
setNew[lhs_, rhs_]:=lhs:=Function[Null, (#1 := #0[##]); #2, HoldFirst][lhs, rhs];

componentsBFLS[lst_List] := Module[{f}, setNew @@@ Map[f, lst, {2}];
   GatherBy[Tally[Flatten@lst][[All, 1]], f]];
```

What happens here is that we first map a dummy symbol on each of the vertex numbers, and then set up a way that, given a pair of vertices `{f[5],f[10]}`, say, then `f[5]` would evaluate to `f[10]`. The recursive pure function is used as a path compressor (to set up memoization in such a way that instead of long chains like `f[1]=f[3],f[3]=f[4],f[4]=f[2], ...`, memoized values get corrected whenever a new "root" of the component is discovered. This gives a significant speed-up. Because we use assignment, we need it to be HoldAll, which makes this construct even more obscure and more attractive ). This function is a result of on and off-line Mathgroup discussion involving Fred Simons, Szabolcs Horvat, DrMajorBob and yours truly. Example:

```
In[13]:= largeTest=RandomInteger[{1,80000},{40000,2}];

In[14]:= componentsBFLS[largeTest]//Short//Timing
Out[14]= {0.828,{{33686,62711,64315,11760,35384,45604,10212,52552,63986,  
     <<8>>,40962,7294,63002,38018,46533,26503,43515,73143,5932},<<10522>>}}
```

It is certainly much slower than a built-in, but for the size of code, quite fast still IMO.

Another example: here is a recursive realization of `Select`, based on linked lists and recursive pure functions:

```
selLLNaive[x_List, test_] :=
  Flatten[If[TrueQ[test[#1]],
     {#1, If[#2 === {}, {}, #0 @@ #2]},
     If[#2 === {}, {}, #0 @@ #2]] & @@ Fold[{#2, #1} &, {}, Reverse[x]]];
```

For example,

```
In[5]:= Block[
         {$RecursionLimit= Infinity},
         selLLNaive[Range[3000],EvenQ]]//Short//Timing

Out[5]= {0.047,{2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,
 <<1470>>,2972,2974,2976,2978,2980,2982,2984,2986,2988,2990,
  2992,2994,2996,2998,3000}}
```

It is however not properly tail recursive, and will blow the stack (crash the kernel) for larger lists. Here is the tail-recursive version:

```
selLLTailRec[x_List, test_] :=
Flatten[
 If[Last[#1] === {},
  If[TrueQ[test[First[#1]]],
   {#2, First[#1]}, #2],
  (* else *)
  #0[Last[#1],
   If[TrueQ[test[First[#1]]], {#2, First[#1]}, #2]
   ]] &[Fold[{#2, #1} &, {}, Reverse[x]], {}]];
```

For example,

```
In[6]:= Block[{$IterationLimit= Infinity},
       selLLTailRec[Range[500000],EvenQ]]//Short//Timing
Out[6]= {2.39,{2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,
       <<249978>>,499980,499982,499984,499986,499988,499990,499992,
        499994,499996,499998,500000}}
```

Comment: The function for connected components is still a favourite of mine :-)

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, it is pretty cool. You and Fred did most of it, Bobby and me only added a few refinements, IIRC.

Answer (score 8):

This is recipe from Stan Wagon's book...use it when built-in Plot behaves erratically due to lack of precision

```
Options[PrecisePlot] = {PrecisionGoal -> 6};
PrecisePlot[f_, {x_, a_, b_}, opts___] := Module[{g, pg},
   pg = PrecisionGoal /. {opts} /. Options[PrecisePlot];
   SetAttributes[g, NumericFunction];
   g[z_?InexactNumberQ] := Evaluate[f /. x -> z];
   Plot[N[g[SetPrecision[y, \[Infinity]]], pg], {y, a, b},
    Evaluate[Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Plot]]]]];
```

I often use the following trick from Kristjan Kannike's when I need "dictionary-like" behavior from Mathematica's downvalues

```
index[downvalue_, 
   dict_] := (downvalue[[1]] /. HoldPattern[dict[x_]] -> x) // 
   ReleaseHold;
value[downvalue_] := downvalue[[-1]];
indices[dict_] := 
  Map[#[[1]] /. {HoldPattern[dict[x_]] -> x} &, DownValues[dict]] // 
   ReleaseHold;
values[dict_] := Map[#[[-1]] &, DownValues[dict]];
items[dict_] := Map[{index[#, dict], value[#]} &, DownValues[dict]];
indexQ[dict_, index_] := 
  If[MatchQ[dict[index], HoldPattern[dict[index]]], False, True];

(* Usage example: *)
(* Count number of times each subexpression occurs in an expression *)
expr = Cos[x + Cos[Cos[x] + Sin[x]]] + Cos[Cos[x] + Sin[x]]
Map[(counts[#] = If[indexQ[counts, #], counts[#] + 1, 1]; #) &, expr, Infinity];
items[counts]
```

When evaluation results are confusing, sometimes it helps to dump evaluation steps into a text file

```
SetAttributes[recordSteps, HoldAll];
recordSteps[expr_] :=
 Block[{$Output = List@OpenWrite["~/temp/msgStream.m"]}, 
  TracePrint[Unevaluated[expr], _?(FreeQ[#, Off] &), 
   TraceInternal -> True];
  Close /@ $Output;
  Thread[Union@
    Cases[ReadList["~/temp/msgStream.m", HoldComplete[Expression]], 
     symb_Symbol /; 
       AtomQ@Unevaluated@symb && 
        Context@Unevaluated@symb === "System`" :> 
      HoldComplete@symb, {0, Infinity}, Heads -> True], HoldComplete]
  ]

(* Usage example: *)
(* puts steps of evaluation of 1+2+Sin[5]) into ~/temp/msgStream.m *)
recordSteps[1+2+Sin[5]]
```

Comment: An usage sample would be great. Try to post one when you have time.

Comment: Do you know Kristjan? I used to work in the same group with him in Helsinki. Nice guy, small world.

Comment: Nope, found his code on the web. Actually, tried to email him to fix a small bug in the code, but the email on his webpage no longer works

Answer (score 8):

It is possible to run MathKernel in batch mode by using undocumented [command-line options `-batchinput` and `-batchoutput`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542537/):

```
math -batchinput -batchoutput < input.m > outputfile.txt
```

(where `input.m` is the batch input file ending with the newline character, `outputfile.txt` is the file to which the output will be redirected).

In *Mathematica* v.>=6 the MathKernel has undocumented command-line option:

```
-noicon
```

which controls whether the MathKernel will have visible icon on the Taskbar (at least under Windows).

The FrontEnd (at least from v.5) has undocumented command-line option

```
-b
```

which disables the splash-screen and allows to run the *Mathematica* FrontEnd much faster

and option

```
-directlaunch
```

which [disables the mechanism which launches the most recent *Mathematica* version installed](http://groups.google.ru/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_frm/thread/99d3c9176b70aa8f#) instead of launching the version associated with .nb files in the system registry.

Another way to do this probably [is](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/msg/6b9fda8480ccb636):

> Instead of launching the
>   Mathematica.exe binary in the
>   installation directory, launch the
>   Mathematica.exe binary in
>   SystemFiles\FrontEnd\Binaries\Windows.
>   The former is a simple launcher
>   program which tries its hardest to
>   redirect requests for opening
>   notebooks to running copies of the
>   user interface.  The latter is the
>   user interface binary itself.

It is handy to combine the last command line option with setting global FrontEnd option `VersionedPreferences->True` [which disables sharing of preferences between different *Mathematica* versions installed](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/msg/b08ead07171bd17e):

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, VersionedPreferences -> True]
```

(The above should be evaluated in the most recent *Mathematica* version installed.)

In *Mathematica* 8 [this is controlled in the Preferences dialog, in the System pane, under the setting "Create and maintain version specific front end preferences"](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/msg/2dde22fa3436ac43).

It is possible to get incomplete list of command-line options of the FrontEnd by using undocumented key `-h` (the code for Windows):

```
SetDirectory[$InstallationDirectory <> 
   "\\SystemFiles\\FrontEnd\\Binaries\\Windows\\"];
Import["!Mathematica -h", "Text"]
```

gives:

```
Usage:  Mathematica [options] [files]
Valid options:
    -h (--help):  prints help message
    -cleanStart (--cleanStart):  removes existing preferences upon startup
    -clean (--clean):  removes existing preferences upon startup
    -nogui (--nogui):  starts in a mode which is initially hidden
    -server (--server):  starts in a mode which disables user interaction
    -activate (--activate):  makes application frontmost upon startup
    -topDirectory (--topDirectory):  specifies the directory to search for resources and initialization files
    -preferencesDirectory (--preferencesDirectory):  specifies the directory to search for user AddOns and preference files
    -password (--password):  specifies the password contents
    -pwfile (--pwfile):  specifies the path for the password file
    -pwpath (--pwpath):  specifies the directory to search for the password file
    -b (--b):  launches without the splash screen
    -min (--min):  launches as minimized
```

Other options include:

```
-directLaunch:  force this FE to start
-32:  force the 32-bit FE to start
-matchingkernel:  sets the frontend to use the kernel of matching bitness
-Embedding:  specifies that this instance is being used to host content out of process
```

---

**Are there other potentially useful command-line options of the MathKernel and the FrontEnd? Please share if you know.**

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770519/command-line-arguments-of-mathematica-kernel-and-frontend).

Comment: "matching bitness?"  What does that mean?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Probably this option has a sense only under 64-bit systems in combination with option `-32` and means that bitness of the MathKernel used by the FrontEnd will match bitness of the operating system (64 bit). It seems that in other cases this option will not change anything.

Answer (score 7):

My favorite hacks are small code-generating macros that allow you to replace a bunch of standard boilerplate commands with one short one.  Alternatively, you can create commands for opening/creating notebooks.

Here is what I've been using for a while in my day-to-day Mathematica workflow.  I found myself performing the following a lot:

1. Make a notebook have a private context, load package(s) I need, make it autosave.
2. After working with this notebook for a while, I'd want to do some throw away scratch computations in a separate notebook, with its own private context, while having access to definitions I've been using in the "main" notebook.  Because I set up the private context, this requires to manually adjust $ContextPath

Doing all this by hand over and over is a pain, so let's automate!   First, some utility code:

```
(* Credit goes to Sasha for SelfDestruct[] *)
SetAttributes[SelfDestruct, HoldAllComplete];
SelfDestruct[e_] := (If[$FrontEnd =!= $Failed,
   SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, EvaluationCell]; 
   NotebookDelete[]]; e)

writeAndEval[nb_,boxExpr_]:=(
    NotebookWrite[nb,  CellGroupData[{Cell[BoxData[boxExpr],"Input"]}]];
    SelectionMove[nb, Previous, Cell]; 
    SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell];
    SelectionEvaluate[nb];
)

ExposeContexts::badargs = 
  "Exposed contexts should be given as a list of strings.";
ExposeContexts[list___] := 
 Module[{ctList}, ctList = Flatten@List@list; 
  If[! MemberQ[ctList, Except[_String]],AppendTo[$ContextPath, #] & /@ ctList, 
   Message[ExposeContexts::badargs]];
  $ContextPath = DeleteDuplicates[$ContextPath];
  $ContextPath]

    Autosave[x:(True|False)] := SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],NotebookAutoSave->x];
```

Now, let's create a macro that's going to put the following cells in the notebook:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CellContext -> Notebook]
Needs["LVAutils`"]
Autosave[True]
```

And here's the macro:

```
MyPrivatize[exposedCtxts : ({__String} | Null) : Null]:=
  SelfDestruct@Module[{contBox,lvaBox,expCtxtBox,assembledStatements,strList},
    contBox = MakeBoxes[SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CellContext -> Notebook]];
    lvaBox = MakeBoxes[Needs["LVAutils`"]];

    assembledStatements = {lvaBox,MakeBoxes[Autosave[True]],"(*********)"};
    assembledStatements = Riffle[assembledStatements,"\[IndentingNewLine]"]//RowBox;
    writeAndEval[InputNotebook[],contBox];
    writeAndEval[InputNotebook[],assembledStatements];
    If[exposedCtxts =!= Null,
       strList = Riffle[("\"" <> # <> "\"") & /@ exposedCtxts, ","];
       expCtxtBox = RowBox[{"ExposeContexts", "[", RowBox[{"{", RowBox[strList], "}"}], "]"}];
       writeAndEval[InputNotebook[],expCtxtBox];
      ]
 ]
```

Now when I type in `MyPrivatize[]` is creates the private context and loads my standard package.  Now let's create a command that will open a new scratch notebook with its own private context (so that you can hack there with wild abandon without the risk of screwing up the definitions), but has access to your current contexts.

```
SpawnScratch[] := SelfDestruct@Module[{nb,boxExpr,strList},
    strList = Riffle[("\"" <> # <> "\"") & /@ $ContextPath, ","];
    boxExpr = RowBox[{"MyPrivatize", "[",
        RowBox[{"{", RowBox[strList], "}"}], "]"}];
    nb = CreateDocument[];
    writeAndEval[nb,boxExpr];
]
```

The cool thing about this is that due to `SelfDestruct`, when the command runs it leaves no trace in the current notebook -- which is good, because otherwise it would just create clutter.

For extra style points, you can create keyword triggers for these macros using `InputAutoReplacements`, but I'll leave this as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 7):

### PutAppend with PageWidth -> Infinity

In *Mathematica* using of the `PutAppend` command is the most straightforward way to maintain a running log file with results of intermediate computations. But it uses by default `PageWith->78` setting when exporting expressions to a file and so there is no guarantee that every intermediate output will take only one line in the log.

`PutAppend` does not have any options itself but tracing its evaluations reveals that it is based on the `OpenAppend` function which has the `PageWith` option and allows changing its default value by the `SetOptions` command:

```
In[2]:= Trace[x>>>"log.txt",TraceInternal->True]
Out[2]= {x>>>log.txt,{OpenAppend[log.txt,CharacterEncoding->PrintableASCII],OutputStream[log.txt,15]},Null}
```

So we can get `PutAppend` to append only one line at a time by setting:

```
SetOptions[OpenAppend, PageWidth -> Infinity]
```

---

**UPDATE**

There is a [bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31612/280) introduced in version 10 (fixed in version 11.3): `SetOptions` no longer affects the behavior of `OpenWrite` and `OpenAppend`.

A workaround is to implement your own version of `PutAppend` with explicit `PageWidth -> Infinity` option:

```
Clear[myPutAppend]
myPutAppend[expr_, pathtofile_String] :=
 (Write[#, expr]; Close[#];) &[OpenAppend[pathtofile, PageWidth -> Infinity]]
```

Note that we also may implement it via `WriteString` as shown in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/77835/280) answer, but in this case it will be necessary to preliminarily convert the expression into the corresponding `InputForm` via `ToString[expr, InputForm]`.

Answer (score 6):

I was just looking through one of my packages for inclusion in this, and found some messages that I defined that work wonders:  `Debug::<some name>`.  By default, they are turned off, so don't produce much overhead.  But, I can litter my code with them, and turn them on if I need to figure out exactly how a bit of code is behaving.

Comment: From The Help > Since Version 2.0 (released in 1991), Debug has been superseded by Trace.

Comment: @belisarius, you missed the point.  It is neither the `Debug` nor `Trace` functions; it is a set of messages I created that I can litter my code with to turn on/off at will.  They are prefaced with the word `Debug`, in the same way a `usage` msg is prefaced with the name of the function.  It provides the same functionality as placing a bunch of `cout` statements in c++ code.

Comment: Ohh... sorry. I got confused 'cause I never graduated from kindergarten for not learning "Capitals are for Countries" :D

Answer (score 6):

One of the things that bothers me about the built-in scoping constructs is that they evaluate all of the local variable definitions at once, so you can't write for example

```
With[{a = 5, b = 2 * a},
    ...
]
```

So a while ago I came up with a macro called WithNest that allows you to do this. I find it handy, since it lets you keep variable bindings local without having to do something like

```
Module[{a = 5,b},
    b = 2 * a;
    ...
]
```

In the end, the best way I could find to do this was by using a special symbol to make it easier to recurse over the list of bindings, and I put the definition into its own package to keep this symbol hidden. Maybe someone has a simpler solution to this problem?

If you want to try it out, put the following into a file called `Scoping.m`:

```
BeginPackage["Scoping`"];

WithNest::usage=
"WithNest[{var1=val1,var2=val2,...},body] works just like With, except that
values are evaluated in order and later values have access to earlier ones.
For example, val2 can use var1 in its definition.";

Begin["`Private`"];

(* Set up a custom symbol that works just like Hold. *)
SetAttributes[WithNestHold,HoldAll];

(* The user-facing call.  Give a list of bindings and a body that's not
our custom symbol, and we start a recursive call by using the custom
symbol. *)
WithNest[bindings_List,body:Except[_WithNestHold]]:=
WithNest[bindings,WithNestHold[body]];

(* Base case of recursive definition *)
WithNest[{},WithNestHold[body_]]:=body;

WithNest[{bindings___,a_},WithNestHold[body_]]:=
WithNest[
{bindings},
WithNestHold[With[List@a,body]]];

SyntaxInformation[WithNest]={"ArgumentsPattern"->{{__},_}};
SetAttributes[WithNest,{HoldAll,Protected}];

End[];

EndPackage[];
```

Comment: Janus posted a version of this, and references your question on MathGroup:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190845/custom-notation-question/4191096#4191096

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! It's been a while since I looked at this stuff, and it's interesting to see all these other approaches.

Answer (score 5):

This one was written by Alberto Di Lullo, (who doesn't appear to be on Stack Overflow).

`CopyToClipboard`, for Mathematica 7 (in Mathematica 8 it's built in)

```
CopyToClipboard[expr_] := 
  Module[{nb}, 
   nb = CreateDocument[Null, Visible -> False, WindowSelected -> True];
   NotebookWrite[nb, Cell[OutputFormData@expr], All];
   FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken[nb, "Copy"]];
   NotebookClose@nb];
```

Original post: http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Jun/msg00148.html

I have found this routine useful for copying large real numbers to the clipboard in ordinary decimal form.  E.g. `CopyToClipboard["123456789.12345"]`

`Cell[OutputFormData@expr]` neatly removes the quotes.

Answer (score 5):

This code makes a palette that uploads the selection to Stack Exchange as an image. On Windows, an extra button is provided that gives a more faithful rendering of the selection.

Copy the code into a notebook cell and evaluate. Then pop out the palette from the output, and install it using `Palettes -> Install Palette...`

If you have any trouble with it, post a comment here. Download the notebook version [here](http://ge.tt/9Ymx9qB?c).

---

```
Begin["SOUploader`"];

Global`palette = PaletteNotebook@DynamicModule[{},

   Column[{
     Button["Upload to SE",
      With[{img = rasterizeSelection1[]},
       If[img === $Failed, Beep[], uploadWithPreview[img]]],
      Appearance -> "Palette"],

     If[$OperatingSystem === "Windows",

      Button["Upload to SE (pp)",
       With[{img = rasterizeSelection2[]},
        If[img === $Failed, Beep[], uploadWithPreview[img]]],
       Appearance -> "Palette"],

      Unevaluated@Sequence[]
      ]
     }],

   (* Init start *)
   Initialization :>
    (

     stackImage::httperr = "Server returned respose code: `1`";
     stackImage::err = "Server returner error: `1`";

     stackImage[g_] :=
      Module[
       {getVal, url, client, method, data, partSource, part, entity,
        code, response, error, result},

       getVal[res_, key_String] :=
        With[{k = "var " <> key <> " = "},
         StringTrim[

          First@StringCases[
            First@Select[res, StringMatchQ[#, k ~~ ___] &],
            k ~~ v___ ~~ ";" :> v],
          "'"]
         ];

       data = ExportString[g, "PNG"];

       JLink`JavaBlock[
        url = "http://stackoverflow.com/upload/image";
        client =
         JLink`JavaNew["org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient"];
        method =
         JLink`JavaNew[
          "org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod", url];
        partSource =
         JLink`JavaNew[
          "org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.\
ByteArrayPartSource", "mmagraphics.png",
          JLink`MakeJavaObject[data]@toCharArray[]];
        part =
         JLink`JavaNew[
          "org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.FilePart",
          "name", partSource];
        part@setContentType["image/png"];
        entity =
         JLink`JavaNew[
          "org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.\
MultipartRequestEntity", {part}, method@getParams[]];
        method@setRequestEntity[entity];
        code = client@executeMethod[method];
        response = method@getResponseBodyAsString[];
        ];

       If[code =!= 200, Message[stackImage::httperr, code];
        Return[$Failed]];
       response = StringTrim /@ StringSplit[response, "\n"];

       error = getVal[response, "error"];
       result = getVal[response, "result"];
       If[StringMatchQ[result, "http*"],
        result,
        Message[stackImage::err, error]; $Failed]
       ];

     stackMarkdown[g_] :=
      "![Mathematica graphics](" <> stackImage[g] <> ")";

     stackCopyMarkdown[g_] := Module[{nb, markdown},
       markdown = Check[stackMarkdown[g], $Failed];
       If[markdown =!= $Failed,
        nb = NotebookCreate[Visible -> False];
        NotebookWrite[nb, Cell[markdown, "Text"]];
        SelectionMove[nb, All, Notebook];
        FrontEndTokenExecute[nb, "Copy"];
        NotebookClose[nb];
        ]
       ];

     (* Returns available vertical screen space,
     taking into account screen elements like the taskbar and menu *)


     screenHeight[] := -Subtract @@
        Part[ScreenRectangle /. Options[$FrontEnd, ScreenRectangle],
         2];

     uploadWithPreview[img_Image] :=
      CreateDialog[
       Column[{
         Style["Upload image to the Stack Exchange network?", Bold],
         Pane[

          Image[img, Magnification -> 1], {Automatic,
           Min[screenHeight[] - 140, 1 + ImageDimensions[img][[2]]]},
          Scrollbars -> Automatic, AppearanceElements -> {},
          ImageMargins -> 0
          ],
         Item[
          ChoiceButtons[{"Upload and copy MarkDown"}, \
{stackCopyMarkdown[img]; DialogReturn[]}], Alignment -> Right]
         }],
       WindowTitle -> "Upload image to Stack Exchange?"
       ];

     (* Multiplatform, fixed-width version.
        The default max width is 650 to fit Stack Exchange *)
     rasterizeSelection1[maxWidth_: 650] :=
      Module[{target, selection, image},
       selection = NotebookRead[SelectedNotebook[]];
       If[MemberQ[Hold[{}, $Failed, NotebookRead[$Failed]], selection],

        $Failed, (* There was nothing selected *)

        target =
         CreateDocument[{}, WindowSelected -> False, Visible -> False,
           WindowSize -> maxWidth];
        NotebookWrite[target, selection];
        image = Rasterize[target, "Image"];
        NotebookClose[target];
        image
        ]
       ];

     (* Windows-only pixel perfect version *)
     rasterizeSelection2[] :=
      If[
       MemberQ[Hold[{}, $Failed, NotebookRead[$Failed]],
        NotebookRead[SelectedNotebook[]]],

       $Failed, (* There was nothing selected *)

       Module[{tag},
        FrontEndExecute[
         FrontEndToken[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[], "CopySpecial",
          "MGF"]];
        Catch[
         NotebookGet@ClipboardNotebook[] /.
          r_RasterBox :>
           Block[{},
            Throw[Image[First[r], "Byte", ColorSpace -> "RGB"], tag] /;
              True];
         $Failed,
         tag
         ]
        ]
       ];
     )
   (* Init end *)
   ]

End[];
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure a lot of people have encountered the situation where they run some stuff, realizing it not only stuck the program, but they also *haven't saved for the last 10 minutes!*

#### EDIT

After suffering from this for some time, I one day found out that **one can create auto-save** from within the *Mathematica* code. I think that using such auto-save have helped me a lot in the past, and I always felt that *the possibility itself* was something that not a lot of people are aware that they can do.

The original code I used is at the bottom. Thanks to the comments I've found out that it is problematic, and that it is much better to do it in an alternative way, using `ScheduledTask` (which will work only in *Mathematica* 8).

Code for this can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193804/automatically-saving-notebook-or-other-type-files-in-mathematica-files/7197175#7197175) from `Sjoerd C. de Vries`
(Since I'm not sure if it's OK to copy it to here, I'm leaving it as a link only.)

---

The solution below is using `Dynamic`. It will save the notebook every 60 seconds, but apparently **only if its cell is visible**. I'm leaving it here only for completion reasons. (and for users of *Mathematica* 6 and 7)

#### /EDIT

To solve it I use this code in the beginning of a notebook:

```
Dynamic[Refresh[NotebookSave[]; DateString[], UpdateInterval -> 60]]
```

This will save your work every 60 seconds.
I prefer it to `NotebookAutoSave[]` because it saves before the input is processed, and because some files are more text than input.

I originally found it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Mathematica#Criticisms

Note that once running this line, saving will happen even if you close and re-open your file (as long as dynamic updating is enabled).

Also, since there is no undo in *Mathematica*, be careful not to delete all your content, since saving will make it irreversible (as a precaution move, I remove this code from every finished notebook)

Comment: you could also save it with a different name (eg by appending the current time and date to the end of the filename) and maybe in a specific directory ("Backups", say). this would be like a primitive form of versioning.

Comment: You can do something like `NotebookSave[SelectedNotebook[], "work-" <> IntegerString[i] <> ".nb"]; i++`, but I think that any kind of referencing to the current notebook name will become recursive.

Comment: You can obtain the name by `"WindowTitle" /. NotebookInformation[SelectedNotebook[]]`. You can also use a scheduled task to save periodically (rather than a `Dynamic`)

Comment: I meant that if I do `NotebookSave[..., CurrentName <> "1"]`, than after 15 saves, I will have 15 times `1` in the end of the filename. If I could do `NotebookSaveACopy[]` it would skip this problem, but there is no such function that I know of.

Comment: I'm curious - What are the advantages (in this case) of scheduled task over `Dynamic`?

Comment: To clarify: It's possible to append (or prepend) something (i.e. the current time) to the notebook name and save it, but one must be careful to remove it in the next save (using string manipulation) before appending something else (i.e. a new time).

Comment: you can first create a new notebook, then save that with the name of the current notebook plus (eg) the time. For instance, like this: `newnb = NotebookPut@NotebookGet[SelectedNotebook[]]` (although I guess this will create a copy and open it in the frontend, which is disruptive). I don't know if this can be prevented (I know little about frontend programming).

Comment: I thought `Dynamic` objects only get refreshed when they are visible, so I would not be sure that this method would work if eg you scroll the `Dynamic` object out of the visible area. Then again, I haven't tried. In any case, I merely offered it as a suggestion.

Comment: @acl I agree. This is not a good solution. Additionally, UpdateInterval doesn't specify the time between updates, it specifies the _maximum_ time between updates. There can be many more updates in this interval (as long as the Dynamic is visible). Better solutions are discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7193804/615464

Comment: You can test this by using `Dynamic[Refresh[i++, UpdateInterval -> 1, TrackedSymbols -> {}]]`. Scroll the incrementing number from sight, wait a minute, scroll back and see the number isn't incremented by 60. About `UpdateInterval`: this is usually used if possible, but if your code includes variables that change, this change triggers a new refresh before the interval ends. Try the above line without `TrackedSymbols`

Comment: @Sjoerd : I can say from my experience (I used this specific code for ~2 years), that it was **always updating every 60 sec**. It was verified with the `DateString`. I was experimenting a bit now, and another `Dynamic` codes indeed behave strange sometimes, but nevertheless, I still know that mine is a working solution.

Comment: The only point I can add is that I always had put this piece of code in the **top** of a document, so it was 'visible' when I opened the document. I suspect that the auto-save in this code will only start after the code is visible (but continue afterward even when it's hidden)

Comment: Anyway, the approach with 'scheduled task' seems as good. I wanted to say that the main point of my answer is not the exact piece of code I used, but the fact that **using any suitable code will prevent a possible loss of work**, so my addition to everyone's toolbag is: use a code to autosave, and one day you'll thank yourself for doing so :).

Comment: @j0ker5 Try my above code and you can see that UpdateInterval doesn't always force updates to be spaced with the specified interval. This code also shows that **Dynamic only works if the cell it is contained in is visible in the frontend**. It really stops the moment it is out of sight. **People really shouldn't trust this code to save their files because it doesn't. Its dangerous**

Comment: @Sjoerd I made some tests with my code and understood now that you are correct. I've edited my answer to reflect it and added a link to your solution. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: PS - I believe that adding here the whole code from @Sjoerd answer may be beneficial for this community wiki, but I don't feel OK to just copy-paste it. You are welcome to add it here, if you like.

Comment: it's generally OK to copy and paste it, since you give attribution anyway (if @Sjoerd minds I'm sure he'll let you know).

Comment: @acl I OK-ed in chat. Don't know where to find it now ;-)

Comment: I think this could be a very nice application for Scheduled Tasks

Answer (score 3):

Remember that The Mathematica Book is also available online at http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/ - though it's superseded by the current documentation at http://reference.wolfram.com

Answer (score 3):

I find it really useful when developing packages to add this keyboard shortcut to my `SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/Windows/KeyEventTranslations.tr` file.

```
(* Evaluate Initialization Cells: Real useful for reloading library changes. *)

Item[KeyEvent["i", Modifiers -> {Control, Command}],
    FrontEndExecute[
        FrontEndToken[
            SelectedNotebook[],
            "EvaluateInitialization"]]],
```

Next for every `Packagename.m` I make a `PackagenameTest.nb` notebook for testing and the first 2 cells of the test notebook are set as initialization cells. In the first cell I put

```
Needs["PackageManipulations`"]
```

to load the very useful [PackageManipulations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8443756/439902) library which was written by Leonid. The second cell contains

```
PackageRemove["Packagename`Private`"]
PackageRemove["Packagename`"]
PackageReload["Packagename`"]
```

which all do the actual package reloading. Note the first two lines are there only to `Remove` all symbols as I like to keep the contexts as clean as possible.

Then the workflow for writing and testing a package becomes something like this.

1. Save changes to `Packagename.m`.
2. Go to `PackagenameTest.nb` and do `CTRL + ALT + i`.

This causes the initialization cells to reload the package, which makes testing real simple.

Answer (score 1):

Following function `format[expr_]` can be used to indent/format unformatted `mathematica` expressions that spans over a page

```
indent[str_String, ob_String, cb_String, delim_String] := 
  Module[{ind, indent, f, tab}, ind = 0; tab = "    ";
   indent[i_, tab_, nl_] := nl <> Nest[tab <> ToString[#] &, "", i];
   f[c_] := (indent[ind, "", " "] <> c <> indent[++ind, tab, "\n"]) /;StringMatchQ[ob, ___ ~~ c ~~ ___];
   f[c_] := (indent[--ind, "", " "] <> c <> indent[ind, tab, "\n"]) /;StringMatchQ[cb, ___ ~~ c ~~ ___];
   f[c_] := (c <> indent[ind, tab, "\n"]) /;StringMatchQ[delim, ___ ~~ c ~~ ___];
   f[c_] := c;
   f /@ Characters@str // StringJoin];
format[expr_] := indent[expr // InputForm // ToString, "[({", "])}", ";"];

(*    
format[Hold@Module[{ind, indent, f, tab}, ind = 0; tab = "    ";
 indent[i_, tab_, nl_] := nl <> Nest[tab <> ToString[#] &, "", i];
 f[c_] := (indent[ind, "", " "] <> c <> indent[++ind, tab, "\n"]) /;StringMatchQ[ob, ___ ~~ c ~~ ___];
 f[c_] := (indent[--ind, "", " "] <> c <> indent[ind, tab, "\n"]) /;StringMatchQ[cb, ___ ~~ c ~~ ___];
 f[c_] := (c <> indent[ind, tab, "\n"]) /;StringMatchQ[delim, ___ ~~ c ~~ ___];
 f[c_] := c;
 f /@ Characters@str // StringJoin]]
*)
```

---

ref: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3088/indent-a-string-using-given-parentheses

Comment: What are you using this for in practice?  The output is a bit too *"funny"* to be readable either when applied to your code or to data (lists, `format@RandomInteger[10,{3,3}]`): http://pastebin.com/nUT54Emq  Since you already have the basics and you are interested in this, can you improve the code to produce a usefully readable formatting?  Then the next step would be to make a paste button that will create an input cell with nicely indented Mathematica code (preferably preserving comments!!) See also [my related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8034298/695132).