# Customizing Mathematica shortcuts

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Is there a place I can view/change global shortcut options like <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd> (turn into Input style)?

In particular, I need a faster way of creating bulleted lists. It's the style "Item" in the Cell context menu which doesn't have its own shortcut.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20080608124549/http://www.lamberta.org/blog/mathematica-keybindings/) is a nice article.

Also, [FROM HERE](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2005/May/msg00200.html/wiki/wiki.jsp?pageName=FAQ_Front_ends) (unchecked)

> Question:
>   How do I modify the front end to add new keyboard shortcuts?
>   Answer:
>   (mathgroup May 2005, trevor baca:)
>
> I've been mucking around in KeyEventTranslations.tr setting up keyboard shortcuts recently and i've learned that front end tokens are pretty cool. [this wolfram page](http://documents.wolfram.com/v5/FrontEnd/FrontEndTokens) gives pretty good docs.
>
> Anyway, here are three that i had to work a little to get going (with good help from the mathgroup, as always).

- for a quit kernel keyboard shortcut, add the following to KeyEventTranslations.tr:

```
       Item[KeyEvent["q", Modifiers -> {Control, Option}],
               FrontEndExecute[
                       FrontEndToken[
                                SelectedNotebook[ ],
                                "EvaluatorQuit",
                                Automatic
                       ]
               ]
       ]
```

- for an initialization cell toggle keyboard shortcut (repeated from previous thread), add the following to  KeyEventTranslations.tr:

```
      Item[KeyEvent["i", Modifiers -> {Command, Control}],
               FrontEndExecute[
                       FrontEndToken[
                               SelectedNotebook[ ],
                               "InitializationCell",
                               "Toggle"
                       ]
               ]
       ]
```

- for a save as package keyboard shortcut, add the following to KeyEventTranslations.tr:

```
       Item[KeyEvent["k", Modifiers -> {Control, Option}], 
           SaveRenameSpecial["Package"]]
```

**Edit**

I found a full list of the (undocumented) front-end tokens.  Hope you'll understand that these are unsupported!

```
{"AllWindowsFront", "BackgroundDialog", "Balance", "BringToFront",
"CellContextDialog", "CellGroup", "CellLabelsToTags", "CellMerge",
"CellSplit", "CellTagsEditDialog", "CellTagsEmpty", "CellTagsFind",
"CellUngroup", "Clear", "ClearCellOptions", "ClearNoAutoScroll",
"Close", "CloseAll", "CloseMain", "ColorSelectorDialog",
"ColorsPanel", "CompleteSelection", "Copy", "CopyCell",
"CopySpecial", "CreateCounterBoxDialog", "CreateGridBoxDialog",
"CreateHyperlinkDialog", "CreateInlineCell", "CreateValueBoxDialog",
"Cut", "CycleNotebooksBackward", "CycleNotebooksForward",
"DebuggerAbort", "DebuggerClearAllBreakpoints", "DebuggerContinue",
"DebuggerContinueToSelection", "DebuggerFinish",
"DebuggerResetProfile", "DebuggerShowProfile", "DebuggerStep",
"DebuggerStepIn", "DebuggerStepInBody", "DebuggerStepOut",
"DebuggerToggleBreakpoint", "DebuggerToggleWatchpoint",
"DeleteGeneratedCells", "DeleteIndent", "DeleteInvisible",
"DuplicatePreviousInput", "DuplicatePreviousOutput",
"EditStyleDefinitions", "EnterSubsession", "Evaluate",
"EvaluateCells", "EvaluateInitialization", "EvaluateNextCell",
"EvaluateNotebook", "EvaluatorAbort", "EvaluatorHalt",
"EvaluatorInterrupt", "EvaluatorQuit", "EvaluatorStart",
"ExitSubsession", "ExpirationDialog", "ExplainBeepDialog",
"ExplainColoringDialog", "ExpressionLinewrap", "FileNameDialog",
"FindDialog", "FindEvaluatingCell", "FindNextMisspelling",
"FindNextWarningColor", "FinishNesting", "FixCellHeight",
"FixCellWidth", "FontColorDialog", "FontFamilyB", "FontPanel",
"FontSizeDialog", "FrontEndHide", "FrontEndQuit",
"FrontEndQuitNonInteractive", "GenerateImageCaches",
"GenerateNotebook", "GeneratePalette", "GraphicsAlign",
"GraphicsCoordinatesDialog", "GraphicsOriginalSize",
"GraphicsPlotRangeAll", "GraphicsPlotRangeAutomatic",
"GraphicsPlotRangeFixed", "GraphicsRender", "Group",
"HandleShiftReturn", "HeadersFootersDialog", "HelpDialog",
"HyperlinkGo", "HyperlinkGoBack", "HyperlinkGoForward", "Import",
"ImportPictures", "ImportStyleDefinitions", "Indent",
"InsertClipPlane", "InsertMatchingBraces", "InsertMatchingBrackets",
"InsertMatchingParentheses", "InsertNewGraphic", "InsertObject",
"InsertRawExpression", "InsertSoftReturn", "LicAuthFailureDialog",
"MacintoshOpenDeskAccessory", "MenuListBoxFormFormatTypes",
"MenuListCellEvaluators", "MenuListCellTags",
"MenuListCommonDefaultFormatTypesInput",
"MenuListCommonDefaultFormatTypesInputInline",
"MenuListCommonDefaultFormatTypesOutput",
"MenuListCommonDefaultFormatTypesOutputInline",
"MenuListCommonDefaultFormatTypesText",
"MenuListCommonDefaultFormatTypesTextInline",
"MenuListConvertFormatTypes", "MenuListDisplayAsFormatTypes",
"MenuListExportClipboardSpecial", "MenuListFonts",
"MenuListFontSubstitutions", "MenuListGlobalEvaluators",
"MenuListHelpWindows", "MenuListNotebookEvaluators",
"MenuListNotebooksMenu", "MenuListPackageWindows",
"MenuListPalettesMenu", "MenuListPaletteWindows",
"MenuListPlayerWindows", "MenuListPlugInCommands",
"MenuListPrintingStyleEnvironments", "MenuListQuitEvaluators",
"MenuListRelatedFilesMenu", "MenuListSaveClipboardSpecial",
"MenuListScreenStyleEnvironments", "MenuListStartEvaluators",
"MenuListStyleDefinitions", "MenuListStyles",
"MenuListStylesheetWindows", "MenuListTextWindows",
"MenuListWindows", "ModifyBoxFormFormatTypes",
"ModifyDefaultFontProperties", "ModifyEvaluatorNames",
"ModifyFontSubstitutions", "ModifyNotebooksMenu",
"ModifyRelatedFiles", "MoveBackward", "MoveForward", "MoveToBack",
"MoveToFront", "New", "NewPackage", "NewText",
"NextFunctionTemplate", "NotebookMail", "NotebookMailSelection",
"NotebookOneNote", "NotebookOneNoteSelection",
"NotebookStatisticsDialog", "Open", "OpenCloseGroup",
"OpenFromNotebooksMenu", "OpenFromNotebooksMenuEmpty",
"OpenFromPalettesMenu", "OpenFromRelatedFilesMenu", "OpenHelpLink",
"OpenSelection", "OpenSelectionParents", "OpenURL", "OptionsDialog",
"PasswordDialog", "Paste", "PasteApply", "PasteApplyNoAutoScroll",
"PasteDiscard", "PasteDiscardNoAutoScroll", "PasteSpecial",
"PlainFont", "PreferencesDialog", "PreviousFunctionTemplate",
"PrintDialog", "PrintOptionsDialog", "PrintSelectionDialog",
"PublishToPlayer", "RebuildHelpIndex", "RecordSoundDialog",
"RefreshDynamicObjects", "RelatedFilesMenu",
"RemoveFromEvaluationQueue", "Replace", "ReplaceAll", "ReplaceFind",
"ReplaceParent", "Revert", "RunColorDialog", "RunEdgeColorDialog",
"RunFaceColorDialog", "Save", "SaveRename", "SaveRenameSpecial",
"ScrollLineDown", "ScrollLineUp", "ScrollNotebookEnd",
"ScrollNotebookStart", "ScrollPageBottom", "ScrollPageDown",
"ScrollPageFirst", "ScrollPageLast", "ScrollPageNext",
"ScrollPagePrevious", "ScrollPageTop", "ScrollPageUp",
"SelectGeneratedCells", "SelectionAnimate", "SelectionBrace",
"SelectionBracket", "SelectionCloseAllGroups",
"SelectionCloseUnselectedCells", "SelectionConvert",
"SelectionConvertB", "SelectionDisplayAs", "SelectionDisplayAsB",
"SelectionHelpDialog", "SelectionOpenAllGroups",
"SelectionParenthesize", "SelectionSaveSpecial", "SelectionScroll",
"SelectionSetFind", "SelectionSpeak", "SelectionSpeakSummary",
"SelectionUnbracket", "SelectNotebookWindow", "SetDefaultGraphic",
"SimilarCellBelow", "SoundPlay", "SpellCheckerDialog",
"StackWindows", "Style", "StyleDefinitionsOther", "StyleOther",
"SubsessionEvaluateCells", "SystemPrintOptionsDialog",
"TemplateSelection", "TestEvaluateNotebook", "TileWindowsTall",
"TileWindowsWide", "ToggleDebugFlag", "ToggleDynamicUpdating",
"ToggleGrayBox", "ToggleOptionListElement", "ToggleShowExpression",
"ToggleTestingFlag", "TrustNotebook", "Undo", "Ungroup",
"WindowMiniaturize", "XInfoDialog", "ZoomWindow"}
```

Comment: +10 for kernel quit!!! I have been yearning for this for years, but it never really occurred to me that it was possible :)

Comment: Ah, hacking KeyEventTranslations.tr brings back memories of trying to get Mathematica 3 working properly on Linux... happy days.

Comment: @Yaro Tested on Winsh and works. Check the "Modifiers->" part, there is a note in the header of the keytrans file.

Comment: perhaps the problem is a conflict with another operation. CTRL+OPTION+Q on Mac already does something similar to "Check Balance". However, it's not in .tr file, and I can't find some of the other Shorcuts showing in Edit menu in the .tr file either

Comment: @Yaro to get it working on Win, I removed the "Option" in {Control,Option}, so Ctrl+q quits the kernel

Comment: The first two links in this response are broken. This may be a fix for one those: https://web.archive.org/web/20080608124549/http://www.lamberta.org/blog/mathematica-keybindings/

Comment: Yaroslav, I didn't get it to work on Mac either. However I did get the whole process of quitting the Kernel, confirming, and starting up the Kernel again, with the keyboard shortcut to work, using a program called Keyboard Maestro which I use all the time for automating things on the Mac. If anyone is interested I can make a small screencast on post it on YouTube

Comment: `FrontEndTokenExecute` allows writing this a bit shorter.

Answer (score 7):

The shortcuts for different types of cells are stored in the [Stylesheet](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/Stylesheets.html).
Choose the style you want and change the <strike>`MenuKeyCommand`</strike> `MenuCommandKey` value.
The dropdown options in the [Option Inspector](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OptionInspector.html) only allow you to use 1-9, but I tested it with "`" and "=" and they worked fine. Sometimes its easier to modify the Stylesheet using the [Show Expression](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/menuitem/ShowExpression.html) (Ctrl-Shift-E) rather than the Option Inspector.