# Keyboard shortcut to quit kernel in Mathematica 5 and 7?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

[`Here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209405/customizing-mathematica-shortcuts/4209612#4209612) is an explanation how to define a custom keyboard shortcut for quitting the kernel of the selected notebook by modifying the file `KeyEventTranslations.tr`. This file is located by default (under Windows) for *Mathematica* 5.2 in the folder

```
C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\5.2\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\TextResources\Windows
```

and for *Mathematica* 7.0.1 in the folder

```
C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\7.0\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\TextResources\Windows
```

In this file after `EventTranslations[{` I have added a line:

```
Item[KeyEvent["q", Modifiers -> {Control}],FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken[SelectedNotebook[],"EvaluatorQuit",Automatic]]]
```

But unfortunately after restarting *Mathematica* the shortcut `Control+q` does not work on both versions.

Moreover, in *Mathematica* 7.0.1 executing the command

```
FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken[SelectedNotebook[], "EvaluatorQuit", Automatic]]
```

and pressing "Quit" leads to an application error and closing `FrontEnd` with loosing all unsaved changes (I am using Windows 2000).

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** The problem was in missing comma after added `Item[...]` (thanks to belisarius). Here is the right line to add to `KeyEventTranslations.tr`:

```
Item[KeyEvent["q", Modifiers -> {Control}],FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken[SelectedNotebook[],"EvaluatorQuit",Automatic]]],
```

Now shortcut `Control+q` works nice both in Mathematica 5.2 and 7.0.1.
But the above bug with "application error" still appears (not when using the shortcut but only when evaluating `FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken[SelectedNotebook[], "EvaluatorQuit", Automatic]]` in notebook).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`This answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209405/customizing-mathematica-shortcuts/4209612#4209612) and the associated comments may help you.

HTH!

BTW ... I did the same in v7 and it worked. On what version are you having trouble?

Just a note: Be very careful with the syntax **Verify that every Item[Keyevent ends with a comma, except the last one.**

Comment: That answer is linked in my post. The problem is with versions 5.2 and 7.0.1 but with v.7.0.1 it is much deeper (see the last but one paragraph in my post).

Comment: @Alexey Sorry, I didn't see the link.

Comment: @Alexey Just a note: Be very careful with the syntax Verify that every Item[Keyevent ends with a comma, except the last.

Comment: Thank you for the note about syntax! I forgot about the comma. That was my mistake. Now `Control+q` works nice in both Mathematica 5.2 and 7.0.1. Thank you again!

Comment: Another question: is there a way to avoid the "Quit Kernel" dialog and to quit kernel immediately after pressing `Ctrl+q`?

Comment: @Alexey I don't know. But may be dangerous :D