# Write below keyboard shortcut

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-frontend, mathematica-8

It used to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> in Mathematica 7, but in Mathematica 8 instead of writing below this shortcut starts free-form input. The documentation at tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing hasn't been updated. Which shortcut is now used for writing below?

Comment: @herbalessence which rule does it violate?

Comment: @belisarius <Enter> is used to move to new line. Old Ctrl+= was used to write something under the symbol but on the same line. It's the opposite for Ctrl+7.

Comment: Hi Max - I still find myself pressing Ctrl+= then getting annoyed at the "linguistic form" box that appears.

Comment: @herbalessence: This is an ongoing debate. Where should Mathematica frontend questions be asked? We recently added the [mathematica-frontend] tag to try to make these questions more clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Below* is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> (or <kbd>$</kbd>) now. You can find that information in the file

($InstallationDirectory)\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\TextResources\Windows\KeyEventTranslations.tr

(expand $InstallationDirectory in Mathematica to find this directory)

Comment: I was about to answer the same. Note that the docs still mention erroneously Ctrl+= as **below**. See http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/menuitem/Typesetting.html under "more info"

Comment: Thank you for the hint about KeyEventTranslations.tr. It's very interesting to look through this file.

Comment: @Max Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209405/customizing-mathematica-shortcuts/4209612#4209612