# How to redefine FrontEndEventActions?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-frontend

Good day,

This question comes from the question on [aborting evaluation of the full sequence of inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625648/how-to-abort-evaluation-of-a-sequence-of-inputs).

I think it is probably possible to achieve the desired behavior by redefining `FrontEndEventActions` for two events: `"EvaluateCells"` (or pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) and for pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>. It should be something like:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, 
 FrontEndEventActions -> {"EvaluateCells" :> Last$PreRead, 
   {{"Alt", "."} :> AbortAllNextInputs}}]
```

or

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, 
 FrontEndEventActions -> {{{"ShiftKey", "ReturnKeyDown"} :> Last$PreRead}
   {{"Alt", "."} :> AbortAllNextInputs}}]
```

Where `AbortAllNextInputs` and `Last$PreRead` are defined as follows:

```
AbortAllNextInputs := AbortProtect[
   $new$PreRead = True;
   last$PreRead = ToString[Definition[$PreRead], InputForm];
   ClearAll[$PreRead];
   $PreRead := # &] /; ! TrueQ[$new$PreRead]
Last$PreRead :=
 $PreRead := AbortProtect[
    $new$PreRead = False;
    ClearAll[$PreRead];
    If[last$PreRead === "Null", #, 
     ToExpression[last$PreRead]; $PreRead@#]
    ] &
```

But I can not get `FrontEndEventActions` working. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to modify KeyEventTranslations.tr as referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209405/customizing-mathematica-shortcuts) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604837/keyboard-shortcut-to-un-comment-out-code-in-mathematica-7).

Comment: I have created [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676911/) on this method. I think these approaches both are very valuable and must be separated.