# Permanent changing FrontEnd behavior to force aborting evaluation of the full sequence of inputs

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-frontend

This sub-question comes from the [question on aborting evaluation of the full sequence of inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625648/how-to-abort-evaluation-of-a-sequence-of-inputs) together with [previous sub-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673277/how-to-redefine-frontendeventactions).

How should we change the file KeyEventTranslations.tr (and/or MenuSetup.tr) to force aborting evaluation of the full sequence of inputs?

One possible method to achieve this is 
described in the [previous sub-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673277/how-to-redefine-frontendeventactions) associated with another approach: temporary changing of `FrontEndEventActions` for the current session. I think these questions should be separated as being useful in different situations.