# mathematica equation tagging

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, format

This seems like an obvious question yet I cannot find any answer to it.  I am using Mathematica 8 and am sequentially numbering my equations using (Format->Style->DisplayFormulaNumbered).  This works fine but how can I reference specific equations in text so that they will change accordingly if I add new equations before the referenced equation?

I know LateX does this fantastically and it seems like an easy process.  Just to be specific, If I have equations,

blah=blahblah     (1)

nerg=flarg        (2)

plugging in equation (2) into equation (1)...
but then I want to add an equation before equation (1), how can I automatically have the text change to "plugging in equation (3) into equation (2)..."?

Also, is there anyway to have more control over the numbering?  Such as instead of equation (2) can I have equation (2.1)?  This would help since I have sections that would make that numbering style much nicer.

Thanks!  I hope this is not a frequently asked question but I searched and couldn't find an answer.

Comment: try http://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Comment: I think this thread might be helpful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903484/how-to-autonumber-cell-tags-in-mathematica-notebooks