# Can we show some Dynamics/CDF in PowerPoint or Keynote ?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8, mathematica-cdf, wolfram-cdf

I want to show some dynamic content in a presentation. However, I am not sure I have time by Thursday to make slides in the way I would like to within Mathematica.

Is it possible to have Dynamic objects built in Mathematica within A Powerpoint (Microsoft) or Keynote (Apple) presentation ?

Comment: I hope you'll deliver an autographed paper to all of us!

Comment: I will rather thank you all in it as it should be ;-)

Comment: Stephen dropped a hint that Powerpoint integration is coming in [this](http://blog.wolfram.com/2009/11/12/the-rd-pipeline-for-mathematica/) talk.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What is wrong with making few Manipulates, export them each to separate CDF, and you got your presentation there.

You can make a web page, each page can be contain one CDF. Each page will be like your one slide.

You can click a link to go to the next web page.next slide, and in it you can run the next CDF.

To insert a CDF into a web page, is very simple, like this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<BODY >

<p><script src="http://www.wolfram.com/cdf-player/plugin/v1.0/cdfplugin.js"
type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
var cdf = new cdf_plugin();
cdf.addCDFObject("source", "source.cdf",840,670);
// ]]></script>

<img id="source" src="screen_shot.png"    
 alt="screen_shot" />

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Put your cdf files in the same folder.

If you know latex, you can write latex document, make them as sections of a document, insert the HTML code in latex, export the latex document to html using latex2html. (this is what I do with my web pages). Like this

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{html}

\begin{document}
\begin{rawhtml}
<p><script src="http://www.wolfram.com/cdf-player/plugin/v1.0/cdfplugin.js"
type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
var cdf = new cdf_plugin();
cdf.addCDFObject("source", "source.cdf",840,670);
// ]]></script>

<img id="source" src="screen_shot.png" 
 alt="screen_shot" />
\end{rawhtml}
\end{document}
```

Then type latex2html foo.tex and that will generate the html for you. This way you can write real mathematics using Latex, and have the CDF in the same page we well, next to your equations.

All what you need for your presentation is a browser and the CDF plugin installed.

Or, you can simply keep everything in Mathematica itself, with a Manipulate in each section of a mathematica notebook, and just run the notebook inside Mathematica at the presentation.

Forget about power points and PDF's. That is so boring and old fashioned now :)

CDF is the way to go.

Comment: Nasser, thank You, although what you propose sounds great, I can`t afford learning html by Thursday :-) And I need the control you have in Keynote for the aesthetic and the rhythm of my talk...

Comment: Nasser, even going through LaTeX is old fashioned (although I do like the rawhtml stuff +1). If you're going to make a web based slide show, then use a web standard, like [s5](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/s5/). Here's a [good example created in instiki](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/wiki/instiki/s5/S5+Test).

Answer (score 4):

If your presentation laptop has Mathematica you could use MMA itself to give the presentation. It has a [presentation mode](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/PresentationsWithTheWolframSystem.html).

Comment: I do but it is hard to get things as good looking as in ppt for me now.

Comment: You could include the power point slide itself inside Mathematica, as an image, and have the Manipulate[] next to it. (or below it). Can use page breaks in Mathematica notebook to arrange as needed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can!  I was wondering the exact same thing for a group presentation where other members were making PowerPoint slides.  It's simply a matter of embedding the slide into an HTML file then [embedding the HTML file](http://www.quora.com/How-do-you-embed-HTML-in-PowerPoint-2010) in a PowerPoint slide.  It's not perfect, but it works surprisingly well and you maintain full interactivity.

Answer (score 2):

Export a video file, eg by

```
an = Table[
   Plot[Cos[x/a],
    {x, 0, 20*Pi},
    PlotRange \[Rule] {-1, 1}
    ],
   {a, 0.1, 10, .1}
   ];
Export["~/Desktop/an.avi", an]
```

Comment: Thank you but I lose the Control here don`t I ? I need to actively manipulate the Object during my talk.

Comment: OK, I don't know then. Personally when I need this I simply switch to  mathematica for the interactive bit and then back to the slides.

Comment: You can even make links and/or buttons to fire up  mathematic in ppt.

Comment: @All,can we export a Manipulate as a video ? Talk in 3 hours :-)

Comment: @500 Have you tried using an `Animate` instead of `Manipulate`?

Comment: @500 I don't know as I do not use ppt. If you can attach animations (which it probably allows), simply export as in my answer

Comment: Thank you ! I did not understand ho to adapt your answer to a manipulate :-(

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible to do what you want, since even if you can use the standard java script to link to the CDF, there is no properly integrated CDF plugin for powerpoint, keynote, a pdf viewer etc...

Either, as other people have suggested, learn how to use Mathematica/CDF to make presentations - see the discussion in [belisarius's SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5058854/421225). Or use a html-based presentation.

It is possible to export a keynote presentation to html. Here's [a tutorial](http://www.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/Members/karla/converting-keynote-to-html-slideshows) that shows how to tweak it to get a navigation toolbar and make movies work - and an [example is here](http://users.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/~karla/teaching/ISMRM_diffusion.html). You should be able to [embed a CDF](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/adopting-cdf/deploying-cdf/web-delivery.html) (see also [Walking Randomly](http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=3323)) using similar modifications of the outputted html.

Alternatively, create a HTML based presentation from the start. [S5](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/s5/) is a good opensource html slideshow. It uses markdown, so it's just like writing in stackexchange sites! [Instiki includes a S5 mode](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/wiki/instiki/s5/S5+Test). You can include raw-html in the presentation, so you should be able to embed CDF's like above.