# How to modify OUTPUT font type?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-frontend, wolframalpha

Is it possible to change the OUTPUT font type instead of the default one? How?

This is my default stylesheet: http://filefactory.com/file/cfc2cb0/n/blueOutput.nb

Thanks!

Comment: You might find [this So discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058854/using-mathematica-to-build-presentations-and-documents) to be of use. Also, you may find the [documentation on stylesheets](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/Stylesheets.html) helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem lies in `StandardForm` not respecting the `FontFamily` option, although it does seem to respect most other font options. [Sjoerd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000365/how-to-modify-output-font-type/8000463#8000463) used `TraditionalForm` output and thus worked. You can see this problem if you run

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[{
    Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]],
    Cell[StyleData["Output"],
     FontColor -> RGBColor[0, 0, .5], FontSize -> 14, 
     FontFamily -> "Symbol", FontWeight -> "Bold"]}]]
```

Then compare

```
{1 + 1, "abc", Sin[x]} (* This is by default in StandardForm *)
{1 + 1, "abc", Sin[x]} // StandardForm
{1 + 1, "abc", Sin[x]} // OutputForm
{1 + 1, "abc", Sin[x]} // TraditionalForm
```

[image: output from above]

You can also look at

```
Dynamic[CurrentValue/@{FontFamily, FontWeight, FontSize}]
Dynamic[CurrentValue/@{FontFamily, FontWeight, FontSize}] // TraditionalForm
```

[image: output from above]

which shows that the `CurrentValue` of `FontFamily` "seen" in the output depends on the output format.

Unfortunately, I don't see how to get around this issue...

Comment: By the way, this is probably a deliberate design choice by WRI. `StandardForm` is meant to be a clear and unambiguous format. Using a dingbats font would definitely remove the clarity of the format.

Comment: So is it wrong if I use TraditionalForm instead of StandardForm ?

Comment: @Nazaf: No, it's not wrong. I know of a few Mma gurus who use `TraditionalForm` for a bulk of their work...

Answer (score 4):

Just go to the `Format > Edit Stylesheet...` menu. Then in the private style definitions sheet that pops-up choose 'Output' from the pull-down menu and change the looks of the resulting Output cell. This stylesheet will  be stored with your open notebook.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try TraditionalForm instead of StandardForm (`Cell > Convert to`). Most font options (size, color, weight, slant) work fine in both Forms but it looks like the font family choice in TraditionalForm is more restricted than in StandardForm.

Comment: I am using my own custom stylesheet.

Comment: I don't, see pictures. What version do you have?

Comment: Could you try removing the `$Failed` Cell, and try formatting an Output cell again? I saw that $Failed once too when I was playing around, but it went away.

Comment: @Nazaf Interesting - does it work if you start a new blank notebook and try to just change straightforward output? i.e. `test="testing this output font"` and see if you can get that very simple output to change?

Comment: By the way, I have the DefaultStyleDefinitions global option set to a custom stylesheet. This is not a problem, right?

Comment: Perhaps there's something wrong with that stylesheet? Could you try with everything set at default?

Answer (score 3):

In light of Simon's answer, you could force output printing in a certain style using `$PrePrint`.

```
$PrePrint = Style[#, FontFamily -> "Symbol"] &;

{1 + 1, "abc", Sin[x]}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with that is that the output is not copy/paste-able... Maybe `$PrePrint = Interpretation[Style[#, FontFamily -> "Symbol"], #] &;`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by redefining the `StandardForm` style which is used for `Output` style by default (see the `DefaultFormatType` option in the `Output` style):

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 StyleDefinitions -> 
  Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
    Cell[StyleData["StandardForm"], 
     FontFamily -> "Palatino Linotype"]}, 
   StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"]]
```

But `Input` style in this case is also affected because it is based on the `StandardForm` style too...

Answer (score -1):

You could try wrapping your inputs using the `Style[]` command. For example:

```
test="This is a test string.";
Style[test,{Red,"Title"}]
```

This generates the string in my style sheet's 'title' settings in the colour red. The solution of changing your Stylesheets is obviously preferable to this, but this might be a quick and dirty temporary workaround.

Comment: I see a red text in large font size. so what now?

Comment: I need to automate this in a stylesheet, so I don't have to type it each time.

Comment: @Nazaf Perhaps you could provide some more information in your question. Something odd is going on if you can't change your style sheet..

Comment: If I use Shift + Ctrl + E to edit the expression manually change font family it works !! 

But how do I save changes to the global stylesheet ?

Comment: @Nazaf This would be a good thing to edit your question to add - just so other users don't miss it (hidden down here in comments).