# Mathematica: How to clear the cache for a symbol, i.e. Unset pattern-free DownValues

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm a bad cacher: Sometimes, when no one is watching, I'll cache results without including the full context like so:

```
f[x_]:=f[x]=x+a;
a=2; f[1];
DownValues[f]

Out[2]= {HoldPattern[f[1]]:>3,HoldPattern[f[x_]]:>(f[x]=x+a)}
```

This leads to horribly subtle bugs, and, more importantly, to the need for clearing the cache when I change the context. One way of clearing the cache is to completely `Clear` the symbol and repeat the definitions, but this is not really a solution.

What I would really like is a method for clearing all pattern-free DownValues associated with a symbol.
For clarity, I'll include my present solution as an answer, but if fails on two counts

- It only clears DownValues with all-numeric arguments
- For aesthetical reasons, I'd like to avoid using `Block` to grab the DownValues.

Any ideas on how to improve `ClearCache`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've made similar functions in the past (but I can't remember where).

Does the following code do all that you need?

```
ClearCache[f_] := DownValues[f] = DeleteCases[DownValues[f], 
                                              _?(FreeQ[First[#], Pattern] &)]
```

This maybe should be extended to `UpValues` and `SubValues`. And the `Head` of `f` restricted to `Symbol`.

Comment: @belisarius: Your comment without an upvote makes me paranoid that I've done something stupid... A simple solution doesn't mean that I'm a simpleton, does it?

Comment: @Simon I just forgot to upvote. Shame on me! That pattern is brillant.

Comment: Wow! This looks exactly like what I was trying to do. One little technicality to keep the question open for a few more minutes: You disqualify a downvalue from clearing even if it only has a pattern on the RHS -- for ClearCache Nirvana we should probably only look at the LHS.

Comment: @Janus: Luckily, that's easily fixed - see edit.  (btw; Nirvana? You must really want this `ClearCache` function!)

Comment: Thanks Simon! I'll leave it open for a few hours -- just because it always annoys me when a question is closed before I even see it :)

Answer (score 8):

Just to complement the other excellent solution: if you have a very large list of `DownValues` and have strict efficiency requirements for `ClearCache`, you can significantly speed up the process by clearing all definitions and then reconstructing only those with patterns. Here is an example:

```
In[1]:= 
ClearCache[f_] := 
  DownValues[f] = DeleteCases[DownValues[f], _?(FreeQ[First[#], Pattern] &)];

In[2]:= Clear[f];
f[x_] := f[x] = x;

In[4]:= f /@ Range[1000000];

In[5]:= ClearCache[f]; // Timing

Out[5]= {7.765, Null}

In[6]:= 
ClearAll[createDefs];
SetAttributes[createDefs, HoldRest];
createDefs[f_, defs_: Automatic] :=
        (createDefs[f] := (Clear[f]; defs); createDefs[f]);

In[9]:= Clear[f];
createDefs[f, f[x_] := f[x] = x]

In[11]:= f /@ Range[1000000];

In[12]:= Length[DownValues[f]]

Out[12]= 1000001

In[13]:= createDefs[f]; // Timing

Out[13]= {1.079, Null}

In[14]:= DownValues[f]

Out[14]= {HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> (f[x] = x)}
```

Note that you only have to call the `createDefs` once with the code that creates the pattern-based definitions of the function. All other times, you call it as `createDefs[f]`, because it memoizes the code needed to re-create the definitions, on the first call.

It is also possible that you don't want to grow huge caches, but this is out of your control in the simple `f[x_]:=f[x]=rhs` approach. In other words, the cache may contain lots of unnecessary old stuff, but in this approach you can not tell old (no longer used) definitions from the new ones. I partially addressed this problem with a  package I called Cache, which can be found [here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/additional_resources.html) together with the notebook illustrating its use. It gives you more control over the size of the cache. It has its problems, but may occasionally be useful.

Comment: Thanks, Leonid. It's good to have this approach listed here as well. I've used it occasionally (i.e. before building 'ClearCache') but I don't really like how it interferes with the implementation process. For my particular uses, the results I cache are so expensive that I could clear a year's worth of cache in the blink of an eye :)

Answer (score 7):

Once I implemented a scheme to [limit the number of memoized values](http://web.ift.uib.no/~szhorvat/mmatricks.php) (and conserve memory).  Search for memoization on that page.  This might be useful here as well (especially considering some of the questions marked as duplicate of this one).

**The code**

```
SetAttributes[memo, HoldAll]
SetAttributes[memoStore, HoldFirst]
SetAttributes[memoVals, HoldFirst]

memoVals[_] = {};

memoStore[f_, x_] := 
 With[{vals = memoVals[f]}, 
  If[Length[vals] > 200, 
   f /: memoStore[f, First[vals]] =.;
   memoVals[f] ^= Append[Rest[memoVals[f]], x], 
   memoVals[f] ^= Append[memoVals[f], x]];
  f /: memoStore[f, x] = f[x]]

memo[f_Symbol][x_?NumericQ] := memoStore[f, x]

memoClearCache[f_Symbol] := 
 (Scan[(f /: memoStore[f, #] =.) &, memoVals[f]]; 
  f /: memoVals[f] =. )
```

**Usage and description**

This version works with functions that take a single numerical argument.  Call `memo[f][x]` instead of `f[x]` to use a memoized version.  Cached values are still associated with `f`, so when `f` is cleared, they are gone.  The number of cached values is limited to 200 by default.  Use `memoClearCache[f]` to clear all memoized values.

Answer (score 3):

This is my present solution to the problem, but as mentioned in the question is doesn't strictly look for pattern-free `DownValues`, nor is it very elegant.
Store the `DownValues` for `f`

```
In[6]:= dv = DownValues[f]

Out[6]= {HoldPattern[f[1]] :> 3, HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> (f[x] = x + a)}
```

Find the `DownValues` to clear inside a `Block` to avoid immediate evaluation

```
In[7]:= dv2clear = Block[{f},
  Hold@Evaluate@Cases[dv,
      HoldPattern[f[args__ /; Apply[And, NumericQ /@ Flatten[{args}]]]], {3}]]

Out[7]= Hold[{f[1]}]
```

Apply `Unset` to the targeted `DownValues` inside the held list and then release

```
In[8]:= Map[Unset, dv2clear, {2}]
ReleaseHold@%

Out[8]= Hold[{(f[1]) =.}]
```

This works fine

```
In[10]:= DownValues[f]

Out[10]= {HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> (f[x] = x + a)}
```

And can be wrapped up like so:

```
ClearCache[f_] := Module[{dv, dv2clear},
  (* Cache downvalues for use inside block *)
  dv = DownValues[f];
  (* Find the downvalues to clear in Block to avoid immediate evaluation *)
  dv2clear = Block[{f},Hold@Evaluate@Cases[dv,HoldPattern[
        f[args__ /; Apply[And, NumericQ /@ Flatten[{args}]]]], {3}]];
  (* Apply Unset to the terms inside the held list and then release *)
  ReleaseHold@Map[Unset, dv2clear, {2}];]
```