# Init.m considerations and good practices

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

As I never found (or perhaps I never search for it enough) a good article about how to manage the init.m files, I ended up developing my own "standard", but I wonder how bad I did it.

For example, my usual init.m is stored in `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Mathematica\Kernel\init.m` (Windows) and I edit it using a text editor.

As I don't want the definitions to go into the Global context, the content is something like:

```
(** User Mathematica initialization file **)
Begin["MyInitContext`"];

Cl:=Clear["Global`*"];
(* Other definitions in this Context *)

End[]; (* End Context *)
$ContextPath = Prepend[$ContextPath,"MyInitContext`"];
```

I don't load packages from the init.m, because I want strict control over what I load, so I only define here shortcuts to utility functions I use on a daily basis and some options.

So: Any references to good practices? Better ways to achieve this kind of behavior?  Any caveats?

Comment: There are several init.m files on my computer.  Perhaps someone can also clarify what one achieves with several init files in different directories. I suspect there is a range of uses.

Comment: Editing `init.m` in FrontEnd directory caused all of my FrontEnd options to be forgotten in Mathematica 8.0, I suppose it shouldn't be touched

Comment: @Yaro When I modify the init.m in the FrontEnd dir, I just receive an error message, and Mma refuses to start. I am not sure what should go in each init.m, anyway :(

Comment: I've used `init.m` once, but it was for setting up a package (older forms of `LevelScheme` had a non-std load procedure).  So, best practices ... I'm curious to see how people use it.

Comment: @rcollyer _I'm curious to see how people use it_ ... that's perhaps the correct way to translate my question to plain English :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, I would strongly recommend against putting anything significant `init.m`, since this invariably results in old stuff being broken when you come back to it after a few years. Much better to put your customizations on the path so you can quickly load it at the head of each notebook: That way the context is explicitly stated and you can easily change versions without breaking old stuff.

My current setup is to start with `` Needs["Janus`"] `` where the `Janus` directory has a custom `init.m` file that loads every file in the directory into the context. This means I can add utility functions in each their own file like this one (`clear_cache.m`):

```
ClearCache::usage="ClearCache[f] unsets all numeric-only downvalues of f, \
  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086749"     

Begin["`Private`"];
ClearCache[f_Symbol] := 
  DownValues[f] = DeleteCases[DownValues[f], _?(FreeQ[First[#], Pattern] &)]
End[]
```

Here is the file `Janus/init.m`. Note that it prints out the name of the loaded extensions, all in the spirit of keeping the context explicit without too much hassle.

```
Module[{packageName,packageFileName,fileNames},
  (* $Input is set to Foo.m when evaluating Foo/init.m *)
  If[$Input=="", Print["init.m cannot run interactively"];Abort[]];
  packageName=StringDrop[$Input,-2];
  packageFileName=FindFile[packageName<>"`"];
  If[packageFileName==$Failed, Print["Unable to find package "<>packageName];Abort[]];
  fileNames=Select[
    FileNames["*.m",{DirectoryName@packageFileName},1],
    FileBaseName[#]=!="init"&];
  Print["Loading extensions from "<>DirectoryName@packageFileName<>" to context "<>packageName<>"`:"];
  BeginPackage[packageName<>"`"];
  Do[Print["Loading "<>fn]; Get@fn, {fn,fileNames}];
  EndPackage[]]
```

Comment: I do not understand your reasoning for using **Needs["Janus`"]** but keeping functions in separate .m files.  The only reason I can think for the separate files is so that it is easy remove them selectively, but then your **Needs["Janus`"]** is inadequate to describe what should actually be loaded.  Once I have added a function to my custom functions package, I won't delete it without very good reason.

Comment: By the way, how do you get backticks within an inline code block?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I've found the "simplest" way to be to use the &lt;code&gt; tag and then escape the actual backtick with a backslash...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Well, for me the utility functions are a two way street: I've dropped many over the years, either due to deprecation or because I realized that I was doing things backwards. For this, I find file-level atomicity makes the archiving easier. A key point is that the loader prints the names of the files to the notebook: if any of the files have been deactivated I can quickly look through `Janus/archive/` to copy the implementation into the notebook.

Answer (score 7):

My `Kernel/init.m` looks like this:

```
AppendTo[$Path, Environment["MMA_LIB"]]
Needs["WRUtil`"]
```

`WRUtil` contains all of my little utilities and performs other initialization that takes into account the platform and Mathematica version.  `MMA_LIB` is an environment variable that points to a directory full of Mathematica packages.  That directory is kept under version control and can be shared by multiple Mathematica instances.  I like to keep `init.m` short so that moving into a new Mathematica installation is as simple as typing two lines that I have committed to memory -- it is surprising how often I seem to have to do this.

Answer (score 5):

Having also not followed an official doctrine, I can only tell you what I do.

My `Kernel/init.m` contains no functions itself.  I use it to:

- Set certain options: `$HistoryLength` `SetDirectory` etc.
- Do a little cleanup (I prefer not to start with a blank notebook)
- Set my desired `DeclarePackage` calls
- Load my custom functions package

Comment: Is there a reason for not declaring custom functions in the init.m?

Comment: @belisarius I generate my custom functions package (.m) file automatically from a Notebook (.nb) with `Initialization` cells, which is much more convenient to me.  Yet, I want to be able to edit my `init.m` manually.  This addresses both.  Also, if I want to keep a different version of `init.m` I can change my functions without having to synchronize these.