# List all `i` for which `data[i_Integer]` is defined

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am reading a file with `Get[]` that contains a semi-colon separated sequence of sub-scripted definitions like this:

```
data[1] = {stuff};
data[5] = {otherStuff};
data[99] = {yetMoreStuff};
```

What is the cleanest way to programatically decide for what values of `i` is `data[i]` defined?  A list of the indices would be nice, e.g. `{1, 5, 99}`.

A hacky way would be to loop through the range of possible values to see which ones don't have head "data" (e.g. `Select[data/@Range[1,1000],(Not[MatchQ[#,_data]])?]`), but this is unattractive since it isn't general (e.g. it won't find `data[dog] = "Max";` if we remove the integer subscript requirement) and assumes that one can choose an upper bound.  It would also be slow and waste memory.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5086749/618728  http://stackoverflow.com/q/7165169/618728 and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7972/121

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm still not at my Mathematica machine but it occurs to me that `DownValues[data]` will probably return a list of rules that you might be happy to manipulate to get out the `i`s. Perhaps something like this;

```
Cases[DownValues[data],RuleDelayed[HoldPattern[data[i_Integer]],rhs_]:>i]
```

Comment: Based on your answer, my final expression is `Cases[DownValues[data], data[i_] -> i, Infinity]`

Answer (score 0):

```
data[1] = {stuff};
data[5] = {otherStuff};
data[99] = {yetMoreStuff};

Cases[
 DownValues @ data,
 _[_@_@x_Integer, _] :> x
]
```

> ```
> {1, 5, 99}
> ```