# How to close initialization cell in Notebook?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In my Notebook I have a fairly large initialization cell. How to make it close-able? I mean how can I roll up this cell in one line with ability to unroll it back?

Comment: your question has got a close vote. I don't know if you are able to see it because of your still relatively low rep. The issue is that there are many users in SO that know nothing about Mma, but are able to close your questions. You can prevent them to do so  by re-reading the text from the outsider point of view and ensure that it sounds like a "programming" question vs. an "administration" or "end user" one. Quirks of the trade.

Comment: @belisarius I think one reason for this is that "mathematica" tag sounds too close to "mathematics". Probably it would be better to use/have "wolfram mathematica" tag to point out that the question is not about pure mathematics.

Comment: Hey! that's brillant. We should propose it at [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/). Go ahead or let me know if you prefer me to post it.

Comment: @belisarius I think you can express this point better than me. I feel myself too inexperienced there. I would prefer you to post this idea.

Comment: Done. Go and vote for it if it fits. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81152/retag-mathematica-to-wr-mathematica-or-something-similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution. I should create a text cell before my initialization cell, for example here is a nice cell:

```
Cell[TextData[StyleBox["Initialization cell(s)",
 FontFamily->"Courier New",
 FontSize->14]], "Text",
 CellFrame->True, ShowGroupOpener->True,
 Background->GrayLevel[0.85]]
```

Then I should select this cell and the next (initialization) cell and then select from the context menu "Group Cells". Now I can roll up this group in one line corresponding to the first text cell by double-clicking its cell bracket at right of window. This is what I searched for. Thanks Andrew Moylan and Brett Champion.

Answer (score 7):

The classic solution is to put the initialization cell(s) into a Section (Alt+4) of their own, titled "Initialization." This Section goes either at the start or end of your notebook.

To hide the contents, you close the Section (double click its cell bracket at right of window).

Comment: There is one side-effect of creation a Section for initialization cell: now I must create another Section for the working content. Otherwise all my other cells will be in the first Section. Is there a way to prevent this and work without creating additional Section for the working cells?

Comment: @Alexey  If your initialization code (put is Section) is at the end of the notebook, then I believe that you don't need an additional Section for your working cells.

Comment: @Leonid At this moment I would prefer to have initialization cell at the top of Notebook. I feel it much more natural for anyone who would try to use my Notebook.

Comment: no there isn't a way to prevent that. However, it does allow you to quickly organize your code by providing them with descriptive headers. In my more involved notebooks, I usually have several hierarchies of sections separating out the various scenarios that I'm working with. Usually, there is a general initialization section at the top, and, as needed, there are more specialized initialization subsections within the hierarchy itself. The other benefit is that you can have Text cells alongside the code discussing your code and results, i.e. it becomes a lab notebook!

Answer (score 1):

Select the cell, then toggle Cell > Cell Properties > Open.  The cell bracket will collapse to a few pixels high and be the only visible part of the cell.  The same menu item will also make it visible again later.