# Changing behavior of General::stop and the main loop

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathlink

On the Documentation [`page`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/message/General/stop.html) for `General::stop` we read:

> This message is generated after the
>   indicated message has been generated
>   for the third time **in a single
>   evaluation**.
>
> Messages are suppressed
>   to prevent redundant or repetitive
>   messages in long calculations.

My problem is that when working through `MathLink` I pass every point as a single evaluation and so `General::stop` never appears.

For example, if I define:

```
link = LinkLaunch[First[$CommandLine] <> " -mathlink"]
f[z_?NumericQ] := (Print@LinkRead[link]; 
   LinkWrite[link, 
    Unevaluated[
     EnterExpressionPacket[NIntegrate[Sin[1/x], {x, .001, z}]]]]; 
   While[Head[packet = LinkRead[link]] =!= OutputNamePacket, 
    Print[packet]]; First@LinkRead[link]);
Plot[f[z], {z, 1, 10}, PlotPoints -> 6, MaxRecursion -> 0]
```

I get as many `Message` packets as many evaluations of `f[z]`. Of course I would like message generarion to be stopped in the slave kernel by `General::stop` after generating the same message 3 times. Is there a way to achieve this?

On the documentation page for `$MessageList` we read that

> With the standard *Mathematica* main
>   loop, $MessageList is reset to {} when
>   the processing of a particular input
>   line is complete.

And on the page `tutorial/Messages` we read:

> In every computation you do,
>   *Mathematica* maintains a list
>   $MessageList of all the messages that
>   are produced.
>   In a **standard** *Mathematica* session,
>   this list is cleared after each line
>   of output is generated.

May be this is a reason why `General::stop` does not appear? If it is true is there a way to control this aspect of the Main Loop? Is there a way to create such a non-standard *Mathematica* session?

**EDIT:**
It seems that my supposition was right. If we will clear `$MessageList` after every Message, then `General::stop` never appears:

```
Unprotect[$MessageList]
Do[$MessageList = {}; 1/0, {10}]
```

So the question remains: how to disable automatic clearing `$MessageList` after generating output?

Comment: @Brett The source of the problem is that the slave kernel considers all evaluations as separate and clears `$MessageList` after each of them. It may be easily simulated:

`Unprotect[$MessageList];
Do[$MessageList = {}; 1/0, {20}]`.

This code does not stop generating identical Messages and `General::stop` never appears.

Comment: On the page `tutorial/Messages` we read:

"In every computation you do, *Mathematica*
maintains a list `$MessageList` of all
the messages that are produced.
In a standard *Mathematica* session,
this list is cleared
after each line of output is generated."

This gives me a hope that there is a way to create a non-standard
*Mathematica* session in which `$MessageList` will not be cleared after each line of output is generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. It exploites again [`elegant hack by Todd Gayley`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/5149656#5149656). Here it is (of course, it must be evaluated in the slave kernel):

```
$globalMessageList = {};
Unprotect[Message];
Message[args___] := 
  Block[{$inMsg = True, $MessageList = $globalMessageList},
    Message[args];
    $globalMessageList = $MessageList;
    ] /; ! TrueQ[$inMsg];
Protect[Message];
```

One can fully emulate standard behavior of Messages in the slave kernel by checking the current value of `$Line` and comparing it with previous value:

```
If[TrueQ[$Line > lastLine], 
 LinkWrite[$kern, 
  Unevaluated[ExpressionPacket[$globalMessageList = {};]]]; 
 LinkRead[$kern]]; lastLine = $Line;
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

There are probably better solutions, but here is one that seems to work. As far as I understand, all that matters is that you have some persistent variable in the slave kernel that accumulates messages.

```
link = LinkLaunch[First[$CommandLine] <> " -mathlink"]
f[z_?NumericQ] := 
(Print@LinkRead[link];
LinkWrite[link, Unevaluated[EnterExpressionPacket[
  If[! ValueQ[oldMessageList], oldMessageList = {}];
  Block[{$MessageList = oldMessageList},
   Module[{result},
    oldMessageList  = 
     Join[oldMessageList, (result = 
        NIntegrate[Sin[1/x], {x, .001, z}]; $MessageList)];
    result
    ]]]]];
While[Head[packet = LinkRead[link]] =!= OutputNamePacket, 
Print[packet]]; First@LinkRead[link]);

Plot[f[z], {z, 1, 10}, PlotPoints -> 6, MaxRecursion -> 0]
```

HTH