# The best way to construct a function with memory

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Good day,

I have some very slooooow and complicated function, say `f[x,y]`. And I need to construct detailed `ContourPlot` of it. Moreover the function `f[x,y]` sometimes fails due to lack of physical memory. In such cases I have to stop evaluation and investigate the problem case of the point {x,y} by myself. Then I should can add the element {x,y,f[x,y]} to a list of computed values of `f[x,y]` (say "cache") and restart evaluation of `ContourPlot`. `ContourPlot` must take all already computed values of `f` from the cache. I would prefer to store such list in some file for having ability to reuse it later. And it is probably simpler to add problematic points to this file by hand.

What is the fastest way to implement this if the list of computed values of `f` may contain 10000-50000 points?

Comment: If you're having to create lists of `{x,y,f[x,y]}` it may be worthwhile to use `ListContourPlot[pts]` instead of `ContourPlot`.

Comment: @Brett `ListContourPlot` will not continue computation of additional values of `f` for making plot better. My need is a possibility to continue computation of `ContourPlot` from some problem point where `f[x,y]` fails.

Comment: Strongly related: "[Memoization with pure functions?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85762/280)"

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Let's assume our slow function has the signature `f[x, y]`.

**Pure In-memory Approach**

If you are satisfied with an in-memory cache, the simplest thing to do would be to use memoization:

```
Clear@fmem
fmem[x_, y_] := fmem[x, y] = f[x, y]
```

This adds a definition to itself every time it is called with a combination of arguments that it has not seen before.

**File-backed In-memory Approach**

However, if you are running out of memory or suffering kernel crashes during the long computation, you will want to back this cache with some kind of persistence.  The simplest thing would be to keep a running log file:

```
$runningLogFile = "/some/directory/runningLog.txt";

Clear@flog
flog[x_, y_] := flog[x, y] = f[x, y] /.
  v_ :> (PutAppend[Unevaluated[flog[x, y] = v;], $runningLogFile]; v)

If[FileExistsQ[$runningLogFile]
, Get[$runningLogFile]
, Export[$runningLogFile, "", "Text"];
]
```

`flog` is the same as `fmem`, except that it also writes an entry into the running log that can be used to restore the cached definition in a later session.  The last expression reloads those definitions when it finds an existing log file (or creates the file if it does not exist).

The textual nature of the log file is convenient when manual intervention is required.  Be aware that the textual representation of floating-point numbers introduces unavoidable round-off errors, so you may get slightly different results after reloading the values from the log file.  If this is of great concern, you might consider using the binary `DumpSave` feature although I will leave the details of that approach to the reader as it is not quite as convenient for keeping an incremental log.

**SQL Approach**

If memory is really tight, and you want to avoid having a large in-memory cache to make room for the other computations, the previous strategy might not be appropriate.  In that case, you might consider using Mathematica's built-in SQL database to store the cache completely externally:

```
fsql[x_, y_] :=
  loadCachedValue[x, y] /. $Failed :> saveCachedValue[x, y, f[x, y]]
```

I define `loadCachedValue` and `saveCachedValue` below.  The basic idea is to create an SQL table where each row holds an `x`, `y`, `f` triple.  The SQL table is queried every time a value is needed.  Note that this approach is *substantially* slower than the in-memory cache, so it makes the most sense when the computation of `f` takes much longer than the SQL access time.  The SQL approach does not suffer from the round-off errors that afflicted the text log file approach.

The definitions of `loadCachedValue` and `saveCachedValue` now follow, along with some other useful helper functions:

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"]

$cacheFile = "/some/directory/cache.hsqldb";

openCacheConnection[] :=
  $cache = OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["HSQL(Standalone)", $cacheFile]]

closeCacheConnection[] :=
  CloseSQLConnection[$cache]

createCache[] :=
  SQLExecute[$cache,
    "CREATE TABLE cached_values (x float, y float, f float)
     ALTER TABLE cached_values ADD CONSTRAINT pk_cached_values PRIMARY KEY (x, y)"
  ]

saveCachedValue[x_, y_, value_] :=
  ( SQLExecute[$cache,
      "INSERT INTO cached_values (x, y, f) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", {x, y, value}
    ]
  ; value
  )

loadCachedValue[x_, y_] :=
  SQLExecute[$cache,
    "SELECT f FROM cached_values WHERE x = ? AND y = ?", {x, y}
  ] /. {{{v_}} :> v, {} :> $Failed}

replaceCachedValue[x_, y_, value_] :=
  SQLExecute[$cache,
    "UPDATE cached_values SET f = ? WHERE x = ? AND y = ?", {value, x, y}
  ]

clearCache[] :=
  SQLExecute[$cache,
    "DELETE FROM cached_values"
  ]

showCache[minX_, maxX_, minY_, maxY_] :=
  SQLExecute[$cache,
    "SELECT *
     FROM cached_values
     WHERE x BETWEEN ? AND ?
     AND y BETWEEN ? AND ?
     ORDER BY x, y"
  , {minX, maxX, minY, maxY}
  , "ShowColumnHeadings" -> True
  ] // TableForm
```

This SQL code uses floating point values as primary keys.  This is normally a questionable practice in SQL but works fine in the present context.

You must call `openCacheConnection[]` before attempting to use any of these functions.  You should call `closeCacheConnection[]` after you have finished.  One time only, you must call `createCache[]` to initialize the SQL database.  `replaceCachedValue`, `clearCache` and `showCache` are provided for manual interventions.

Comment: I really enjoyed reading your response. Thank you very much! The "File-backed In-memory" solution is very elegant and fast. That's exactly what I need. SQL-approach is very interesting and a good reserve strategy.

Comment: +1, I agree with @Timo. Never thought to back it up with an SQL table. Now I just need to find something to apply this to ...

Comment: Useful addition to this excellent answer on how to maintain the running log having exactly one expression per line: [`PutAppend` with `PageWidth -> Infinity`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/6441361#6441361).

Comment: If my function is over a continous variables, can I get mathematica to interpolate (linearly say) from memory, when I query very close to a point I've got in store?

Comment: @ThomasAhle We could create an interpolation function by passing the saved lists of input and output values to [Interpolation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html).  The way to recover those lists would require adding some kind of query function to whichever strategy we chose for remembering the values.

Answer (score 8):

The simplest and possibly most efficient way to do this is just to set up the cached values as special case definitions for your function. The lookup is fairly fast due to hashing.

A function:

```
In[1]:= f[x_, y_] := Cos[x] + Cos[y]
```

Which points are used during a ContourPlot?

```
In[2]:= points = Last[
   Last[Reap[
     ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
      EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, y}]]]]];

In[3]:= Length[points]

Out[3]= 10417
```

Set up a version of f with precomputed values for 10000 of the evaluations:

```
In[4]:= Do[With[{x = First[p], y = Last[p]}, precomputedf[x, y] = f[x, y];], {p, 
   Take[points, 10000]}];
```

In the above, you would use something like `precomputedf[x, y] = z` instead of `precomputed[x, y] = f[x, y]`, where z is your precomputed value that you have stored in your external file.

Here is the "else" case which just evaluates f:

```
In[5]:= precomputedf[x_, y_] := f[x, y]
```

Compare timings:

```
In[6]:= ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}]; // Timing

Out[6]= {0.453539, Null}

In[7]:= ContourPlot[precomputedf[x, y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}]; // Timing

Out[7]= {0.440996, Null}
```

Not much difference in timing because in this example f is not an expensive function.

A separate remark for your particular application: Perhaps you could use [ListContourPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListContourPlot.html) instead. Then you can choose exactly which points are evaluated.