# How do I store the results of a long symbolic calculation for later use?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

My calculations are something like this:

```
f[x_]:= (*runs fast*)
g[x_]:=(*runs fast*)
h[x_]=depends on f[x],g[x] (*runs slow ~5mins*)
```

Now I need only the results of `h[x]` and every time I restart mma, I essentially redo the same calculations to get `h[x]`, when it could have been stored. Is there some way I can save the symbolic results, and just import it anytime I need it?

Comment: Have you tried my solution?  Does it work in your application?  Loading with `Get` should *not* require the time it took to generate `h[x_]` in the first place.

Comment: Related: ["The best way to construct a function with memory."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287817/the-best-way-to-construct-a-function-with-memory/5291299#5291299)

Comment: @Alexy: Thanks a lot! That question was helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Save](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Save.html)

Use like:

```
Save["h-defs.m", h]
```

And load with [Get](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Get.html):

```
<< "h-defs.m"
```

Comment: I suggest using `DumpSave["h-defs.mx", h]` instead, it is much much faster for large data.  But it is platform-dependent.  I.e. the 64 bit version won't load something saved by the 32-bit version.

Comment: `Get`'s documentation says that it _"reads in a file, evaluating each expression in it, and returning the last one"_. I don't want it to evaluate each time I load it.

Comment: You were not clear about *what* takes 5 minutes to evaluate (certainly not the definition of the function since it was with :=).  Do the computation, store the result into a variable, then save this variable with `(Dump)Save`.  Alternatively use memoization with `h` and save `h` after doing the computation.

Comment: You can also use use `DumpSave`, but I think using `Save` is better for a beginner as you can read the .m file to see what it contains.

Comment: @d'o-o'b as Szabolcs describes, I am assuming you are creating a series of DownValues for `h`, via memoization or otherwise.  When you use `Get` (`<<`) it evaluates the expression that sets these DownValues, which is what you want.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard: Sorry about the `:=`. I just copied from the lines above. I do use `=`, which is why the evaluation takes time.

Comment: @d'o-o'b I understand that, and my solution should work.  Please try it, and report any problems.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard: Your solution does work and loads immediately; however, variables with subscripts do not get saved this way. Do you know of a workaround for this? I've also symbolized `Subscriptbox["_","_"]`, so I don't really know why it won't save.

Comment: @d'o-o'b there are several ways to use subscripts, if I recall correctly.  Would you mind posting a small example of your use?

Comment: @Mr. Wizard: I was wrong. It actually does save the variables with subscripts. I was confused because it didn't show anything when I used `?variable`, but `Definition@variable` worked. Accepting your answer.

Comment: @d'o-o'b thanks for the accept.  If you wonder what is being saved, you can view the .m file in a text editor or Mathematica.  That is why is intentionally recommended `Save` over `DumpSave`.  (Also, the fact that `DumpSave` is machine dependent and therefore if you think you have saved your code safely, and delete the original, you will be sorry later.)