# How to connect an Oracle Database to Mathematica?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, connection, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to connect an Oracle database to Mathematica 8. Another question already says how it can be done in for [a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863566/using-mathematica-in-mysql-databases) but it does not work for me:

```
Needs["DatabaseLink"] AND conn = OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["MySQL(Connector/J)", 
"yourserver/yourdatabase"], "Username" -> "yourusername", "Password" -> "yourpassword"]
```

The following information is available for me on my desktop:

```
filepath = "C:\oracle\ora92\network\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora"; HOST; PORT; username; password;

conn = OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["MySQL(Connector/J)", HOST], "Username" -> username, "Password" -> password]

Error message: JDBC::error: 
    Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. 
    The driver has not received any packets from the server. >>
```

Does anyone know how I can connect or continue?

Answer (score 12):

Mathematica 8 does not come pre-equipped with an Oracle driver, a fact that can be verified by evaluating these expressions:

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"]
JDBCDriverNames[]
(*
Out[2]= {Microsoft Access(ODBC),hsqldb,HSQL(Memory),HSQL(Server),
         HSQL(Server+TLS),HSQL(Standalone),HSQL(Webserver),HSQL(Webserver+TLS),
         jtds_sqlserver,jtds_sybase,mysql,MySQL(Connector/J),ODBC(DSN),odbc,
         PostgreSQL,Microsoft SQL Server(jTDS),Sybase(jTDS),HSQL 2.0.1}
*)
```

We will have to follow the instructions in the Mathematica [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/DatabaseLink/tutorial/DatabaseResources.html) that describes how to install a new JDBC driver.

First, we will have to create a new resource directory in which to place the necessary JDBC driver JAR file:

```
$jarDirectory =
  CreateDirectory @
    FileNameJoin @
      {$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications", "Oracle", "Java"}
```

Next, we must select a JDBC driver to use.  Visit the [relevant Oracle page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html) to find the correct JDBC driver for your database.

Chose a driver version that is compatible with Java 6, the version that Mathematica 8 uses internally.  For this example, I chose to use the Oracle 11.2.0.2.0 driver for Java 6.  Download the file and then move it into the resource directory just created:

```
SystemOpen[$jarDirectory]
```

Next, we will create a JDBC driver configuration file so that the new driver is registered with Mathematica:

```
$configDirectory =
  CreateDirectory @
    FileNameJoin @
      {$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications", "Oracle", "DatabaseResources"}

Export[
  FileNameJoin @ {$configDirectory, "Oracle.m"}
, JDBCDriver[
    "Name" -> "Oracle"
  , "Driver" -> "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
  , "Protocol" -> "jdbc:oracle:thin:@"
  , "Version" -> 1
  ]
, "Text"
]
```

The driver is now installed:

```
JDBCDriverNames[]
(*
Out[9]= {Oracle,Microsoft Access(ODBC),hsqldb,HSQL(Memory),HSQL(Server),
         HSQL(Server+TLS),HSQL(Standalone),HSQL(Webserver),HSQL(Webserver+TLS),
         jtds_sqlserver,jtds_sybase,mysql,MySQL(Connector/J),ODBC(DSN),odbc,
         PostgreSQL,Microsoft SQL Server(jTDS),Sybase(jTDS),HSQL 2.0.1}
*)
```

If the fates are smiling, we can now establish a connection and execute an SQL query:

```
$connection =
  OpenSQLConnection[
    JDBC["Oracle", "myserver:1521:mysid"]
  , "Username" -> "scott"
  , "Password" -> "tiger"
  ]

SQLExecute[$connection, "SELECT 'success!' FROM DUAL"]
```

... where *myserver* is the database server name, *1521* is the listener port number and *mysid* is the Oracle System ID (SID).

Oracle JDBC URLs come in many forms.  For details, take a look at the [Oracle FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC#Thin_driver).

Comment: How is the file for the driver called exactly? I tried "ojdbc6.jar" but Mathematica still does not see Oracle.

Comment: Hit enter accidentally - thank you very much for your already really helpful comments and insights! Patrick

Comment: @Patrick `ojdbc6.jar` is the correct file.  I have had problems before where a database resource file is not recognized when it starts with a comment.  Try running the `Export` expression again, this time with "`Text`" added as the last argument.  I have updated that expression in my response so you can copy it from there.

Comment: Almost there - have Oracle installed successfully. It seems that only the SID is missing and I tried to insert that at several places, what did not work.

Comment: JDBC::error: ""Listener refused the connection with the following error:\\ nORA-12504, TNS:listener was not given the SID in CONNECT_DATA "

Comment: @Patrick You can add the SID after the port number, e.g. `myserver:1521:SID`.

Comment: Success - I am connected :-) thank you very, very much for your help!

Comment: on my installation, "User" had to be "Username".  Otherwise perfect answer and very well stated!

Comment: @PatrickBernhard may I suggest that you mark WReach's answer as "accepted?"  It seems to have worked for a lot of people (including me)

Answer (score 6):

I suspect that you are using the wrong JDBC driver - you should be using the Oracle JDBC driver, rather than MySQL one.  When I was using `DatabaseLink` to connect to an Oracle database, I used this command:

```
OpenSQLConnection[
  JDBC[
   "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver", 
   "jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:port:dbname"
  ], 
  "Name" -> "dbname", 
  "Username" -> "YourUserName", 
  "Password" -> "YourPassword"
]
```

You should make sure to put the proper Oracle JDBC driver (corresponding to your Oracle db version) into a place where Mathematica can find it. This procedure is described in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/DatabaseLink/tutorial/DatabaseConnections.html) for the DatabaseLink, section `JDBC Connections`. You can test which JDBC drivers are visible to Mathematica by executing `JDBCDrivers[]`. Make sure that you install and use the correct driver corresponding to your DB version, b.t.w. - incorrect driver versions may result in very nasty and non-obvious bugs (this is unrelated to Mathematica).

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that you shouldn't use MySQL JBDC connections for Oracle.  Although it is for Mathematica 5.2, [here is an article](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/Add-onsLinks/DatabaseLink/DatabaseConnections/DatabaseResources/DatabaseLink2.3.1.html) that you perhaps can use as something to go from.

I've barely used Mathematica, and certainly not with a database, but from that page, it looks like you can do this:

```
OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["oracle","server.business.com:1999"],
    Username -> "you"]
```

Comment: OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["Oracle", "localhost:1521/databasename"], 
  "Username" -> "username", "Password" -> "password"]

Answer (score 1):

Whilst the answer from WReach above is correct it may also be helpful to know that there are 2 additional lines that are useful - namely to make sure Jlink is loaded and the Java ClassPath is correct and pointing to your oracle jdbc6.jar file.

```
Needs["JLink`"]
AddToClassPath[
FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications", "Oracle", 
"Java"}]];
```

or if using the answer verbatim just

```
Needs["JLink`"]
AddToClassPath[$jarDirectory];
```