# backing file in memory explaination

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In another thread [The best way to construct a function with memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287817/the-best-way-to-construct-a-function-with-memory/5291299#5291299), it was described how to back in file a function:

```
$runningLogFile = "/some/directory/runningLog.txt";
flog[x_, y_] := flog[x, y] = f[x, y] /.
v_ :> (PutAppend[Unevaluated[flog[x, y] = v;], $runningLogFile]; v)
```

I feel like I understand most of the ingredients here without understanding exactly how this works. Any chance someone could walk me through exactly how this is evaluated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's walk through the evaluation of `flog[1, 2]`, step-by-step...

**flog[1, 2]**

When this expression is evaluated, Mathematica will substitute `1` for `x` and `2` for `y` in the definition of `flog` given in the question.  This yields the next step in our tour:

**flog[1, 2] = 
 f[1, 2] /. v_ :> (PutAppend[Unevaluated[flog[1, 2] = v;], $runningLogFile]; 
    v)**

Note carefully that the assignment here, `flog[1, 2] = ...`, is part of the definition of `flog` itself.

`/.` is an infix operator that is an alternate representation of the [ReplaceAll](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html) function.  `ReplaceAll` will apply a replacement rule to the value of the first argument.  Hold that thought -- we'll come back to it.  The first argument is `flog[1, 2] = f[1, 2]`.  This expression will evaluate `f[1, 2]` and then assign the result to `flog[1, 2]`.  For the sake of discussion, let's assume that `f[1, 2]` returns `345`.  Thus, a new definition will be added to `flog`, namely `flog[1, 2] = 345`.  After assignment, we can check the definition of `flog`:

[image: flog definition]

Observe that where `flog` only had a single definition initially but now it has two -- the newly added `flog[1, 2]` definition caching the result of that call.  This is frequently called "memoization".

`flog[1, 2] = 345` may have the side-effect of establishing a new definition for `flog` but, like every expression in Mathematica, it yields a value as well.  The value is `345` which, after much ado, will be the first argument to `ReplaceAll`.

The second argument to `ReplaceAll` is an invocation of the `:>` operator, an infix expression of the [RuleDelayed](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RuleDelayed.html) function.  In an effort to keep this post to a manageable size, we'll simply note that the rule evaluates to itself in this context.

So, now we have an expression that involves `/.` to evaluate...

**345 /. v_ :> (PutAppend[Unevaluated[flog[1, 2] = v;], $runningLogFile]; v**

A replacement expression matches its first argument (`345`) with the pattern component of the replacement rule (`v_`).  `v_` matches `345` (or anything else for that matter) and gives `345` the name `v` for purposes of replacement.  `ReplaceAll` then substitutes `345` for every occurrence of `v` in the right hand side of the rule.  The result is the next expression to be evaluated...

**(PutAppend[Unevaluated[flog[1, 2] = 345;], $runningLogFile]; 345)**

Here we have two expressions separated by a semicolon.  Incidentally, `;` is an infix operator that expands to [CompoundExpression](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CompoundExpression.html).  The first expression involves [PutAppend](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PutAppend.html) which writes the value of its first argument to the file named as the value of the second argument.  Note, however, that the first argument is wrapped in [Unevaluated](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Unevaluated.html).  This suppresses the evaluation of the first argument so that it will be written exactly as-is to the file: `flog[1, 2] = 345;`.  Should the current Mathematica session end, the written expression can be read into a future Mathematica session to re-establish the memoized result for `flog[1, 2]`.

`CompoundExpression` discards the value of all arguments except the last.  Here, the last argument is `345`.  Since we have come to the end of our expression, this will be the final return value of the original call.  That is, `flog[1, 2]` returns `345` -- although as we saw there were side-effects that saved this result to memory and disk for future reference.

**Future calls to `flog[1, 2]`**

Now if `flog[1, 2]` is called again, Mathematica will find the new definition `flog[1, 2] = 345`.  `345` will be returned directly, without any of the complications that we discussed above.  In particular, it won't even call `f[1, 2]` again.  This, of course, was the whole motivation for this example.  The assumption was that `f` was very expensive to calculate, justifying all of these gymnastics to minimize the number of times that calculation occurs.

Comment: thankyou for an excellent explanaton. One more question though: why do you need the 'v' after the ';' in the parentheses. Why not just:     PutAppend[Unevaluated[flog[x, y] = v;], $runningLogFile]; Is it so the value of flog is printed to screen as well as file?

Comment: Yes, the last `v` provides the final value of the whole expression.  In practice, `flog` is likely to be called many times in the course of performing a much larger computation that requires that result (or all this complexity would not be justified).