# a special Tally function in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am wondering how one can write a special Tally function, which treats the following list `{{{1,0},{2,1,3}},{{1,1},{0,1,1}},{{2,1,2},{3,2}},{{1,0},{2,1}}}` as if:

1. as long as dimensions match, it is equivalent. For example, `{{1,0},{2,1,3}}` and `{{1,1},{0,1,1}}` are equivalent, but not with `{{1,0},{2,1}}`.
2. ordering also does not matter. For example, `{{1,0},{2,1,3}}` and `{{2,1,2},{3,2}}` are equivalent.

The elements of the level `1` list can be artitarily nested. How can I write such a function?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very similar to @Daniel's answer, but preserves a member of each class:

```
In[9]:= Tally[list, (Sort[Length /@ #] == Sort[Length /@ #2]) &]

Out[9]= {{{{1, 0}, {2, 1, 3}}, 3}, {{{1, 0}, {2, 1}}, 1}}
```

Answer (score 7):

(1) Replace all integers with 0.
(2) Sort at level one.
This gives a unique representative for every class in the list.

```
 ll2 = Map[Sort, ll /. aa_Integer -> 0]
```

Out[9]= {{{0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0, 
   0}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}}

```
Tally[ll2]
```

Out[10]= {{{{0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, 3}, {{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, 1}}

Daniel Lichtblau
Wolfram Research

Answer (score 3):

Using [`SelectEquivalents`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/4225830#4225830)

```
SelectEquivalents[list, Dimensions, #&, {#2[[1]], Length@#2}&]
```

which gives the same thing as [Michael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306549/a-special-tally-function-in-mathematica/5307104#5307104), or

```
SelectEquivalents[list, Dimensions, #&, {#2[[1]] /. _Integer -> 0, Length@#2}&]
```

which gives [Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306549/a-special-tally-function-in-mathematica/5306958#5306958). Or, my personal favorite

```
SelectEquivalents[list, Dimensions, #&, {#1, Length@#2}&]
```

which gives

```
{{{2},3}, {{2,2}, 1}}
```

But, that reveals a flaw in using `Dimension`, in that it does not know what to report when the sublists are of different dims, so if we replace `Dimension` with `Sort@Map[Length,#,{1,Infinity}]&`, we can begin to handle arbitrary dimensions.  This gives

```
{{{2, 3}, 3}, {{2, 2}, 1}}
```

So, the dimensionality of each sublist is revealed. This does not sort below the first dimension, and I do not see how it can be immediately fixed.