# Making simplified MakeBoxes

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

What is the simplest way to make an analog of `MakeBoxes` which will reproduce only on aspect of its behavior: converting correct expressions involving only symbols without `FormatValues` to `BoxForms`:

```
Trace[MakeBoxes[graphics[disk[]], StandardForm], TraceInternal -> True]
```

This function should be recursive as `MakeBoxes` is. What is really confusing is how to convert `disk[]` to `RowBox[{"disk", "[", "]"}]` avoiding parsing of string representation of the original expression.

P.S. This question comes from the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534071/is-it-possible-to-create-makeboxesstop-wrapper).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can avoid parsing or string conversion in one way or another - at the end you need strings, and you start with symbols. Either you somehow  [reuse `MakeBoxes`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534071/is-it-possible-to-create-makeboxesstop-wrapper/6534799#6534799), or you have to deal with strings. Dragging my code around: the following simple box-making function is based on the Mathematica parser posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776158/matching-brackets-in-a-string/5776978#5776978) (my second post there, at the bottom of the page):

```
Clear[toBoxes];
toBoxes[expr_] :=
  First[parse[tokenize[ToString@FullForm[expr]]] //. {
    head_String[elem_] :>    RowBox[{head, "[", elem, "]"}], 
    head_String[elems___] :>  RowBox[{head, "[", RowBox[Riffle[{elems}, ","]], "]"}]}]
```

**If you don't want to parse** but don't mind `ToString`, then a slight variation of the above will do:

```
toBoxesAlt[expr_] := 
  expr /. s_Symbol :> ToString[s] //. {
     head_String[elem_] :> RowBox[{head, "[", elem, "]"}], 
     head_String[elems___] :>  RowBox[{head, "[", RowBox[Riffle[{elems}, ","]], "]"}]}
```

Note that this last function does not involve any parsing.Then, we need:

```
Clear[MakeBoxesStopAlt];
MakeBoxesStopAlt /: MakeBoxes[MakeBoxesStopAlt[expr_], form_] :=  toBoxes[expr]
```

For example:

```
In[327]:= MakeBoxesStopAlt[Graphics[Disk[]]]

Out[327]= Graphics[Disk[List[0, 0]]]
```

You may want to re-implement the parser if my implementation looks too complicated, although mine is rather efficient.

**EDIT**

Here is a very simplistic and probably slow approach to parsing: the function `tokenize` is the same as before, and I will repost it here for convenience:

```
tokenize[code_String] :=
 Module[{n = 0, tokenrules}, 
   tokenrules = {"[" :> {"Open", ++n}, "]" :> {"Close", n--}, 
     Whitespace | "" ~~ "," ~~ Whitespace | ""};
   DeleteCases[StringSplit[code, tokenrules], "", Infinity]];
```

Here is the parsing function:

```
parseSimple[tokenized_] :=
  First[tokenized //. {left___, 
     Shortest[
       PatternSequence[h_, {"Open", n_}, elems___, {"Close", n_}]], right___} :> 
       {left, h[elems], right}];
```

You may use it in place of `parse`, and these two functions then form a self-contained solution for the parser.

The same comment as for my answer to your previous question is in order: if you want to handle /disallow expression evaluation, add appropriate attributes and `Unevaluated` wrappers where needed.

**EDIT2**

Here is a version of makeBoxes that does not involve parsing, does not leak evaluation and does handle nested heads correctly (at least for some simple tests):

```
Clear[handleElems];
handleElems[] := Sequence[];
handleElems[el_] := el;
handleElems[els__] := RowBox[Riffle[{els}, ","]];

ClearAll[makeBoxes];
SetAttributes[makeBoxes, HoldAllComplete];
makeBoxes[ex_] :=
 Block[{makeBoxes},
   SetAttributes[makeBoxes, HoldAllComplete];
   makeBoxes[expr_ /;!FreeQ[Unevaluated[expr],
        s_ /; AtomQ[Unevaluated[s]] && ! StringQ[Unevaluated[s]]]] :=    
     makeBoxes[#] &@(Unevaluated[expr] /. 
          s_ /; AtomQ[Unevaluated[s] && ! StringQ[Unevaluated[s]]] :> 
                  ToString[Unevaluated[s]]);

   makeBoxes[a_ /; AtomQ[Unevaluated[a]]] := a;

   makeBoxes[expr_] /; MatchQ[expr, h_String[___]] :=
        expr //. {
           (h : ("Rule" | "RuleDelayed"))[l_, r_] :>
                 RowBox[{l, h /. {
                           "Rule" -> "\[Rule]", 
                           "RuleDelayed" -> "\[RuleDelayed]"
                         }, r}], 
           "List"[elems___] :> RowBox[{"{", handleElems[elems], "}"}], 
           head_String[elems___] :> RowBox[{head, "[", handleElems[elems], "]"}]
        };

   makeBoxes[expr_] := 
       RowBox[{makeBoxes[#] &@Head[expr], "[", 
           handleElems @@ (makeBoxes @@@ expr), "]"}];

   makeBoxes @@ (HoldComplete[ex] /. s_String :> 
       With[{eval = StringJoin["\"", s, "\""]}, eval /; True])   
];
```

Example of use:

```
In[228]:= a=1;b=2;c = 3;

In[229]:= makeBoxes[a:>b]
Out[229]= RowBox[{a,:>,b}]

In[230]:= makeBoxes[a->b]
Out[230]= RowBox[{a,->,b}]

In[231]:= makeBoxes[{a,{b,c}}]
Out[231]= RowBox[{{,RowBox[{a,,,RowBox[{{,RowBox[{b,,,c}],}}]}],}}]

In[232]:= makeBoxes[a[b][c]]
Out[232]= RowBox[{RowBox[{a,[,b,]}],[,c,]}]

In[233]:= makeBoxes[a[b[e[],f[]],c[g[],h[]]][x,y]]

Out[233]= RowBox[{RowBox[{a,[,RowBox[{RowBox[{b,[,RowBox[{RowBox[{e,
   [,]}],,,RowBox[{f,[,]}]}],]}],,,RowBox[{c,[,RowBox[{RowBox[{g,[,]}],,,
    RowBox[{h,[,]}]}],]}]}],]}],[,RowBox[{x,,,y}],]}]
```

In all cases tested, the output is the same as that of `MakeBoxes`.

Comment: Your function gives a little bit different output than `MakeBoxes`: it shows `List` explicitly while `MakeBoxes` converts it to `RowBox[{,"{",...,"}",}]`. I think the default output of `MakeBoxes` is much easier to read.

Comment: Well, you can add another rule to it, to handle this, perhaps as a post-processing step. The rule you  need is `//. RowBox[{"List", "[", elems___, "]"}] :> RowBox[{"{", elems, "}"}]`.

Comment: There is one problem with your solution: it does not handle correctly expressions involving `String`s and even goes to infinite loop when applied directly to a string: compare `makeBoxes[a["c"]]` and `MakeBoxes[a["c"]]` and try `makeBoxes["c"]`.

Comment: And it does not convert numbers to strings as `MakeBoxes` does: compare  `makeBoxes[{1, 1., 1.3}]` and `MakeBoxes[{1, 1., 1.3}]`.

Comment: @Alexey Good points. I did not claim that my function has all the features of `MakeBoxes`, it served to outline the main principle. But these flaws are serious enough, so I updated it. It is now somewhat more complex indeed. I don't claim that the new version is complete either.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation of simplified `MakeBoxes` without conversion of the original expression to string:

```
ClearAll[SimpleMakeBoxes, SimpleMakeBoxesRules];
SetAttributes[SimpleMakeBoxes, HoldAll];
SimpleMakeBoxesRules = {h_Symbol[] :> RowBox[{ToString@h, "[", "]"}], 
   h_Symbol[expr_] :> 
    RowBox[{ToString@h, "[", Unevaluated[expr] /. SimpleMakeBoxesRules, "]"}],
   h_Symbol[expr__] :> 
    RowBox[{ToString@h, "[", 
      RowBox[Riffle[
        List @@ Replace[Hold[expr], 
          x_ :> (Unevaluated[x] /. SimpleMakeBoxesRules), {1}], ","]], "]"}],
   a:(_Real | _Integer | _String) :> ToString[FullForm@a]};
SimpleMakeBoxes[expr_] := 
 Unevaluated[expr] /. 
   SimpleMakeBoxesRules //. {RowBox[{"List", "[", elems___, "]"}] :> 
    RowBox[{"{", elems, "}"}], 
   RowBox[{"Rule", "[", RowBox[{lhs_, ",", rhs_}], "]"}] :> 
    RowBox[{lhs, "\[Rule]", rhs}], 
   RowBox[{"RuleDelayed", "[", RowBox[{lhs_, ",", rhs_}], "]"}] :> 
    RowBox[{lhs, "\[RuleDelayed]", rhs}]}
```

Usage example:

```
In[7]:= SimpleMakeBoxes@Graphics[Disk[]]
RawBoxes@%
Out[7]= RowBox[{Graphics,[,RowBox[{Disk,[,]}],]}]
Out[8]= Graphics[Disk[]]
```

Comment: @Leonid What do you think about my implementation? It seems that it is not necessary to write own parser in this case.

Comment: I don't see a significant difference between your code and my version under the "if you don't want to parse" sentence (`toBoxesAlt`). You added a few postprocessing rules plus evaluation control, but otherwise this is similar, and my version seems somewhat simpler to me.

Comment: I actually looked closer, and found your function unsatisfactory on several grounds. It leaks evaluation (despite your attempts to avoid that), it does not treat the nested heads correctly, and it is overly complex for my taste. See my edit for a function that seems to satisfy my criteria (at least on a limited set of test cases. You can use my test cases with your implementation to see what I mean).