# Pressing arrow keys do not work correctly in Clojure console

Tags: clojure

I downloaded the Clojure jar. Its version is 1.6.0.
When I run Clojure in console I press arrow keys but they don't move the cursor but produce these characters **"[[D^[[C**.

I start Clojure using this command:

```
java -cp clojure-1.6.0.jar clojure.main
```

using Java 1.7.0_55 64 bit on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit.

How can I get back normal arrow keys behaviour ?

Comment: Just a pedantic note, this is not "normal arrow keys behavior", it is the behavior that the `readline` library and its various imitators implement. It isn't a property of the console, it is a property of some program using the console. Normal console behavior is to echo the representation of each key that comes in, which for arrow keys is the strange compound sequence you see here.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The repl bundled with Clojure is pretty terrible. But that's okay, because you want to install [Leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/README.md) *anyway*, and its repl is much better, including the various readline stuff you're used to.

But in general, if there's some app that does a terrible job of being a repl, you can [always use `rlwrap` to wrap the app in readline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639502/one-repl-to-bind-them-all/5639703#5639703).

Comment: For reference, here is the [lein-cljsbuild wiki page on using Readline](https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild/wiki/Using-Readline-with-REPLs-for-Better-Editing).

Answer (score 11):

You are following hopelessly outdated instructions/tutorials. The generally accepted way to interact with all things clojure is through [Leiningen](http://leiningen.org/). Then start Clojure by running:

```
lein repl
```

You can create a new web project by running:

```
lein new compojure my-project-name
```

or a new general project by running:

```
lein new my-project-name
```