# MATLAB: array of symbolic dimension

Tags: matlab

I want to create a D by D matrix, where D is an even positive integer. I then want to fill it with values depending on a lambda and calculate the eigenvalues of the matrix. I'm interested in the smallest eigenvalue as a function of D and lambda.

Is this doable? I absolutely cannot find any way of doing this, and the help only mentions creating matrices of symbolic variables with known dimension.

Comment: No, this is not possible in Matlab or MuPAD.

Comment: Which program could do it?

Comment: I think that Mathematica ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5708208/2278029)) and Sage ([here](http://ask.sagemath.org/question/8074/symbolic-matrices/)) may be able to do this, though it requires some code. You could probably get Matlab to do this too by writing your abstraction layer and procedures, but it would take some doing.