# Using Array and Table Functions in Mathematica. Which is best when

Tags: arrays, wolfram-mathematica

I have been mostly a Table functions user in mathematica. However I have noticed that in several examples where I used Array instead of Table to express the same result, it ran markedly faster, especially as the dimension of table grew larger.

So my question is this: When speed of execution is the primary concern, when is it most appropriate to use table?

What explains this difference?

My guess is that because Arrays assume a functional relationship between the items in the list, it stores them more efficiently, therefore use less memory, thus facilitating storage and subsequent processing?

Is it what is going on?

Comment: @Leonid @Sasha I'd like to add a related question here, if Phil doesn't mind. Is the only reason to choose `ConstantArray` over `Array` or `Table` just speed of execution? Ever since the introduction of ConstantArray I have been wondering about its purpose. I mean, it even doesn't save you typing. `ConstantArray[1, 10^7]` is longer than `Table[1, {10^7}]` and filling a table is so speedy that the difference (which when given as a factor is considerable) isn't really interesting. At least not for symbols (factor of 2), and integers (10). However, for complexes it gets interesting (50).

Comment: @belisarius I meant to say. <beat by the 5 min limit>

Comment: @Sjoerd Apart from the speed-up, the result of `ConstantArray` is automatically packed for numerical constants. And for numerical constants, chances are that you want it packed, so you have to add the time to pack the result produced otherwise (by `Table` or `Array`), plus the convenience - with `ConstantArray` you don't have to think about it.

Comment: @Sjoerd I must add that `Array` and `Table` (the latter in 1D only) will pack for functions which can be compiled, and for number of elements larger than corresponding settings in `SystemOptions->"CompileOptions"` ("ArrayCompileLength" and "TableCompileLength"). So, the difference in packing is for small lists mostly, unless the above options are reset to larger values. But, IMO, it still adds some convenience, and also it looks a bit unnatural to convert a number into a constant pure function like in `Array[1&,{100}]`, just to fit the syntax of `Array` which expects a function.

Comment: @Phil +1 Your question turned out a lot more subtle than I realized.

Comment: @Sasha: I am learning a lot from the posts that have been coming - This site is pretty cool... How do you do to be aware of new relevant questions as soon as they are posted? I only have a daily digest of mathematica questions sent to my e-mail. By that time most have gone cold...

Comment: @Phil You can change the settings for you subscription to questions, so that the time interval can be as small as 15 minutes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Array` has no performance advantages over `Table`. There are differences between them which make one preferred over another.

---

**EDIT** It was noted by several persons that `Table` is slower on multi-dimensional arrays. All of them used variable to hold the table size. `Table` has `HoldAll` attributes and only auto-evaluates outer-most interation bound. Because internal iterators remain unevaluated, the element of the table fails to compile. Using explicit numbers or `With` with result in auto-compilation:

```
In[2]:= With[{b = 10^4, c = 10^4},
 {Timing@(#[[1, 1]] &[ar = Array[(# + #2) &, {b, c}]]) , 
  Timing@(#[[1, 1]] &[ta = Table[(i + j), {i, b}, {j, c}]])}
 ]

Out[2]= {{4.93, 2}, {4.742, 2}}

In[3]:= Attributes[Table]

Out[3]= {HoldAll, Protected}
```

---

The `Array` allows you to build an array of function values just as much as the `Table`. They take different arguments. `Array` takes a function:

```
In[34]:= Array[Function[{i, j}, a[i, j]], {3, 3}]

Out[34]= {{a[1, 1], a[1, 2], a[1, 3]}, {a[2, 1], a[2, 2], 
  a[2, 3]}, {a[3, 1], a[3, 2], a[3, 3]}}
```

while table takes an explicit form:

```
In[35]:= Table[a[i, j], {i, 3}, {j, 3}]

Out[35]= {{a[1, 1], a[1, 2], a[1, 3]}, {a[2, 1], a[2, 2], 
  a[2, 3]}, {a[3, 1], a[3, 2], a[3, 3]}}
```

`Array` can only go over regular arrays, while `Table` can do arbitrary iterating over list:

```
In[36]:= Table[a[i, j], {i, {2, 3, 5, 7, 11}}, {j, {13, 17, 19}}]

Out[36]= {{a[2, 13], a[2, 17], a[2, 19]}, {a[3, 13], a[3, 17], 
  a[3, 19]}, {a[5, 13], a[5, 17], a[5, 19]}, {a[7, 13], a[7, 17], 
  a[7, 19]}, {a[11, 13], a[11, 17], a[11, 19]}}
```

Sometimes `Array` can be more succinct. Compare multiplication table:

```
In[37]:= Array[Times, {5, 5}]

Out[37]= {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}, {3, 6, 9, 12, 15}, {4, 8,
   12, 16, 20}, {5, 10, 15, 20, 25}}
```

versus

```
In[38]:= Table[i j, {i, 5}, {j, 5}]

Out[38]= {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}, {3, 6, 9, 12, 15}, {4, 8,
   12, 16, 20}, {5, 10, 15, 20, 25}}
```

`Array` allows one to build expression with any head, not just list:

```
In[39]:= Array[a, {3, 3}, {1, 1}, h]

Out[39]= h[h[a[1, 1], a[1, 2], a[1, 3]], h[a[2, 1], a[2, 2], a[2, 3]],
  h[a[3, 1], a[3, 2], a[3, 3]]]
```

By default the head `h` is chosen to be `List` resulting in creation of the regular array. Table does not have this flexibility.

Comment: @sasha: these I know.I was looking more for what explains the varying speeds of execution. I have edited the question to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: @Phil I have also expanded the answer. The performance will be better when you get to the result in smaller amount of evaluations. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721171/performance-tuning-in-mathematica

Comment: @Sasha: Good reference. I have to sift through it. it is not so clear after all:Clear[a, ar, t] ; a = 10000000; In: Timing@First[ar = Array[(#^4) &, a]] Out:{24.149, 1} In:Timing@First[ta = Table[i^4, {i, a}]] Out: {21.014, 1}

Comment: @Phil The performance difference is due to time spent evaluating pure function. `Table` does not do this, hence is a little faster.

Comment: @Phil Of course for that example you could use `Timing@First[ra = Range[a]^4]` which is faster still (at least on my computer.)

Comment: There are cases where `Array` is significantly faster, particularly for multi-dimensional arrays. Consider, for instance, `b = 1000;
c = 1000;
Timing@(#[[1, 1]] &[ar = Array[(# + #2) &, {b, c}]])
Timing@(#[[1, 1]] &[ta = Table[(i + j), {i, b}, {j, c}]])`. So the statement of speed equivalence seems to hold only for linear arrays. Perhaps, for multi-dimensional arrays `Table` can not fully utilize the auto-compilation (perhaps can not ensure that array is indeed rectangular, thus can not pack) - I have no other explanation for an order of magnitude performance difference of the above example.

Comment: Also, on general grounds, `Array` must have performance  edge over `Table` at least in some cases, since it has more information than `Table` - that the resulting array is rectangular.

Comment: @Leonid In your example the array produced by `Array` is packed array while for `Table` is not: ``Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ {ar, ta}`` gives `{True, False}`.

Comment: @Alexey  That's exactly the point. `Array` can often pack, since the resulting array is known to be rectangular. For `Table`, this is not always true, since iterators may be dependent on other iterators. See also my comment to @Sjoerd's question on `ConstantArray`.

Comment: @Leonid Please see an edit to my answer, which explains why `Table` was not performing equally with `Array` in your comment from yesterday.

Comment: @Sasha I don't know if this explains/answers everything, but his is an insightful answer. thanks

Answer (score 9):

Michael Trott in *Programming* (pp 707 - 710) address the issue of the differences between `Array` and `Table` and argues that as `Table` has the attribute `HoldAll` it computes its argument for every call, whereas `Array` "to the extent possible" computes its argument only at the beginning. This may lead to differences in behaviour as well as speed.

```
Attributes[Table]
```

{HoldAll, Protected}

```
Attributes[Array]
```

{Protected}

Michael Trott uses the following examples to illustrate the difference in both speed and behaviour.  I am taking them verbatim from his book (disc).  I hope I am not breaking any rules by doing so.

```
Remove[a, i, j];
a = 0;
Table[a = a + 1; ToExpression[StringJoin["a" <> ToString[a]]][i, j],
       {i, 3}, {j, 3}]
```

{{a1[1, 1], a2[1, 2], a3[1, 3]}, {a4[2, 1], a5[2, 2], 
  a6[2, 3]}, {a7[3, 1], a8[3, 2], a9[3, 3]}}

```
a = 0;
Array[a = a + 1; 
 ToExpression[StringJoin["a" <> ToString[a]]], {3, 3}]
```

{{a1[1, 1], a1[1, 2], a1[1, 3]}, {a1[2, 1], a1[2, 2], 
  a1[2, 3]}, {a1[3, 1], a1[3, 2], a1[3, 3]}}

(Note the difference in behaviour)

To illustrate the effect of precomputing the first argument he uses the following example (again verbatim, p 709).

```
o[a = 0;
  Table[a = a + 1; 
   ToExpression[StringJoin["a" <> ToString[a]]][i, j],
         {i, 3}, {j, 3}], {2000}] // Timing
Do[a = 0;
  Array[a = a + 1; ToExpression[ StringJoin["a" <> ToString[a]]], 
                                            {3, 3}], {2000}] // Timing
```

{0.700173, Null}

{0.102587, Null}

(I am using mma7 on a Mac. My copy of *Programming* uses v5.1. There may well be an update to this)

This is not the only difference between `Array` and `Table` discussed in *Programming*, of course.

I view of other answers, I'll be interested to learn what others think of this point.

Answer (score 6):

One reason `Array` may be faster is that it often compiles its first argument better.

In Mathematica 7:

```
In[1]:= SystemOptions[CompileOptions -> ArrayCompileLength]

Out[1]= {"CompileOptions" -> {"ArrayCompileLength" -> 250}}
```

and

```
In[2]:= SystemOptions[CompileOptions -> TableCompileLength]

Out[2]= {"CompileOptions" -> {"TableCompileLength" -> 250}}
```

So one can infer that `Array` and `Table` should compile at the same point.

But let's try it.  I will be making use of [Timo's `timeAvg` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/4199042#4199042):

```
n = 15;
Array[Mod[#^2, 5]*(1 + #2) &, {n, n}] // timeAvg
Table[Mod[i^2, 5]*(1 + j), {i, n}, {j, n}] // timeAvg

(* Out = 0.00034496 *)

(* Out = 0.00030016 *)

n = 16;
Array[Mod[#^2, 5]*(1 + #2) &, {n, n}] // timeAvg
Table[Mod[i^2, 5]*(1 + j), {i, n}, {j, n}] // timeAvg

(* Out = 0.000060032 *)

(* Out = 0.0005008   *)
```

What we see is that Array is able to compile `Mod[#^2, 5]*(1 + #2) &` while `Table` is not able to compile `Mod[i^2, 5]*(1 + j)` and therefore for `Array` becomes faster when the CompileLength is reached.  Many functions are not so favorable.  If you merely change multiplication to division in the function, which results in a rational rather than integer result, then this auto-compile does not happen, and `Table` is faster:

```
n = 15;
Array[Mod[#^2, 5]/(1 + #2) &, {n, n}] // timeAvg
Table[Mod[i^2, 5]/(1 + j), {i, n}, {j, n}] // timeAvg

(* Out = 0.000576   *)

(* Out = 0.00042496 *)

n = 16;
Array[Mod[#^2, 5]/(1 + #2) &, {n, n}] // timeAvg
Table[Mod[i^2, 5]/(1 + j), {i, n}, {j, n}] // timeAvg

(* Out = 0.0005744  *)

(* Out = 0.0004352  *)
```

But what if we can make this compile too?  If we use floating point numbers, done by starting with `1.`, we get `Real` output, which can be compiled:

```
n = 15;
Array[Mod[#^2, 5]/(1 + #2) &, {n, n}, 1.] // timeAvg
Table[Mod[i^2, 5]/(1 + j), {i, 1., n}, {j, 1., n}] // timeAvg

(* Out = 0.0006256  *)

(* Out = 0.00047488 *)

n = 16;
Array[Mod[#^2, 5]/(1 + #2) &, {n, n}, 1.] // timeAvg
Table[Mod[i^2, 5]/(1 + j), {i, 1., n}, {j, 1., n}] // timeAvg

(* Out = 0.00010528 *)

(* Out = 0.00053472 *)
```

And once again, `Array` is faster on the larger dimension array.

Comment: +1 for the expanded analysis of autocompilation. As for why `Table` is slower for multi-dimensional arrays, I think it is not because `Table` is unable to compile, but because it is unable to determine that the resulting array is rectangular (since you can create non-rectangular nested lists with `Table`), and thus can not pack - as I mentioned in my first comment to @Sasha's answer. And if you don't pack, there is little advantage in using Compile, assuming that your function is not incredibly computationally demanding on a single number. But this is just a guess, I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 4):

Your statement:

> However I have noticed that in several examples where I used Array instead of Table to express the same result, it ran markedly faster, especially as the dimension of table grew larger.

is not usually true **for one-dimensional arrays**. Take a look:

```
Cl;
Needs["PlotLegends`"]
$HistoryLength = 0;
a = 10^8;
arr = {}; tab = {};
Do[(
   arr = {First@Timing@Array[# &, a], arr};
   tab = {First@Timing@Table[i, {i, a}], tab};
   ), {10}];

ListLinePlot[{Flatten@arr, Flatten@tab}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["Iteration", 14], Style["Time", 14]}, 
 PlotLegend -> {Style["Array", 14], Style["Table", 14]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {1.6, 2}}]
```

[image]

Comment: @belisarius For higher-dimensional arrays, there are cases when `Array` is order of magnitude faster than `Table`, see my comment to @Sasha's answer for an example.

Comment: @Sjoerd You can control them with **ShadowOffset**

Comment: @ belisarius:I made that observation myself in my comment to @sasha above. @leonid then pointed that in higher dimensions, array has the edge over table...Indeed I made this observation based on work when handling tensors of dim>1 . Liked the plot!

Comment: @Phil I misunderstood your statement _especially as the dimension of table grew larger_

Comment: @belisarius I know, please use it  ;-)

Comment: @belisarius As I remarked elsewhere the `PlotLegends` legends will never win a beauty contest. Look at the size of the box and the spacing.

Answer (score 1):

Without giving some conrete examples, it is difficult to answer your question correctly.

Since Mathematica is a closed source program, the exact implementations behind `Table` and `Array` cannot be known, unless explained by people that were involved in development of Mathematica.

These factors will hinder your ability to reason which structure you should use in what circumstances. Experimentation will be your best bet, so I would suggest you keep parallel versions of your programs, one using `Table`, one using `Array`. This way, you'll be able to see which one is faster.

Even better, you could write a wrapper function which depends on a global variable. This function will, depending on the variable, use `Table`, or `Array` as the underlying implementation, so you will be able to quickly switch from one version to another, without doing many modifications to your code.

Comment: thanks. I am looking for structural explanations, so numerical examples won't provide the insights I am looking for.I have edited the question to make it clearer.