# Command-line arguments of Mathematica Kernel and FrontEnd

Tags: resources, wolfram-mathematica, command-line-arguments, mathematica-frontend

I still know nothing on usage of such command-line options of MathKernel as

```
-lmverbose
-run cmd
-password "pw"
-pwfile "file"
```

How are they working and what they are needed for?

Are there other potentially useful command-line options of the MathKernel and the FrontEnd?

P.S. [Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/5771946#5771946).

Comment: This question will be deleted  sooner or later by other users as it is "not a real question". Much care have been used in the "Mathematica Toolbag" question to prevent that, and we will eventually move all of its contents to the tag wiki, if someone propose to close the question. I suggest you to edit the question there and add answers, instead of creating another post. Also, if you decide in contrary, please flag this question for moderation attention and ask to  converted it to _community wiki_

Comment: @belisarius I think that the subject of this tread differs a bit from "Mathematica Toolbag" and that these threads should be separated. But you are much more experienced and I will do what you say.

Comment: In Spanish there is a meme that goes "Tiene razón, pero marche preso". Something like "You're right, but go to jail".

Comment: @belisarius What do you think about edited version of my question?

Comment: Better now. Let's see if it survives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please consult the following reference pages: [MathKernel](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/program/MathKernel.html) and [Mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/program/Mathematica.html). Opening "More Information" section you will see documented options. Its says

-pwfile "file" -------  read passwords from file

-run cmd  ----------- run cmd on startup

-lmverbose   ------------ print information on interactions with MathLM

---

One can use -run option to execute certain commands before the first input, and it will not affect `In`/`Out`. Try `MathKernel -run "a=1"` and evaluate `a` on In[1](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/program/MathKernel.html).

Comment: I just found what [MathLM](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/program/mathlm.html) is.

Comment: @Sasha Your addition about `run` eliminates ambiguity. I thought that this command just allows to run another program with path specified in `cmd` argument. But how large `cmd` is allowed to be?

Comment: @Alexey It can be anything, including `Get` of a large program.

Comment: @Sasha I mean how long `cmd` can be itself? Are there any limitations?

Comment: @Alexey I am unsure, but strongly suspect that the limitations are those of OS. On Linux, for instance, these can be multi-line and be of any length.

Comment: I just found [in the Documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Run.html) an example of using `-run` command-line argument: `commandstring=First[$CommandLine]<>" -noprompt -run \"Put[Factorial[20],ToFileName[$TemporaryPrefix,ToString[temp1]]];Quit[]\"";Run[commandstring]`