# How to delete the input cell upon evaluation?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I would like to accomplish the following: upon evaluation of an input cell, it should self-destruct (i.e. delete itself).  I tried to hack something together with `SelectionMove` and `NotebookDelete`, but didn't quite get what I wanted.

Here are potential use cases:

- the command might be a shorthand for a series of other commands that will be generated dynamically and inserted into the notebook
- the command might only be used for side effects (e.g. to set a notebook option or to open a new notebook); leaving the command in the notebook after evaluation serves no purpose and creates clutter

Edit: As per Mr. Wizard, the answer is `SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Previous, Cell]; NotebookDelete[];`.  I don't know why it wasn't working for me before.  Here is some code that uses this idiom.

```
writeAndEval[nb_, boxExpr_] := (NotebookWrite[nb, 
    CellGroupData[{Cell[BoxData[boxExpr], "Input"]}]];
   SelectionMove[nb, Previous, Cell];
   SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell];
   SelectionEvaluate[nb]);

addTwoAndTwo[] := Module[{boxExpr},
  boxExpr = RowBox[{"2", "+", "2"}];
  SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Previous, Cell];
  NotebookDelete[];
  writeAndEval[EvaluationNotebook[], boxExpr];
  ]
```

Now, running `addTwoAndTwo[]` deletes the original input and makes it look as if you've evaluated "2+2".  Of course, you can do all sorts of things instead and not necessarily print to the notebook.

Edit 2: Sasha's abstraction is quite elegant.  If you are curious about "real-world" usage of this, check out the code I posted in the "what's in your toolbag" question: [What is in your Mathematica tool bag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/5917798#5917798)

Comment: Leo, the application I envisioned was that of transparent use, where a user would evaluate a cell on their on machine, and have it replaced with the output.  For example, where you want a graphic (but don't want the bytes for a graphic), you put the code for the graphic instead, and change the `CellEvaluationFunction` as shown.  Then, the user would evaluate all cells, producing the final document that you intended him to read, without excess Input cells cluttering it up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Or, building on [Mr. Wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/618728/mr-wizard)'s solution, you can create a function `SelfDestruct`, which will delete the input cell, if you intend to only do this occasionally:

```
SetAttributes[SelfDestruct, HoldAllComplete];
SelfDestruct[e_] := (If[$FrontEnd =!= $Failed,
   SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, EvaluationCell]; 
   NotebookDelete[]]; e)
```

Then evaluating `2+3//SelfDestruct` outputs `5` and deletes the input cell. This usage scenario seems more appealing to me.

Comment: Ah, this is precisely what I wanted.  This allowed me to clean up lots of nasty code...  gotta give you the check mark :)

Answer (score 9):

To affect all Input cells, evaluate this is the notebook:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CellEvaluationFunction -> 
  ( (
    SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, EvaluationCell]; NotebookDelete[];
    ToExpression@#
  )&)
]
```

If you only want to affect one cell, then select the cell and use the Options Inspector to set `CellEvaluationFunction` as above.