# What is the simplest way to constraint a built-in function's output in Mathematica? say let Sin returns only odd numbers?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

For example, for a **built-in** function in Mathematica, f,  originally f[1] gives {1,2,3}, but I want to let Mathematica gives only {1,3}. A simple method for **rewritting** f is desired. I don't want to define a new function or totally rewrite f or just dealing with original f's outputs. I want to rewite f.

Thanks. :)

Comment: `$Post` seems to be an good way, but it applies to all built-function which is not I want?

Comment: `$Post` is applied to every output expression as it is clearly stated in the documentation. It knows nothing on how this expression was generated.

Comment: In you example, do you mean `f[1]` gives `{1,2,3}`, or do you mean something like `f /@ {3, 5, 7}` gives `{1,2,3}`?  I ask because `Sin` gives a single numerical output, not a list.

Comment: There are some solutions below, but it's really asking for trouble mucking with system symbols.  It's much better to write a new function mySin[], calling the built in Sin[] and altering the output before returning.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [the Villegas-Gayley trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/5149656#5149656) for this.

For the `Sin` function:

```
Unprotect[Sin];
Sin[args___]/;!TrueQ[$insideSin]:=
   Block[{$insideSin=True,result},
      If[OddQ[result=Sin[args]],result]
   ];
Protect[Sin];
{Sin[Pi],Sin[Pi/2]}

==> {Null,1}
```

Comment: @Sjoerd：Your answer is what I have looking for for a really long time. Sorry for the late response. :( and Many, many thanks for this brilliant hacking method! :)

Comment: @Fresh Actually, the above was written by Alexey who was referring to a trick we have been using quite a lot here since it was published in the Mathematica toolbag question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/5149656#5149656).

Answer (score 6):

I prefer a method which is functional and reminds me of decorators in Python. http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators

First we create the decorator:

```
OddOnly[x_] := If[OddQ[x], x, Null];
```

It can then be used as a prefix:

```
OddOnly@
 Sin[Pi]

Null (* Doesn't actually give a result *)

OddOnly@
 Sin[Pi/2]

1
```

Answer (score 6):

A variation of Searke's method that I prefer is:

```
OddOnly[s_Symbol] := 
 Composition[If[OddQ@#, #, ##&[]] &, s]
```

This automatically removes results that are not odd, and it is applied to the function itself, which I find more convenient.

Examples:

```
OddOnly[Sin] /@ {2, Pi, Pi/2}

(*  Out[]= {1}  *)

Array[OddOnly[Binomial], {5, 5}]

(*  Out[]= {{1}, {1}, {3, 3, 1}, {1}, {5, 5, 1}}  *)
```

Comment: Nice idea - +1. Since I know about your passion for terseness, let me point out that the effect equivalent to `Unevaluated@Sequence[]` inside `If` (or any head that is `Hold*` but not `SequenceHold`) can be achieved also with  `Sequence@@{}`.

Comment: @Leonid that is a great tip!  I wish I had thought of that; it makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Leonid, interestingly, that short form comes with a small performance penalty.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, sure, there is a little performance penalty. But I haven't yet seen a single use case for it where this would be noticeable, let alone be the major bottleneck.

Comment: @Leonid, I did notice the difference in the first place I tried it. ;-)  Nevertheless, I was mostly remarking on the fact that it was slower, which I could not predict before trying it; `Sequence @@ {}` seems very simple, why should there be any performance penalty?  (Please do not think that because of this slight penalty, I am any less grateful for your tip!)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The penalty is because it is one evaluation more, I think. `Unevaluated` gets stripped by the evaluator, without any sub-evaluation induced. But `Apply[Sequence,{}]` must undergo a separate evaluation. May be, there are other more subtle reasons that I am not aware of, as well.

Comment: @Leonid, appreciate your thoughts.  Interestingly, if I set `vanish[] := Sequence[]` and then use `vanish[]` it is almost as fast as `Unevaluated@Sequence[]`; faster than `Sequence @@ {}`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard This seems logical. Before I became aware of `Sequence@@{}`, I was using `1/.(1:>Sequence[])` or something similar, which is a local version of your `vanish`. I think, in part the speed gain here is due to `RuleDelayed` (and `SetDelayed`) being `SequenceHold`. Simply rewriting is faster than inducing (sub)evaluation, which is what happens with `Apply`.

Comment: @Leonid, today in my notes I found an even shorter form: `##&[]`  I wish I was half as retentive as I am clever. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Could apply a rule of the form

```
whatever /. _Integer?EvenQ :>Sequence[]
```

Daniel Lichtblau