# When to use Hold / ReleaseHold in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Example and background ( note the usage of Hold, ReleaseHold ):

The following code represents a static factory method to create a scenegraph object ( from an XML file ). The (output-)field is an instance of CScenegraph ( an OO-System class ).

```
 new[imp_]:= Module[{
 ret,
 type = "TG",
 record ={{0,0,0},"Root TG"}
 },
 ret = MathNew[
    "CScenegraph", 
    2,
    MathNew["CTransformationgroup",1,{type,record},0,0,0,0,Null]];
 ret@setTree[ret];
 ret@getRoot[]@setColref[ret];
 csp = loadClass["CSphere"];
 spheres = Cases[imp, XMLElement["sphere", _, __], Infinity];
 codesp = Cases[spheres, XMLElement["sphere", 
    {"point" -> point_, "radius" -> rad_, "hue" -> hue_}, {}] -> Hold[csp@new[ToExpression[point], ToExpression[rad], ToExpression[hue]]]];
 ret@addAschild[ret@getRoot[],ReleaseHold[codesp]];
 ret
 ];
```

My question is about the following:

```
spheres = Cases[imp, XMLElement[\sphere\, _, __], Infinity];
codesp = Cases[spheres, XMLElement[\sphere\, 
    {\point\ -> point_, \radius\ -> rad_, \"hue\" -> hue_}, {}] -> Hold[csp@new[ToExpression[point], ToExpression[rad], ToExpression[hue]]]];
ret@addAschild[ret@getRoot[],ReleaseHold[codesp]];
```

where

```
  addAschild
```

adds ( a list of ) geometries to a ( root ) transformationgroup and has the signature

```
  addAsChild[parent MathObject, child MathObject], or
  addAsChild[parent MathObject, Children List{MathObject, ...}]
```

and the XML element representing a sphere looks as follows:

```
  <sphere point='{0., 1., 3.}'
  radius='1'
  hue='0.55' />
```

If I do NOT USE Hold[] , ReleaseHold[] I end up with objectdata like

```
  {"GE", {"SP", {CScenegraph`point, CScenegraph`rad}}, {CScenegraph`hue}}
```

while I would have expected

```
  {"GE", {"SP", {{4., 3., -4.}, 3.}}, {0.45}}
```

(The above code with Hold[], ReleaseHold[] yields the correct data.)

#### Questions

#### 1. Why is Hold necessary in this case? ( In fact, is it? Is there a way to code this without Hold[], ReleaseHold[]? ) ( I got it right by trial and error! Don't really understand why. )

#### 2. As a learning point: What is the prototypical example / case for the usage of Hold / ReleaseHold?

### EDIT:

Summary of Leonid's answer. Change this code

```
  codesp = Cases[spheres, XMLElement["sphere", 
{"point" -> point_, "radius" -> rad_, "hue" -> hue_}, {}] -> Hold[csp@new[ToExpression[point], ToExpression[rad], ToExpression[hue]]]];
  ret@addAschild[ret@getRoot[],ReleaseHold[codesp]];
```

to:

```
  codesp = Cases[spheres, XMLElement["sphere", 
{"point" -> point_, "radius" -> rad_, "hue" -> hue_}, {}] :> csp@new[ToExpression[point], ToExpression[rad], ToExpression[hue]]];
  ret@addAschild[ret@getRoot[],codesp];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer for the first question is that you probably should have used `RuleDelayed` rather than `Rule`, and then you don't need `Hold`-`ReleaseHold`.

It is hard to be sure what is going on since your code sample is not self-contained. One thing to be sure is that OO-System performs non-trivial manipulations with contexts, since it uses contexts as an encapsulation mechanism (which makes sense). Normally, `Rule` and `RuleDelayed` inject the matched expressions in the r.h.s., so it is not clear how this could happen. Here is one possible scenario (you may execute this in a notebook):

```
BeginPackage["Test`"]
f[{a_Symbol, b_Symbol}] := {c, d};
fn[input_] :=  Cases[input, XMLElement[{"a" -> a_, "b" -> b_}, {}, {}] -> f[{a, b}]];
fn1[input_] := Cases[input, XMLElement[{"a" -> a_, "b" -> b_}, {}, {}] :> f[{a, b}]];
EndPackage[];
$ContextPath = DeleteCases[$ContextPath, "Test`"]
```

Now,

```
In[71]:= Test`fn[{XMLElement[{"a"->1,"b"->2},{},{}],{"a"->3,"b"->4},{"a"->5,"b"->6}}]
Out[71]= {{Test`c,Test`d}}
```

What happened is that, since we used `Rule` in `XMLElement[...]->rhs`, the `r.h.s.` evaluates before the substitution takes place - in this case the function `f` evaluates. Now,

```
In[78]:= Test`fn1[{XMLElement[{"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2}, {}, {}], 
      {"a" ->3, "b" -> 4}, {"a" -> 5, "b" -> 6}}]

Out[78]= {Test`f[{1, 2}]}
```

The result is different here since the idiom `XMLElement[...] :> rhs` was used in implementation of `fn1`, involving `RuleDelayed` this time. Therefore, `f[{a,b}]` was not evaluated until `a` and `b` were substituted by the matching numbers from the l.h.s. And since `f`  does not have a rule for the argument of the form of list of 2 numbers, it is returned.

The reason why your method with `Hold`-`ReleaseHold` worked is that this prevented the r.h.s. (function `f` in my example, and the call to `new` in your original one) from evaluation until the values for pattern variables have been substituted into it.  As a side note, you may find it useful to add better error-checking to your constructor (if OO-System allows that), so that problems like this would be better diagnosed at run-time.

So, the bottom line: use `RuleDelayed`, not `Rule`.

---

To answer the second question, the combination `ReleaseHold`-`Hold` is generally useful when you want to manipulate the held code before you allow it to evaluate. For example:

```
In[82]:= 
{a,b,c}={1,2,3};
ReleaseHold[Replace[Hold[{a,b,c}],s_Symbol:>Print[s^2],{2}]]

During evaluation of In[82]:= 1
During evaluation of In[82]:= 4
During evaluation of In[82]:= 9

Out[83]= {Null,Null,Null}
```

One can probably come up with more sensible examples. This is especially useful for things like code-generation - one less trivial example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214946/how-to-dynamically-generate-mathematica-code/6215394#6215394). The specific case at hand, as I already mentioned, does not really fall into the category of cases where `Hold`-`ReleaseHold` are beneficial - they are here just a workaround, which is not really necessary when you use delayed rules.

Comment: Leonid ( This is embryonic code still requiring tons of work, but I have to start with something. ) RuleDelayed is fairly new to me, I'll read up on this, no doubt that you are right about it though. Adding ToExpression was an attempt to fix it in my trial/error session. I will try running without it. - Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @ndroock1 I find myself using `RuleDelayed` much more frequently than `Rule`, for exactly the reason I described above. Generally, it is safer. I covered these topics here: http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node149.html, although on a rather elementary level. And you can find lots of examples involving it by reading the past SO Mathematica questons: `RuleDelayed` is truly ubiquitous in mma programming. Reading on it is a very good idea, since learning its usage is essential for creating non-trivial mma programs.

Comment: Leonid, Will definitely read up on this topic. - I tried but ToExpression can't be missed in this stage ( in the Sphere constructor I add translation vectors so it must contain numerical data. ) Anyway, it might be possible in a code clean-up later.

Comment: @ndroock1 You are right about `ToExpression` - my bad. They were only useless in the wrong approach (without `Hold`-`ReleaseHold`),  where symbols were not substituted by values. Since values are strings, they should be parsed to numbers. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @_Leonid i have summarized your answer on part 1 below the question.

Comment: Leonid, you've been very busy while I was away!  Congratulations on #1 ranking.

Comment: @Mr.W: However, belisarius _might_ get the gold badge first. Leonid's answers garner a lot of upvotes and I'm not sure if he'll have 70 more answers by the time belisarius gets 300 more upvotes (Leonid will cross 1000 upvotes first, but he also needs 200 answers to be awarded the badge).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks! I am happy to know that you are back, since it looks like I'll have less time to be here on SO in the next few weeks.

Comment: @yoda Interesting. I did not know that you need also 200 answers for the gold badge, I thought it is just upvotes. But anyway, it will only be right that belisarius gets it first.

Comment: @Leonid: Initially, you could get the gold badge from just 1000 upvotes. However, some questions/answers get shared on social sites like reddit/Hackernews/Facebook/Twitter and just explode in views and upvotes. Take [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/) question and the top answer, for e.g. or even belisarius' top voted answer. Soon, [people realized](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30193/) that once they had a post with 1000 upvotes, they could just add additional tags to the question and get cool gold badges for each and that's why this limit is in place.

Comment: @yoda Thanks for the clarification, makes perfect sense.