# Auto complete brackets in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, brackets

Not a long ago I started to learn Mathematica - i.e. I'm novice. Usually I code in text editors with auto close of brackets like Gedit,Notepad++,Qt IDE etc.
It's very convenient when you are not  obliged to watch over brackets. 
 But my attempts to find similar functionality in Mathematica weren't successful. I can't believe that such a powerful tool doesn't have such simple thing. Does anyone know how to autocomplete brackets?

Comment: fyi, somewhat related question at SO is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137716/mathematica-editor-removing-the-right-matching-automatically-when-the-left

Comment: What I do is this: I first type in the parentheses, say (), then after that, I fill the inside. Same for  [[  ]].  This might help a little.

Comment: yeah, it's good but it's much better when system does this stuff for you and you are able to concentrate at your task

Comment: Could this be migrated/included in mathematica.SE?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could experiment with something like:

```
SetOptions[InputNotebook[], 
 InputAutoReplacements -> {"[" -> "[\[SelectionPlaceholder]]", 
   "{" -> "{\[SelectionPlaceholder]}", 
   "(" -> "(\[SelectionPlaceholder])"}]
```

Note that the replacement doesn't happen until you type a character *after* the opening bracket.  If you like the result you can then apply this more globally.

Comment: If to be honest I expected something like option  in menu or plugin. It is not what I was waiting for, but it's even better!

Comment: The menu option is **Insert > Typesetting > Matching []** etc... (with keyboard shortcuts.)  But I generally find it easier to just type [], even instead of the shortcut.

Comment: You might need to modify this so that you can still use the shorthand for `Part`: `[[ ]]`

Comment: @Simon It should just work. `x[[` turns into `x[[]` with the insertion point before the last bracket, and then typing a specification (1, All, etc...) will add the second closing bracket.

Comment: Brett: My bad. Should have checked (or even just thought) before commenting.

Comment: While this is nice in continuous typing, it is very annoying when you go back and correct/edit your code. For e.g., it works smoothly when  write `f[a,g[b]]`, but if I go back to change the `a` to a `c`, then it inserts another `]`, since the cursor was next to `[` to give `f[c],g[b]]`. This compounds the work, since you have to now go back and delete it

Comment: @yoda And it's also a pain if you want change it to `h[1,f[a,g[b]]]`.  I very specifically had the answer only affect a single notebook.  Having this enabled by default would personally drive me nuts.

Answer (score 15):

As an alternative, Alt+] will produce [] and move the insertion point inside the [].

Answer (score 0):

Auto-completion of brackets has been introduced in version 13:

https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2021/12/launching-version-13-0-of-wolfram-language-mathematica/

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/EnterPairedDelimiters.html