# Mathematica: Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in {Null} {} cannot be combined. >>

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have aproblem:

Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in {Null} {} cannot be combined. >>

It seems to occur in the while test which makes no sense at all since I am onlu comparing numbers...?

The program is a program to solve the 0-1 knapsack dynamic programming problem though I use loops, not recursion.

I have put some printouts and i can only think that the problem is in the while loop and it doesnt make sense.

```
(*  0-1 Knapsack problem
 item = {value, weight} 
  Constraint is maxweight. Objective is to max value. 
 Input on the form:
 Matrix[{value,weight},
       {value,weight},
        ...
      ]
*)

lookup[x_, y_, m_] := m[[x, y]];

generateTable[items_, maxweight_] := {
  nbrofitems = Dimensions[items][[1]];
  keep = values = Table[0, {j, 0, nbrofitems}, {i, 1, maxweight}];
  For[j = 2, j <= nbrofitems + 1, j++,
   itemweight = items[[j - 1, 2]];
   itemvalue = items[[j - 1, 1]];
   For[i = 1, i <= maxweight, i++,
    {
     x = lookup[j - 1, i, values];
     diff = i - itemweight;
     If[diff > 0, y = lookup[j - 1, diff, values], y = 0];
     If[itemweight <= i ,
      {If[x < itemvalue + y,
        {values[[j, i]] = itemvalue + y; keep[[j, i]] = 1;},
        {values[[j, i]] = x; keep[[j, i]] = 0;}]
       },
      y(*y eller x?*)]
     }
    ]
   ];
  {values, keep}
  }

pickItems[keep_, items_, maxweight_] :=
 {
  (*w=remaining weight in knapsack*)
  (*i=current item*)
  w = maxweight;
  knapsack = {};
  nbrofitems = Dimensions[items][[1]];
  i = nbrofitems + 1;
  x = 0;
  While[i > 0 && x < 10,
   {
      Print["lopp round starting"];
      x++;
      Print["i"];
      Print[i];
      Print["w"];
      Print[w];
      Print["keep[i,w]"];
      Print[keep[[i, w]]];
      If[keep[[i, w]] == 1,
       {Append[knapsack, i];
        Print["tjolahej"];
        w -= items[[i - 1, 2]];
        i -= 1;
        Print["tjolahopp"];
        },
       i -= 1;
       ];
      Print[i];
      Print["loop round done"];
      }
     knapsack;
   ]
  }

Clear[keep, v, a, b, c]
maxweight = 5;
nbrofitems = 3;
a = {5, 3};
b = {3, 2};
c = {4, 1};
items = {a, b, c};


MatrixForm[items]
results = generateTable[items, 5];
keep = results[[1]][[2]];
Print["keep:"];
MatrixForm[keep]
Print["------"];
results2 = pickItems[keep, items, 5];
MatrixForm[results2]
```

Comment: I am on an iPad so no Mma here, but a couple of comments on your code. First, `values` definition doesn't need `i` and `j`. Outer `For` loop could be a `FoldList` instead. Also, you are creating global variables in the function. You should put them in a `Module`. It would help to know the input data you are using.

Comment: If I may give a general recommendation, I'd try to better localize the problematic portion of the code and construct a minimal self - contained example illustrating the problem. That's more work on your side, but you'll learn more and also increase chances for a better answer, since more people will be willing to spend their time looking at your code. This question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167291/how-to-debug-when-writting-small-or-big-codes-using-mathematica-workbench-mma-d/ contains some discussion on debugging of mma code.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer to the specific question being asked, but some hints on general situations when this error occurs. The short answer is that this is a sign of passing lists of unequal lengths to some `Listable` function, user-defined or built-in.

Many of Mathematica's built-in functions are [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Listable.html)(have `Listable` attribute). This basically means that, given lists in place of some or all arguments, Mathematica automatically threads the function over them. What really happens is that `Thread` is called internally (or, at least, so it appears). This can be illustrated by

```
In[15]:= 
ClearAll[f];
SetAttributes[f,Listable];
f[{1,2},{3,4,5}]

During evaluation of In[15]:= Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in 
f[{1,2},{3,4,5}] cannot be combined. >>
Out[17]= f[{1,2},{3,4,5}]
```

You can get the same behavior by using `Thread` explicitly:

```
In[19]:= 
ClearAll[ff];
Thread[ff[{1,2},{3,4,5}]]

During evaluation of In[19]:= Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in 
ff[{1,2},{3,4,5}] cannot be combined. >>
Out[20]= ff[{1,2},{3,4,5}]
```

In case of `Listable` functions, this is a bit more hidden though. Some typical examples would include things like `{1, 2} + {3, 4, 5}` or `{1, 2}^{3, 4, 5}` etc. I discussed this issue in a bit more detail [here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node199.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this version:

```
pickItems[keep_, items_, maxweight_] := Module[{},
  {(*w=remaining weight in knapsack*)(*i=current item*)w = maxweight;
   knapsack = {};
   nbrofitems = Dimensions[items][[1]];
   i = nbrofitems + 1;
   x = 0;
   While[i > 0 && x < 10,
    {
     Print["lopp round starting"];
     x++;
     Print["i"];
     Print[i];
     Print["w"];
     Print[w];
     Print["keep[i,w]"];
     Print[keep[[i, w]]];

     If[keep[[i, w]] == 1,
      {
       Append[knapsack, i];
       Print["tjolahej"];
       w -= items[[i - 1, 2]];
       i -= 1;
       Print["tjolahopp"];
       },
      i -= 1;
      ];

     Print[i];
     Print["loop round done"]
     };
     knapsack
    ]
   }
  ]
```

no errors now, but I do not know what it does really :)