# Switching on and off the ShowIt debugging function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I like to use the variant of ShowIt for debugging purpose in Mathematica defined here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8270643/884752. I was reading again the idea of rcollyer to use messages for some functions to turn them on or off here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4211700/884752. And I'm asking myself if it would be possible to do something similar for ShowIt, but I didn't manage to. Does someone have any idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your intention:

```
debug::ShowIt = "`1`";
SetAttributes[System`ShowIt, HoldAll];
System`ShowIt[code__] := System`ShowIt[{code}];
System`ShowIt[code_] :=
  With[{y = code},
    Message[debug::ShowIt, HoldForm[code = y]];
    y
  ];
```

> ```
> In[5]:= ShowIt[2 + 2]
>
> During evaluation of In[5]:= debug::ShowIt: 2 + 2 = 4
>
> Out[5]= 4
>
> In[6]:= Off[debug::ShowIt]
>         ShowIt[2 + 2]
>
> Out[7]= 4
> ```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I wanted. I cannot convert the output of the debug message to an input format like I do for the original ShowIt. Is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: @Faysal, I don't know.  I'll make an attempt tomorrow.