# How to write a showIt function in Haskell?

Tags: debugging, haskell, functional-programming, wolfram-mathematica

In Mathematica, [`ShowIt` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167291/how-to-debug-when-writting-small-or-big-codes-using-mathematica-workbench-mma) is commonly used for debugging. 
Basically, `ShowIt` is an identity function that prints the value of its parameter to the console. I wonder, how it is possible to write the same function for Haskell. The issue with Haskell is that since the function does IO, it cannot have the same return type as the input type. I think we have to use **unsafe IO** to implement `showIt`. But I have no idea how.

Comment: For a better way of debugging pure code, see [You Could Have Invented Monads! (And Maybe You Already Have)](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This already exists in the `Debug.Trace` package. It's called [`traceShowId`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Debug-Trace.html#v:traceShowId). (And it does use `unsafePerformIO` under the covers - you can see [the implementation of `trace` here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/src/Debug-Trace.html#trace).)