# Mapping two argument function in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to archive:

```
Map2[f,{a,b,c,d}]
{f[a,b], f[b,c], f[c,d]}
```

But for some reason, I can only think of iterative approaches.

What's the functional way?

## Edit:

Use of this, was to generate graph examples. If number list is given, following generates the graph of what it would mean, to sequentially visit all the nodes.

For example:

```
Map2 = # @@@ Partition[#2, 2, 1] &;
MG[elems_] := Graph[Map2[DirectedEdge, elems]]
nrs = RandomInteger[{1, 15}, 20]
MG[nrs]
```

{10,13,9,7,13,3,5,1,15,10,15,6,14,3,1,2,11,4,8,5}

Radial layout:

[image]

Comment: @d00b it must be; `Graph` is not in v7.

Comment: @d00b: Yes, this use case is for Mathematica 8. Although note, that question itself is not version specific. All the more reason, to appreciate good answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most simply:

```
Map2 = # @@@ Partition[#2, 2, 1] &;
```

Or, possibly using less memory, but running a bit slower:

```
Map2[f_, lst_] := Developer`PartitionMap[f @@ # &, lst, 2, 1]
```

Also, be aware of [`Differences`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Differences.html) and [`Accumulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Accumulate.html), which are related.

---

Other ways:

```
Inner[#, Most@#2, Rest@#2, List] &
```

Notice that in this one `List` could be a different function.

```
MapThread[#, {Most@#2, Rest@#2}] &

Most@MapThread[#, {#2, RotateLeft@#2}] &

Rest@MapThread[#, {RotateRight@#2, #2}] &

Table[# @@ #2[[i ;; i + 1]], {i, Length@#2 - 1}] &
```

---

Now, the timings.  I will make use of [Timo's `timeAvg`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/4199042#4199042).

```
f1 = # @@@ Partition[#2, 2, 1] &;
f2[f_, lst_] := Developer`PartitionMap[f @@ # &, lst, 2, 1]
f3 = Inner[#, Most@#2, Rest@#2, List] &;
f4 = MapThread[#, {Most@#2, Rest@#2}] &;
f5 = Most@MapThread[#, {#2, RotateLeft@#2}] &;
f6 = Table[# @@ #2[[i ;; i + 1]], {i, Length@#2 - 1}] &;

timings = 
  Table[
   list = RandomReal[99, 10^i];
   func = Plus;
   timeAvg[#[func, list]] & /@ {f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6},
   {i, 6}
  ];

TableForm[timings, 
 TableHeadings -> {10^Range@6, {"f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", "f6"}}]

ListLogPlot[timings\[Transpose], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

[image]

The numbers on the left side of the table are the length of the list of real numbers for each run.

Note that the graph is logarithmic.

Here are the bytes of memory used while processing the longest list (1,000,000):

[image]

---

After doing the timings above, I found I can make `f6` faster by eliminating `Apply` (`@@`).  It is now clearly the fastest on longer lists.  I will not add it to the table above because that is already wide enough, but here is the function and its timings:

```
f7 = Table[#2[[i]] ~#~ #2[[i + 1]], {i, Length@#2 - 1}] &;
```

[image]

Comment: @Margus, I am glad that helps.  I am not done with my answer.  There are other ways, and I want to add timings, so check back later.

Comment: @Mr. I am going to add all your functions to my answer in retaliation :)

Comment: @Mr. I am taking offense of this :). You forgot to include my only contribution in the test. Did I win? :)

Comment: @Mr. In my score, the one using `Inner` is the fastest, and the deleted one is second.

Comment: @belisarius, correction made.  Did you use the same code, or different?  I wonder if `Table` is slower in v8.

Comment: @Mr. I used my code, very similar to yours. Not much to invent there. The only significant difference I get is that the last function (using Table) is much slower here (by a factor of 6). Perhaps a parallelization issue.

Answer (score 9):

As explained in the [*Mathematica* cookbook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596521004) mapping a function over a moving sublist can  be elegantly solved with the [ListConvole](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListConvolve.html) function:

```
Map2[f_, l_List] := ListConvolve[{1, 1}, l, {-1, 1}, {}, #2 &, f]

In[11]:= Map2[f, {a, b, c, d}]
Out[11]= {f[a, b], f[b, c], f[c, d]}
```

---

*Mr.Wizard here, adding comparative timings as requested by sakra.*

[image]

[image]

Comment: I knew I was forgetting something. :-)

Comment: (grumble mode) I voted for this myself, because it is helpful, but it is **not** the best method here.  In fact, it is slower than any of the options I gave.  Nothing against you sakra, but I don't think it should rank so highly.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Can you add the ListConvole option to your timing test plot?

Comment: sakra, may I edit your post to include a comparative graph, or would you prefer that I do not?

Comment: Done.  Observe that `Map2` is uniformly slower than the simple `f1`.  `f3` is usually faster than `f1` but it has a strange bobble on the 10^5 list.  `f7` starts out slow, but once automatic compilation kicks in, it is easily the fastest.

Comment: These are really some interesting findings. It shows that ListConvole is just a too general function for the problem at hand. I have upvoted your solution to put you out of grumble mode ;-)

Comment: lol, thanks for the "grumble" vote.  Indeed, ListConvolve (and ListCorrelate) are very fast with their default functions, but slow down considerably when made general.  If it is possible to reformulate a problem in terms of `Times` and `Plus` however, they can be great.

Answer (score 7):

I like:

```
Map2[f_, l_List]:= MapThread[f, {Most@l, Rest@l}]

In[988]:= Map2[f,{a,b,c,d}]
Out[988]= {f[a,b],f[b,c],f[c,d]}
```

Answer (score 6):

I recently re-read your question and saw your `Graph[ ]` application.

I think the natural way to do that is:

```
f[l_] := Graph[Thread[Most@l -> Rest@l]]
```

So

```
f[{10, 13, 9, 7, 13, 3, 5, 1, 15, 10, 15, 6, 14, 3, 1, 2, 11, 4, 8, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for bothering to read the updated question, and giving a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

Following belisarius' lead, and addressing your `Graph` application, this should be a little faster:

```
f = Inner[Rule, Most@#, Rest@#, Composition[Graph, List]] &;
```

Comment: I think that being the current application to display a _directed_ graph, it is doubtful that speed matters _that_ much. A huge Graph is almost illegible :). +1

Comment: @belisarius I thought `Graph` was used for other stuff, not just display. No?  Thanks for the +1 anyway.  I like your solution much better.

Comment: from the question context seems the display is the objective, but you may well be right.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I saw the other solutions and they seem quite complex and obfuscate. This is a lot simpler to understand, at least if you like a more functional approach:

```
MapApplyImpl[fun_] := Function[{args}, Apply[fun, args]]
MapApply[fun_, argList_] := Map[MapApplyImpl[fun], argList]
```

and a usage example:

```
ff := Function[{t, phi}, t*phi]
MapApply[ff, {{0, Pi/4}, {(Pi/4)/(10^3) , 0}, {(2*Pi/(10^3)), 
   Pi/4}}]
```