# TableForm with TableHeadings aligned to Left but the content of table aligned to Right

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-frontend

`TableForm` with `TableHeadings` option is a quick and easy way to display good-looking classical table in *Mathematica* FrontEnd. The only problem is that it is common to display such a table with headings aligned to the left but the content of the table aligned to the right. Is it possible to force `TableForm` to behave in this way? Or if not, what is the best way to make an analog of `TableForm` that behaves in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that one way to do this is:

```
RawBoxes[ToBoxes[
   TableForm[RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {3, 3}], 
    TableHeadings -> {{"First left header", "Second left header", 
       "Trird left header"}, {"First top header", "Second top header",
        "Third top header"}}]] /. (ColumnAlignments -> _) -> 
   ColumnAlignments -> {Left, Right}]
```

One can make such behavior permanent using [Villegas-Gayley trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/5149656#5149656):

```
Unprotect[TableForm];
TableForm[args___] /; ! TrueQ@$inTableForm := 
 Block[{$inTableForm = True}, 
  RawBoxes[ToBoxes[TableForm[args]] /. (ColumnAlignments -> _) -> 
     ColumnAlignments -> {Left, Right}]]
Protect[TableForm];
```

Now

```
TableForm[RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {3, 3}], 
 TableHeadings -> {{"First left header", "Second left header", 
    "Third left header"}, {"First top header", "Second top header", 
    "Third top header"}}]
```

gives:

[image: Modified TableForm]

Another way is to define alternative function `myTableForm`:

```
myTableForm[args___] := 
 RawBoxes[ToBoxes[TableForm[args]] /. (ColumnAlignments -> _) -> 
    ColumnAlignments -> {Left, {Right}}]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Grid` and `Alignment`.  Here is one way:

```
a = Map[Mod[RandomInteger[2*^9], 10^#] &, RandomInteger[{1, 6}, {4, 7}], {2}];

b = Item[#, Alignment -> Left] & /@
      {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven"};

Grid[a~Prepend~b, Alignment -> Right]
```

Here is another:

```
headings = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven"};

Grid[a ~Prepend~ headings,
     Dividers -> {None, {2 -> True}}, 
     Alignment -> {Right, Automatic, {{1, 1}, {1, -1}} -> Left}
]
```

[image]

Comment: The main problem is with left table headings, not the top. It is just always takes too much time to think about `Transpose` and `Prepend`. So I need a easy-to use short function that will take (optionally) left and top table headings and construct classical table as `TableForm` does: `TableForm[{{5, 7}, {4, 26}, {100, 3}}, 
 TableHeadings -> {{"Group A", "Group B", "Group C"}, {"y1", "y2"}}]`. But with another alignment, of course.

Comment: It is worth to mention that `TableForm` is based on `GridBox` and we can see the "definition" of `TableForm` by evaluating: `FormatValues[TableForm] // InputForm`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get far more control using Grid or GridBox if TableForm doesn't do what you like.