# How to align first column and first row in Grid independently from others?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-frontend

How to specify separate alignments for the first column (excluding first row in this column), first row (excluding first element in this row) and all other elements in the `Grid`? It is preferable to do this just with `Alignment` option of `Grid` preserving tight control given by `Item[]` with `Alignment` option for more tight purposes.

P.S. This question comes from [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242080/tableform-with-tableheadings-aligned-to-left-but-the-content-of-table-aligned-to) but I wish to get individual control over alignments of horizontal and vertical table headings here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found several ways to achieve what I want. The most direct solution is:

```
Grid[Table[Row@(Range[a]), {a, 1, 4}, {7}], 
 Alignment -> {Right, 
   Automatic, {{{2, -1}, {1, 1}} -> Left, {{1, 1}, {2, -1}} -> 
     Center}}, Dividers -> {{2 -> True}, {2 -> True}}]
```

[image]

Other solutions include:

```
Grid[Table[Row@Range[a], {a, 1, 4}, {7}], 
 Alignment -> {{Left, {Right}}, 
   Automatic, {{1, 1}, {1, -1}} -> Center}, 
 Dividers -> {{2 -> True}, {2 -> True}}]
Grid[Table[Row@Range[a], {a, 1, 4}, {7}], 
 Alignment -> {Right, 
   Automatic, {1 -> Left, {{1, 1}, {2, -1}} -> Center}}, 
 Dividers -> {{2 -> True}, {2 -> True}}]
Grid[Table[Row@Range[a], {a, 1, 4}, {7}], 
 Alignment -> {Right, 
   Automatic, {1 -> Left, {{1, 1}, {1, -1}} -> Center}}, 
 Dividers -> {{2 -> True}, {2 -> True}}]
Grid[Table[Row@Range[a], {a, 1, 4}, {7}], 
 Alignment -> {Right, 
   Automatic, {{{1, 1}, {1, -1}} -> Center, 1 -> Left}}, 
 Dividers -> {{2 -> True}, {2 -> True}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Somehow I did not see this answer before I replied.  Nevertheless, I think I show a good general way to make specific alignments in a table.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `Alignment` uses the same syntax as the `Background` in `Grid` so it might help to look at `Options > Background` in the documentation for `Grid` for examples.

For example, suppose you want to align the item in the first row and first column top-right and all other items bottom-left, you could do something like

```
Grid[RandomInteger[10, {5, 5}], ItemSize -> {3, 3}, Frame -> All, 
 Alignment -> {Left, Bottom, {{1, 1} -> {Right, Top}}}]
```

[image: grid with different alignment for item {1,1}]

Comment: You have achieved something opposite to what is stated in the question: I need not to modify the alignment of the first element in the table but the alignment of all others elements in the first row and the first column.

Comment: @Alexey: Setting `{{1,1}->None}` instead of `{{1,1}->{Right, Top}` should work.

Comment: Again, it is not what I want. But just now I have solved the problem myself. Thank you in any case.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your requirements, I would favor doing this with `Item` as follows:

```
x = Array[\[HappySmiley] &, {5, 5}];

x = ReplacePart[x, 
      i : Except[{1, 1}, {_, 1} | {1, _}] :> 
        Item[x~Extract~i, Alignment -> Left]
    ];

Grid[x, ItemSize -> {3, 3}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for elegant use of `ReplacePart`. Another way is to use `Part`: `x[[2;;-1,1]]=Item[#,Alignment->Left]&/@x[[2;;-1,1]];x[[1,2;;-1]]=Item[#,Alignment->Center]&/@x[[1,2;;-1]];Grid[x,Alignment->Right]`.

Comment: Thanks.  In this case I prefer the `SparseArray` style index pattern that is possible with `ReplacePart`.

Comment: Your solution with `ReplacePart` is more appropriate than more obvious with `Part` since it does not require creation of temporary variable for storing of the original matrix.