# Creating Palette for switching .NB-associations between installed versions of Mathematica

Tags: windows, wolfram-mathematica, registry, file-association, mathematica-frontend

I would like to create a palette for switching .NB-file associations between installed versions of *Mathematica* under Windows.

At this moment I have developed the following code for enumerating installed versions of *Mathematica* and switching between them:

1) Getting list of names of system registry keys of installed versions of *Mathematica*:

```
installedVersions = 
 Select[Developer`EnumerateRegistrySubkeys["HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT"], 
  StringMatchQ[#, "Mathematica.NB." ~~ ___] || # === 
     "MathematicaNB" &]

=> {"Mathematica.NB.7.0.1.1213965", "MathematicaNB"}
```

2) Function that adds [command line options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/5771946#5771946) `-b` (disables the splash screen) and `-directlaunch` (disables the mechanism which launches the most recent *Mathematica* version installed) to the command line string for launching *Mathematica* FrontEnd in the system registry:

```
customizeOpenCommand[id_String] := Module[{value},
   value = 
    Cases[Developer`ReadRegistryKeyValues[
      "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\" ~~ id ~~ "\\shell\\open\\command"], 
     Verbatim[Rule][Null, 
       val_String /; 
        StringFreeQ[val, " -b -directlaunch "]] :> (Null -> 
        StringReplace[val, 
         path__ ~~ "\\Mathematica.exe\"" ~~ __ ~~ "\"%1\"" :> 
          path ~~ "\\Mathematica.exe\" -b -directlaunch \"%1\""])];
   Developer`WriteRegistryKeyValues[
    "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\" ~~ id ~~ "\\shell\\open\\command", value]];
```

This function can be used as follows:

```
customizeOpenCommand /@ installedVersions
```

3) Function for getting current .NB-file association:

```
Null /. Developer`ReadRegistryKeyValues["HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\.nb"]
```

4) Buttons for switching between all *Mathematica* versions installed (but I think it probably could be implemented better using `Dynamic` and `SetterBar`):

```
Column[Button[
    Row[{"Associate .NB-files with ", Style[#, Bold], " (", 
      First@Cases[
        Developer`ReadRegistryKeyValues["HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\" ~~ #], 
        Verbatim[Rule][Null, str_String] :> str], ")"}], 
    Developer`WriteRegistryKeyValues["HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\.nb", 
     Null -> #], Alignment -> Left] & /@ installedVersions]
```

In addition to the above here is the command which disables sharing of preferences between different *Mathematica* versions installed (by default all installed versions use one file for storing the FrontEnd settings):

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, "VersionedPreferences" -> True]
```

So my problem is:

How to create and install a small `Palette` which will dynamically display the current file associations for .NB-files and will allow to switch between them by clicking a button? I think it probably can be implemented just with `SetterBar` but I still unexperienced with `Dynamic` and palette creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to this moment I have come to the following solution:

```
CreatePalette@
  Framed[DynamicModule[{b, installedVersions}, 
    Dynamic[Column[
      Join[{Style["Associate .NB-files with:", Bold], 
        SetterBar[
         Dynamic[val, 
          Function[{v, e}, 
           Developer`WriteRegistryKeyValues["HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\.nb", 
            Null -> v]; 
           e = Null /. 
             Developer`ReadRegistryKeyValues[
              "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\.nb"], HoldRest], 
          Initialization -> (installedVersions = 
             Select[Developer`EnumerateRegistrySubkeys[
               "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT"], 
              StringMatchQ[#, "Mathematica.NB." ~~ ___] || # === 
                 "MathematicaNB" &]; 
            If[StringFreeQ[
                value = 
                 Null /. 
                  Developer`ReadRegistryKeyValues[
                   "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\" ~~ # ~~ 
                    "\\shell\\open\\command"], " -b -directlaunch "], 
               Developer`WriteRegistryKeyValues[
                "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\" ~~ # ~~ 
                 "\\shell\\open\\command", 
                Null -> 
                 StringReplace[value, 
                  path__ ~~ "\\Mathematica.exe\"" ~~ __ ~~ "\"%1\"" :>
                    path ~~ 
                    "\\Mathematica.exe\" -b -directlaunch \"%1\""]]] \
& /@ installedVersions)], installedVersions, 
         Appearance -> "Vertical"]}, 
       If[Last@Last@Options[$FrontEnd, "VersionedPreferences"] === 
          False && 
         b == True, {Button[
          Pane[Style[
            "This FrontEnd uses shared preferences file. Press this \
button to set FrontEnd to use versioned preferences file (all the \
FrontEnd settings will be reset to defaults).", Red], 300], 
          AbortProtect[
           SetOptions[$FrontEnd, "VersionedPreferences" -> True]; 
           b = False]]}, {}]], Alignment -> Center], 
     Initialization :> 
      If[! Last@Last@Options[$FrontEnd, "VersionedPreferences"], 
       b = True, b = False]]], FrameMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 5}}, 
   FrameStyle -> None];
```

This palette can be installed permanently using "Install Palette..." menu item in "Palette" menu.

Here is how it looks:

[image: screenshot1] [image: screenshot2]

Any suggestions and improvements are welcome!

---

Since all installed versions of *Mathematica* share the same `$BaseDirectory` and `$UserBaseDirectory`, it is recommended to install this palette in the oldest version installed to avoid standard warning popup:

> This notebook was created in a more recent version of Mathematica, and
>   may not function properly with the older front end you are using.
>   Contact Wolfram Research (www.wolfram.com) for upgrade information.