# How to disable case sensitivity in Mathematica functions?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, case

I want to make mathematica insensitive to the functions first capital letter. For example, it accepts both "Plot" and "plot" as plotting function.

Comment: for a specific example you can just do `plot=Plot`.  To do it in general I suspect the answer is "you don't want to do that", but you should ask on mathematica.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with [george](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1004168/george)'s sentiment: "You don't want to do that."  It is common practice to start user Symbols with lowercase letters which both identifies them and prevents collisions with built-ins.  Nevertheless you can do this in several ways.  One is just to create aliases as george also suggested, e.g.

```
plot = Plot;
sin = Sin;

plot[sin[x], {x, 0, 6}]
```

This has the advantage of working even in packages because it does not rely on the Front End.   However, because these are [not true aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7912984/618728) it will fail in some cases, e.g.:

```
evaluate = Evaluate;
Hold[evaluate[2 + 2]]
```

> ```
> Hold[evaluate[2 + 2]]
> ```

Whereas the "real" function behaves like this:

```
Hold[Evaluate[2 + 2]]
```

> ```
> Hold[4]
> ```

To get complete equivalence, though only in the Front End, you can use `$PreRead`. ([Example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/117/121).)  You will need to build a list of rules that replace the string form of each lowercase Symbol with the uppercase string.  I shall do that only for all Symbols in the `` System` `` context.

```
With[{rules = Thread[ToLowerCase[#] -> #] & @ Names["System`*"]},
  $PreRead = # /. rules &
];
```

Now both of these examples work:

```
plot[sin[x], {x, 0, 6}]

hold[evaluate[2 + 2], 3 + 4]
```

The latter producing:

> ```
> Hold[4, 3 + 4]
> ```

Answer (score 4):

This is not a direct answer to your question and I strongly advise you against redefining *Mathematica* functions just for the sake of the letter-case.

Nevertheless, have you seen that there is an option *Match case in command completion* when you go to *Edit* -> *Preferences* -> *Interface*?

[image]

If you turn this off, then you can type `plot` in the notebook and you get the correct `Plot` as suggestion from the autocompletion. You only have to hit enter and the correct command is inserted.