# Defining a function with an optional value that is by default a function of another paramether of the function in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to define a function that takes in a Matrix and when its dimensions are not provided as input, compute these dimensions in the optional parameter `d`

This does not work but gives you the idea (The options parameter need be constants):

```
Options[DimM] = {d -> Dimensions[A]};
DimM[A_?MatrixQ, OptionsPattern[]] := OptionValue@d;
```

Indeed the simple way is to input an impossible value and in the function def put an if condition as in

```
Options[DimM] = {d -> 0};
DimM[A_?MatrixQ, OptionsPattern[]] :=If[OptionValue@d==0,Dimensions[A],OptionValue@d]
```

How can I accomplish this most efficiently?

Answer (score 9):

For your original formulation, @WReach gave a fine answer. However, it may make sense to reconsider your design a bit: note that you  have a (dependent on input arguments) value for `d` *in any case*. Optional arguments are designed exactly for that - to be *optional*. In your case, a default argument seems more appropriate. You can set it up with `Automatic`, similarly to what @WReach suggested:

```
dimMAuto[a_?MatrixQ, d_: Automatic] :=
     If[d === Automatic, Dimensions[a], d];
```

To use this in more than one place in your code, you will however need to introduce an auxiliary variable or constant (using `With` or `Module`), to store this value. As an alternative, you can also use the following code:

```
Module[{dims},
  dimM[a_?MatrixQ, d_: dims] :=
      Block[{dims = Dimensions[a]}, 
          d]
]
```

which has the advantage that you can use the same original parameter `d` everywhere in the body of your function. What happens here is rather non-trivial: `Module` is used to generate a unique symbol, which is then given as a default for `d` and used to dynamically compute the dimensions. Note that `Block` localizes not the symbol `dims`, but the unique symbol like `dims$77542` produced by `Module`. This combination of `Module` and `Block` makes this technique completely safe. Examples of use:

```
In[1466]:= dimM[IdentityMatrix[3],{1,1}]
Out[1466]= {1,1}

In[1467]:= dimM[IdentityMatrix[3]]
Out[1467]= {3,3}
```

I think this combination of `Module` and `Block` is an interesting technique which may find other uses. Essentially, it is a version of dynamic scoping made safe by lexical scoping (or, more precisely, its imitation in Mathematica) - since one of the main dangers of dynamic scoping is inadvertent collisions of dynamically localized symbols with the same name.

On an unrelated matter - it is best to not start your variables and functions with a capital letter, since they may collide with the system symbols.

Comment: This is quite deep! my only concern here is efficiency. It seems the Module/Block combination computes Dimensions[a] whether or not a value for d is supplied which is precisely what I am trying not to do. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Phil Yes, you are right. In the case of `Dimensions`, overhead is probably not very significant, but if this is just a toy example for you, I see your point. You may make it compute the function conditionally at the price of making code a bit uglier: `Module[{dims},dimM[a_?MatrixQ, d_: dims] := Block[{dims}, If[d===dims,dims =  Dimensions[a]]; function-body]]`. Perhaps, this destroys a purpose a bit, but you still have the advantage of using the original parameter `d` everywhere in the body. You can also write a macro to abstract away the `Module`-`Block` part.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the use of `Block` within `Module` value is to create a dynamic default via a local, unique var which can acquire its value as needed. Clever. +1.

Comment: @rcollyer Yes, that's the idea. Just using `Block[{dims},...` is dangerous because in principle the body of the function may use the same global symbol `dims` for some unrelated purpose, in the chain of function calls resulting from evaluation of the body (with `dims` not necessarily lexically present in the body). This is a major problem with dynamic scoping. But, by using `Module`, we ensure that the dynamically - scoped symbol in question is unique and can not possibly collide with other symbols. AFAICT, this variation of dynamic scoping is much safer. I used it a few times before.

Comment: Yet another interesting dissertation, Leonid. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I was sure you'd like this one when you see it :). Thanks for the upvote.

Answer (score 5):

This is not really an improvement over your "simple way", but for many built-in Mathematica functions the symbol `Automatic` is used as the "impossible value".  For example:

```
Options[DimM] = {d -> Automatic};
DimM[A_?MatrixQ, OptionsPattern[]] := OptionValue[d] /. Automatic->Dimensions[A]

DimM[RandomInteger[10, {2, 2}]]
(* {2, 2} *)

DimM[RandomInteger[10, {2, 2}], d -> {5, 5}]
(* {5, 5} *)
```

Comment: thanks. How about if I have more than one optional parameter? how do I name them all?

Comment: You can use `Automatic` for all of them.  Then, inside the function you reference each option in turn thus:`a = OptionValue[A] /. Automatic -> defaultA; b = OptionValue[B] /. Automatic -> defaultB`.

Comment: Right, right! Do we still compute Dimensions[A] if a value for d is provided? I think not, since if Automatic is not found in OptionValue[d], then the replacement rule is not activated. Am I missing it? My goal is to avoid computing Dimensions[A] if in the context I already know it and can pass it on.

Comment: @Phil As written, the solution does compute `Dimensions` in any case. To avoid computing `Dimensions` in this approach, you can simply use delayed rules: `Automatic :> defaultA`, etc.

Comment: You are correct that the replacement rule will not be activated if the option value is anything other than `Automatic`.  However, as I have written it, `Dimensions[A]` will always be evaluated.  To avoid this calculation when unnecessary, the replacement rule would have to be written as a deferred rule, i.e. `Automatic :> Dimensions[A]`.