# How do I get interdependent options?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, optional-parameters, optional-values

I want to do something like

```
foo[OptionsPattern[]] := OptionValue[b]
Options[foo] = {a -> 0, b :> OptionValue[a]};
foo[a -> 1]
```

and have Mathematica give me `1`, instead of `0`.  Is there a better way to do this than

```
foo[OptionsPattern[]] := (
  Options[foo] = {a -> 0, b :> OptionValue[a]};
  OptionValue[b]
)
foo[a -> 1]
```

?

For one thing, it's inefficient to set the options of `foo` on every call, especially if `foo` has many options.

Comment: duplicate question: [Defining a function with an optional value that is by default a function of another paramether of the function in mathematica](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7394113/211232)

Answer (score 8):

This is why we have `Automatic`.  I'd use something like:

```
Options[foo] = {a -> 0, b -> Automatic};

foo[OptionsPattern[]] := 
            Block[{a, b},
               {a, b} = OptionValue[{a, b}];
               If[b === Automatic, a, b]
               ]

foo[]
(* --> 0 *)

foo[a -> 1]
(* --> 1 *)

foo[a -> 1, b -> 2]
(* --> 2 *)
```

Plus this allows for more complicated interpretation of automatic values if you need it.

Answer (score 4):

You wrote:

> I want to do something like
>
> ```
> foo[OptionsPattern[]] := OptionValue[b]
> Options[foo] = {a -> 0, b :> OptionValue[a]};
> foo[a -> 1]
> ```
>
> and have Mathematica give me `1`, instead of `0`.

I get `OptionValue[a]` as a return for this, not `1` OR `0`.  This is because `OptionValue` is to be matched with `OptionsPattern[]` and it is not.  Consider:

```
ClearAll[foo, a, b]
Options[foo] = {a -> 0};
foo[___] := OptionValue[a]

foo[it, doesnt, matter]
```

```
(* Out[]= OptionValue[a] *)
```

Here is one possible method to effect your goal.  I name the `OptionsPattern[]` so that I can work with these rules outside of OptionValue.  Notice that I can still specify an explicit value for `b`.

```
ClearAll[foo, a, b]
Options[foo] = {a -> 0, b -> a};
foo[opts : OptionsPattern[]] := OptionValue[b] /. {opts}

foo[a -> 1]
foo[a -> 3, b -> 7]
```

```
1
```

```
7
```