# Use of Dynamic to monitor progress within functions

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am interested in monitoring the progress of a computation using Dynamic. This can be done interactively as follows:

```
In[3]:= Dynamic[iter]

In[4]:= Table[{iter, iter^2}, {iter, 1, 500000}];
```

However, if the Table is within a function such as

```
f[m_] := Module[{iter}, Table[{iter, iter^2}, {iter, 1, m}]];
```

how can I keep track of the value of iter, when I execute the function via

```
f[500000];
```

?

Comment: `Table` already scopes `iter`, so in this case I don't see a need to include it in the first argument of `Module`.  This might not apply in more complicated functions, in which case you might consider using `Block` instead of `Module`.

Comment: @Brett It is a bit more subtle I think, although I can't come up with an example of constructive use of it in this given case. `Table` scopes dynamically, but it scopes not `iter` - it scopes an already `Module`-generated symbol like `iter$123` (can be seen e.g. with `Trace`). In the case of `Block`, there are constructive uses for combinations like `Module[{sym},Block[{sym},...]]`, for example as in this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394113/defining-a-function-with-an-optional-value-that-is-by-default-a-function-of-anot/7394668#7394668

Comment: @Leonid Yes, I know that in the code above the `iter` in the `Table` is really `iter$123`, which makes it tricky to refer to it from outside the `Module`.  My point is that, in this particular case, including  `iter` as a `Module` variable is unnecessary, and in fact makes things harder than they need to be.

Comment: @Brett I agree. But I can think of a (somewhat contrived) example where `Module` can serve to protect the inner `iter` from name collisions possible with the dynamic scoping: define `ff[] := iter^3`, and then contrast this: `Block[{iter = 2},  Module[{iter}, Table[{iter, iter^2, ff[]}, {iter, 1, 5}]]]`, with this: `Block[{iter = 2}, Table[{iter, iter^2, ff[]}, {iter, 1, 5}]]`. Not that I meet this in my day to day work, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure it is a good advice, but:

```
f[m_] := 
Module[{iter}, getIter[] := iter; 
    Table[{iter, iter^2}, {iter, 1, m}]];
```

And then:

```
Dynamic[getIter[]]

f[500000];
```

*EDIT*

This will be better but somewhat more obscure:

```
ClearAll[f];
SetAttributes[f, HoldRest];
f[m_, monitorSymbol_: monitor] :=
   Block[{monitorSymbol},
     Module[{iter}, 
         monitorSymbol := iter; 
         Table[{iter, iter^2}, {iter, 1, m}]]
   ];
```

Here, you designate a certain symbol to monitor the state of your localized variable. By using `Block`, you ensure that your symbol does not obtain any global value at the end (more precisely, that its global value is not changed at the end - you may as well use a symbol that has some global value, if you so desire). The default symbol is `monitor`, but you can change it. Here is how you use it:

```
Dynamic[monitor]

f[500000];
```

This is a somewhat better suggestion than the first simpler one, since by using `Block` you guarantee that no global state modifications happen after the function finishes.

Comment: The following also works, f[m_] :=
 Module[{iter}, getIter = iter;
  Table[{iter, iter^2}, {iter, 1, m}]]. Which one is preferable?

Comment: @asim Between these two, it is largely a matter of style. I prefer the one with `getIter[]`, but this is just a personal preference. But see my edit for what I think is a generally better solution.

Comment: Thanks! That looks sophisticated.

Comment: @asim This allows you to specify the name of the monitoring symbol, as a second parameter of your function's call, plus guarantees the absence of global side-effects, as explained in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `ProgressIndicator`, you can do something like this:

```
(*version 1.0*)
Manipulate[

 msg = "busy...";
 result = process[Unevaluated@progressCounter, max];
 msg = "done!";
 result,


 Dynamic@Grid[{
    {ProgressIndicator[progressCounter, {0, 100}, 
      ImageSize -> {105, 23}, ImageMargins -> 0, 
      BaselinePosition -> Bottom],
     Spacer[5],
     progressCounter, " %"},
    {msg}
    }
   ],


 {{max, 100, "maximum"}, 10, 10000, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled", 
  ContinuousAction -> False},

 {{progressCounter, 0}, None},
 {{result, 0}, None},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> {max},

 Initialization :>
  (

   process[c_, max_] := Module[{i, tbl},
     c = 0.;
     tbl = Table[0, {max}];

     Do[
      tbl[[i]] = {i, i^2};
      Pause[0.00001];
      c = i/max*100.,
      {i, 1, max}
      ];
     c = 0.;
     tbl[[-1]]
     ]
   )
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To monitor an expression you could try using `Monitor`:

```
Monitor[
 t = Table[{i, i^2}, {i, 500000}];
 Last[t]
 ,
 i
]
```

Additionally you can use `ProgressIndicator` with the range on `i`:

```
Monitor[
 t = Table[{i, i^2}, {i, 500000}];
 Last[t]
 ,
 ProgressIndicator[i, {1, 500000}]
]
```