# How to redirect Mathematica printing and error printing to files?

Tags: printing, wolfram-mathematica

How to redirect Mathematica printing and error printing to files?

Sometimes, a Mathematica program

- 1) uses `Print[]` to print messages,
- 2) sometimes, there is side-effect type of printing by some functions without any explicit `Print[]`
- 3) and sometimes there is error printing.

How to redirect the above three varieties of printing to (separate) text files, so they can be archived (separately) when the Mathematica kernel is closed?

Comment: Can you give an example of point 2?  I am not aware of this.

Comment: I am probably wrong about that there exist the type 2.  In Mathematica 8 there is no longer such printing.  In some earlier versions, it did, IIRC.

Comment: Related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7741432/198315).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Print[]` by default outputs to the stream `$Output`.  Messages go to the `$Messages` stream.  You can redefine these two global variables to redirect the output to a file:

```
stream = OpenWrite["out.txt", FormatType -> OutputForm]
$Output = {stream}
```

Comment: -1 for making me [look like an ass](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1118/121). ;-p

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You see now why I avoid asking questions (you asked me about it once) :)? I upvoted this one, b.t.w.

Comment: To save a bit of face, I must state that I *did* test the code I included and it worked correctly for the simple scenario I used.

Comment: @Leonid lol -- honestly I wish you would reconsider; you are well respected and I doubt a foolish question would change that. Furthermore I am sure you could ask some really interesting, insightful questions if you chose.

Comment: @Szabolcs what's really annoying is that I did not try to solve the problem on my own first, but thought: "oh, here's a good post for mma.SE!"  -- I've started a question in Meta relating to this.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Well, seriously, I was burnt enough with this when doing Physics. I did Astrophysics as undergrad, then switched to Quantum Optics, then Quantum Field Theory and finally Mathematical Physics - and everywhere I did not dig deep enough (I mean, for my taste. I co-authored papers etc, but too many gaps where I relied on some knowledge without carefully testing it. I could easily stay in Physics, get another postdoc etc). With M (which was a hobby), I started from scratch, and did it right. I wish I had this attitude when starting with Physics. Perhaps, I am overdoing it, but so be it.

Comment: @Leonid whatever you're doing appears to be working quite well.  Keep at it.