# Contingency Table in Mathematica

Tags: count, wolfram-mathematica, contingency

Trying to build what I believe to be a contingency table, please consider the following :

```
dist = Parallelize[Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]], {100000}]];

dist2 = Rest@FoldList[0.95 # + #2 &, 0, dist];

dist3 = Rest@FoldList[0.95 # + Abs[#2] &, 0, dist];

dist4 = {dist2, dist3}\[Transpose]

q1 = Flatten[{Quantile[dist2, {1/3, 2/3}], Quantile[dist3, {1/3, 2/3}]}]

{-1.39001, 1.33851, 15.0327, 16.6757}
```

[image]

What I need to do : For each element of dist4 I need to see with of the 9 box below it belongs to :

```
for example : {1.55191, 15.7189} belongs to 2   
                            1.55 belongs to 1 and 
                           15.71 belongs to 8  
So the intersection is 2.
```

I have tried If, or Switch but it is to long to write. Is there an automatic way to do this ?

Comment: By the way, if you adopt [my `Fold` and `FoldList` modification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/5433867#5433867), you can write:  `dist2 = FoldList[0.95 # + #2 &, dist];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question, I think this does it:

```
{a, b, c, d} = q1;
tbl = Range@9 ~Partition~ 3;

f[{x_, y_}] := tbl[[
  Which[x > b, 1, x > a, 2, x <= a, 3],
  Which[y < c, 1, y < d, 2, y >= d, 3]
  ]]

f /@ dist4 // Short
```

Answer (score 2):

```
y[t_] := Piecewise[{{7, t <  q1[[1]]}, {4, t <= q1[[2]]}}, 1];
x[t_] := Piecewise[{{0, t <  q1[[3]]}, {1, t <= q1[[4]]}}, 2];
{{##}, x[#1] + y[#2]} & @@@ dist4
```

Or perhaps using `BinLists`!:

```
k = BinLists[dist4,
   {Join[{Min[dist4[[All, 1]]]}, q1[[1 ;; 2]], {Max[dist4[[All, 1]]]}]},
   {Join[{Min[dist4[[All, 2]]]}, q1[[3 ;; 4]], {Max[dist4[[All, 2]]]}]}
   ];

Flatten[Replace[
        Flatten[MapIndexed[{#1, #2} &, k, {2}], 1], {{x__}, t_} :>
           (Join[{#}, {9 - 3 First@t + Last@t}] & /@ {x}), {1}], 1]
```

Comment: PS: do I get a time adjustment for doing this on a sleepy Sunday morning? I'm still drinking my coffee.

Comment: @Verbeia  No, you don't get any adjustment since it's still late Saturday evening here, and I won't even see the question for 12 more hours. ;-)

Comment: belisarius, why do you have `SlotSequence` in your first code block?

Comment: I think you know I know that.  I was trying to hint that you'd mixed methods.  Anyway, whether you change `/@` to `@@@` or `##` to `#` I think the forms should agree.

Comment: @Mr. I think you know I think you know that. I don't know why you feel it's wrong, but be my guest and correct it if it is so.

Comment: he he he... I think.. Ah nevermind. ;-)  I just find the construct `(*stuff*) ## (*stuff*) & /@ (*stuff*)` confusing.  The presence of `##` suggests that there is the possibility of more than one argument, and yet `Map` doesn't provide for that.  Honestly, what do you think?

Comment: @Mr. Probably I don't get confused because I usually read prefix expressions from right to left, so I know what the arguments are in advance.

Comment: Interesting.  So you read most lines of Mathematica code in reverse; is that correct?  Still, in this case is there any reason not to change your answer?  If you don't have any objection, I will.

Comment: @Mr. No only I read the lines in reverse, I also write (and think) them right  to left when I design code bottom-up. I go the other way only with more difficult tasks that deserve top down design. And yes, please edit the answer if you think it is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a step function?
Depending on whether you want the output to be {3,2} in the case of slot 8, or actually the number 8, the implementation might differ.

```
g1[x_] := 
 Piecewise[{{1, x > 1.33851}, {2, 1.33851 >= x > -1.39001}, 3}]

g2[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, x < 15.0327}, {2, 15.0327 <= x < 16.6757}}, 3]

slotfn[{a_, b_}] := {g2[b], g1[a]}

slotnumber[{a_, b_}] := 3 g2[b] + g1[a]
```

If belisarius's implementation really is the same, I'll delete. I'll note that my non-functional no-# version ensures that you're only passing two arguments to either `slotfn` or `slotnumber`.

Answer (score 1):

With a separate limits specification:

```
limits =
  {
   {.1, .15, .5, \[Infinity]},
   {1, 2, 3, \[Infinity]}
   };

cell[l_List] :=
 Table[
  Position[
    limits[[i]], _?(# > l[[i]] &), 1, 1
    ][[1, 1]], {i, 1, Length@l}]
```

`cell[{.4, 1.5}]` will then yield `{3, 2}`. You can convert with:

```
(cell[{.4, 1.5}] - {0, 1})*{1, Length[limits[[1]]]} // Plus @@ # &
```

which yields `7`.