# How to test if a list contains consecutive integers in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to test if a list contains consecutive integers.

```
 consQ[a_] := Module[
  {ret = True}, 
  Do[If[i > 1 && a[[i]] != a[[i - 1]] + 1, ret = False; Break[]], {i, 
  1, Length[a]}]; ret]
```

Although the function consQ does the job, I wonder if there is a better ( shorter, faster ) method of doing this, preferably using functional programming style.

**EDIT:**
The function above maps lists with consecutive integers in decreasing sequence to False. I would like to change this to True.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use

```
consQ[a_List ? (VectorQ[#, IntegerQ]&)] := Union@Differences[a] === {1}
consQ[_] = False
```

You may want to remove the test for integers if you know that every list you pass to it will only have integers.

**EDIT:**  A little extra: if you use a very old version that doesn't have `Differences`, or wonder how to implement it,

```
differences[a_List] := Rest[a] - Most[a]
```

**EDIT 2:** The requested change:

```
consQ[a : {Integer___}] := MatchQ[Union@Differences[a], {1} | {-1} | {}]
consQ[_] = False
```

This works with both increasing and decreasing sequences, and gives `True` for a list of size 1 or 0 as well.

More generally, you can test if the list of numbers are equally spaced with something like `equallySpacedQ[a_List] := Length@Union@Differences[a] == 1`

Comment: Since you're testing that the set of difference is *exactly* `{1}`, it's sufficient to check that the list contains one integer, instead of checking all of them.

Comment: Or without the integrity-constraints : consQ[a_] := Union@Differences[a] === {1}. Cool. It's hard to choose between your solution and the one by Champion. - ( I was not aware Mathematica had the Differences function. )

Comment: Please have a look at EDIT: and further in question. How would you modify your consQ?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. @Szabolcs - I like your answer for its readability, compactness and functional style, even though technically it might not be the fastest. - The variety in solutions show the power of Mathematica.

Answer (score 11):

Szablics' solution is probably what I'd do, but here's an alternative:

```
consQ[a : {___Integer}] := Most[a] + 1 === Rest[a]
consQ[_] := False
```

Note that these approaches differ in how they handle the empty list.

Comment: and also the list of size 1.  I like yours better.

Comment: Fast, functional and compact. :-) But cryptic ( to me ), where Union@Differences is close to self-documenting. - It's hard to decide which one is the best! - Both leave my 'solution' far behind performance-wise.

Comment: But easily broken down.  Set `a = {1,2,3,4,5}` and go from there.

Comment: Please have a look at EDIT: and further in question. How would you modify your consQ?

Comment: @nilo, you can follow belisarius' lead and use `Sign`:  `Most[a] + Sign[a[[2]]-a[[1]]] === Rest[a]`

Comment: @Mr. Do you mean `Sign[-#[[1]] + #[[2]]]] &@{a[[1]], a[[-1]]}` ?

Comment: @belisarius `Sign[{-1,1}.a[[{1,-1}]]]`

Answer (score 8):

I like the solutions by the other two, but I'd be concerned about very long lists.  Consider the data

```
d:dat[n_Integer?Positive]:= d = {1}~Join~Range[1, n]
```

which has its non-sequential point at the very beginning.  Setting `consQ1` for Brett's and `consQ2` for Szabolcs, I get

```
AbsoluteTiming[ #[dat[ 10000 ] ]& /@ {consQ1, consQ2}
{ {0.000110, False}, {0.001091, False} }
```

Or, roughly a ten times difference between the two, which stays relatively consistent with multiple trials.  This time can be cut in roughly half by short-circuiting the process using [`NestWhile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NestWhile.html):

```
Clear[consQ3]
consQ3[a : {__Integer}] := 
 Module[{l = Length[a], i = 1},
   NestWhile[# + 1 &, i, 
      (#2 <= l) && a[[#1]] + 1 == a[[#2]] &, 
   2] > l
 ]
```

which tests each pair and only continues if they return true.  The timings

```
AbsoluteTiming[consQ3[dat[ 10000 ]]]
{0.000059, False}
```

with

```
{0.000076, False}
```

for `consQ`.  So, Brett's answer is fairly close, but occasionally, it will take twice as long.

**Edit**: I moved the graphs of the timing data to a [Community Wiki answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931716/how-to-test-if-a-list-contains-consecutive-integers-in-mathematica/7940367#7940367).

Comment: I am not a timing expert but isn't Timing the function to choose when comparing sec algorithm speeds? - I ask because I get different results when using Timing instead of AbsoluteTiming. - I am interested which solution uses the fastest algorithm.

Comment: @niloderoock, I added timing data, using `Timing` to my answer.

Comment: @belisarius, absolutely. Give me a couple of hours.

Comment: @belisarius, so do I, see my [wiki answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931716/how-to-test-if-a-list-contains-consecutive-integers-in-mathematica/7940367#7940367).

Answer (score 8):

I think the following is also fast, and comparing reversed lists does not take longer:

```
a = Range[10^7];
f[a_] := Range[Sequence @@ ##, Sign[-#[[1]] + #[[2]]]] &@{a[[1]], a[[-1]]} == a;
Timing[f[a]]
b = Reverse@a;
Timing[f[b]]
```

**Edit**

A short test for the fastests solutions so far:

```
a = Range[2 10^7];
Timing@consQSzab@a
Timing@consQBret@a
Timing@consQBeli@a
(*
{6.5,True}
{0.703,True}
{0.203,True}
*)
```

Comment: http://our-shed.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/kangaroo-kicks-kid-in-th.gif

Comment: @Mr. Watch your manners! Back kicking, laying giant eggs and  eating eucalyptus leaves is allowed only in www.stackoverflow.co.au

Answer (score 5):

`Fold` can be used in a fairly concise expression that runs very quickly:

```
consQFold[a_] := (Fold[If[#2 == #1 + 1, #2, Return[False]] &, a[[1]]-1, a]; True)
```

Pattern-matching can be used to provide a very clear expression of intent at the cost of substantially slower performance:

```
consQMatch[{___, i_, j_, ___}] /; j - i != 1 := False
consQMatch[_] = True;
```

**Edit**

`consQFold`, as written, works in Mathematica v8.0.4 but not in earlier versions of v8 or v7.  To correct this problem, there are a couple of alternatives.  The first is to explicitly name the `Return` point:

```
consQFold[a_] :=
  (Fold[If[#2==#1+1, #2, Return[False,CompoundExpression]] &, a[[1]]-1, a]; True)
```

The second, as suggested by @Mr.Wizard, is to replace `Return` with `Throw` / `Catch`:

```
consQFold[a_] :=
  Catch[Fold[If[#2 == #1 + 1, #2, Throw[False]]&, a[[1]]-1, a]; True]
```

Comment: this is what I thought of when I read the question, but don't you mean to use `Throw` rather than `Return`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard `Throw` would work as well, but it would require a corresponding `Catch`.  `Return` is therefore more concise as it exits the nearest enclosing construct (in this case, the definition of `consQFold`).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Aha!  I see the problem now.  `Return` appears to be broken in version 7 and version 8.0.1.  It is fixed again in version 8.0.4 (or broken, depending upon your viewpoint :).

Comment: How many constructs does `Return` work with in 8.0.4?  Oh, and of course, +1.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard There seems to be a lot of lore surrounding `Return` -- and few facts.  The official documentation is sparse.  For example, the two-argument form is [almost undocumented](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/message/Break/nofunc.html).  I've been surprised more than once by the documented behaviour: _If [the second argument] is omitted, the affected function or loop is determined using built-in heuristics_.  I suppose I should have known better than to rely on it and I had the (mis)fortune of trying out my code in the shiny new 8.0.4.

Answer (score 5):

I am now convinced that belisarius is trying to get my goat by writing intentionally convoluted code. :-p

I would write: `f = Range[##, Sign[#2 - #]]& @@ #[[{1, -1}]] == # &`

Also, I believe that WReach probably intended to write something like:

```
consQFold[a_] := 
 Catch[
  Fold[If[#2 === # + 1, #2, Throw@False] &, a[[1]] - 1, a]; 
  True
 ]
```

Comment: -14 for reverse engineering my copyrighted and obfuscated code

Comment: There's a wine for your [goat problem](http://www.bullyhill.com/wines/Downloads/Labels/Red/LoveMyGoat.jpg).

Answer (score 5):

Since the timing seems to be rather important. I've moved the comparisons between the various methods to this, Community Wiki, answer.

The data used are simply lists of consecutive integers, with a single non-consecutive point, and they're generated via

```
d : dat[n_Integer?Positive] := (d = {1}~Join~Range[1, n])
d : dat[n_Integer?Positive, p_Integer?Positive] /; p <= n := 
     Range[1, p]~Join~{p}~Join~Range[p + 1, n]
```

where the first form of `dat[n]` is equivalent to `dat[n, 1]`.  The timing code is simple:

```
Clear[consQTiming]
Options[consQTiming] = {
   NonConsecutivePoints -> {10, 25, 50, 100, 250,500, 1000}};
consQTiming[fcns__, OptionPattern[]]:=
With[{rnd = RandomInteger[{1, #}, 100]}, 
  With[{fcn = #}, 
     Timing[ fcn[dat[10000, #]] & /@ rnd ][[1]]/100
  ] & /@ {fcns}
] & /@ OptionValue[NonConsecutivePoints]
```

It generates 100 random integers between 1 and each of `{10, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500, 1000}` and `dat` then uses each of those random numbers as the non-consecutive point in a list 10,000 elements long.  Each `consQ` implementation is then applied to each list produced by `dat`, and the results are averaged. The plotting function is simply

```
Clear[PlotConsQTimings]
Options[PlotConsQTimings] = {
     NonConsecutivePoints -> {10, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500, 1000}};
PlotConsQTimings[timings : { _?VectorQ ..}, OptionPattern[]] :=
  ListLogLogPlot[
    Thread[{OptionValue[NonConsecutivePoints], #}] & /@ Transpose[timings],
    Frame -> True, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic
  ]
```

[image: timing data for various functions]

I timed the following functions [`consQSzabolcs1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931716/how-to-test-if-a-list-contains-consecutive-integers-in-mathematica/7931806#7931806), [`consQSzabolcs2`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931716/how-to-test-if-a-list-contains-consecutive-integers-in-mathematica/7931806#7931806), [`consQBrett`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931716/how-to-test-if-a-list-contains-consecutive-integers-in-mathematica/7931900#7931900), [`consQRCollyer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931716/how-to-test-if-a-list-contains-consecutive-integers-in-mathematica/7932165#7932165), [`consQBelisarius`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931716/how-to-test-if-a-list-contains-consecutive-integers-in-mathematica/7935644#7935644), [`consQWRFold`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931716/how-to-test-if-a-list-contains-consecutive-integers-in-mathematica/7934354#7934354), [`consQWRFold2`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931716/how-to-test-if-a-list-contains-consecutive-integers-in-mathematica/7934354#7934354), [`consQWRFold3`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931716/how-to-test-if-a-list-contains-consecutive-integers-in-mathematica/7934354#7934354), [`consQWRMatch`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931716/how-to-test-if-a-list-contains-consecutive-integers-in-mathematica/7934354#7934354), and [MrWizard's version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931716/how-to-test-if-a-list-contains-consecutive-integers-in-mathematica/7936368#7936368) of `consQBelisarius`.

In ascending order of the left most timing: `consQBelisarius`, `consQWizard`, `consQRCollyer`, `consQBrett`, `consQSzabolcs1`, `consQWRMatch`, `consQSzabolcs2`, `consQWRFold2`, `consQWRFold3`,and `consQWRFold`.

**Edit**: Reran all of the functions with [`timeAvg`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/4199042#4199042) (the second one) instead of `Timing` in `consQTiming`.  I did still average over 100 runs, though.  For the most part, there was any change, except for the lowest two where there is some variation from run to run.  So, take those two lines with a grain of salt as they're timings are practically identical.

[image]

Comment: @belisarius, pushed it out to allow random non-consecutive points out to 5000 and 10000, and updated picture.

Comment: @belisarius, the one right above yours, which dips below yours between 50 and 1000.

Comment: yes, but which _function_ is it? There are two functions in Mr's answer

Comment: @belisarius, I thought I made that clear in the text, apparently not. It's his version of your function, `f`. I didn't bother with the other one, since WReach applied that fix to `consQWRFold3`. So, I was quite surprised that there is any difference in the timing.

Comment: @rcollyer would you test belisarius' and my functions again, using `timeAvg` or similar?  I am curious to know if, on your system, the wobble seen on mine is real or an artifact.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, reran all the functions with `timeAvg`, and there is some variation for both yours and Belisarius' from run to run.

Comment: Thank you.  It appears to be simple variation, rather than one being faster than the other, which is what I expected.