# A "MapList" function

Tags: performance, dictionary, wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-7

In *Mathematica* there are a number of functions that return not only the final result or a single match, but all results.  Such functions are named `*List`.  Exhibit:

- FoldList
- NestList
- ReplaceList
- ComposeList

#### Something that I am missing is a MapList function.

For example, I want:

```
MapList[f, {1, 2, 3, 4}]
```

```
{{f[1], 2, 3, 4}, {1, f[2], 3, 4}, {1, 2, f[3], 4}, {1, 2, 3, f[4]}}
```

I want a list element for each application of the function:

```
MapList[
  f,
  {h[1, 2], {4, Sin[x]}},
  {2}
] // Column
```

```
{h[f[1], 2], {4, Sin[x]}}
{h[1, f[2]], {4, Sin[x]}}
{h[1, 2], {f[4], Sin[x]}}
{h[1, 2], {4, f[Sin[x]]}}
```

---

#### One may implement this as:

```
MapList[f_, expr_, level_: 1] :=
 MapAt[f, expr, #] & /@
  Position[expr, _, level, Heads -> False]
```

#### However, it is quite inefficient.  Consider this simple case, and compare these [timings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/4199042#4199042):

```
a = Range@1000;
#^2 & /@ a // timeAvg
MapList[#^2 &, a] // timeAvg
ConstantArray[#^2 & /@ a, 1000] // timeAvg

0.00005088

0.01436

0.0003744
```

This illustrates that on average `MapList` is about 38X slower than the combined total of mapping the function to every element in the list and creating a 1000x1000 array.

---

#### Therefore, how may MapList be most efficiently implemented?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect that `MapList` is nearing the performance limit for any transformation that performs structural modification.  The existing target benchmarks are not really fair comparisons.  The `Map` example is creating a simple vector of integers.  The `ConstantArray` example is creating a simple vector of shared references to the same list.  `MapList` shows poorly against these examples because it is creating a vector where each element is a freshly generated, unshared, data structure.

I have added two more benchmarks below.  In both cases each element of the result is a packed array.  The `Array` case generates new elements by performing `Listable` addition on `a`.  The `Module` case generates new elements by replacing a single value in a copy of `a`.  These results are as follows:

```
In[8]:= a = Range@1000;
        #^2 & /@ a // timeAvg
        MapList[#^2 &, a] // timeAvg
        ConstantArray[#^2 & /@ a, 1000] // timeAvg
        Array[a+# &, 1000] // timeAvg
        Module[{c}, Table[c = a; c[[i]] = c[[i]]^2; c, {i, 1000}]] // timeAvg

Out[9]=  0.0005504

Out[10]= 0.0966

Out[11]= 0.003624

Out[12]= 0.0156

Out[13]= 0.02308
```

Note how the new benchmarks perform much more like `MapList` and less like the `Map` or `ConstantArray` examples.  This seems to show that there is not much scope for dramatically improving the performance of `MapList` without some deep kernel magic.  We can shave a bit of time from `MapList` thus:

```
MapListWR4[f_, expr_, level_: {1}] :=
  Module[{positions, replacements}
  , positions = Position[expr, _, level, Heads -> False]
  ; replacements = # -> f[Extract[expr, #]] & /@ positions
  ; ReplacePart[expr, #] & /@ replacements
  ]
```

Which yields these timings:

```
In[15]:= a = Range@1000;
         #^2 & /@ a // timeAvg
         MapListWR4[#^2 &, a] // timeAvg
         ConstantArray[#^2 & /@ a, 1000] // timeAvg
         Array[a+# &, 1000] // timeAvg
         Module[{c}, Table[c = a; c[[i]] = c[[i]]^2; c, {i, 1000}]] // timeAvg

Out[16]= 0.0005488

Out[17]= 0.04056

Out[18]= 0.003

Out[19]= 0.015

Out[20]= 0.02372
```

This comes within factor 2 of the `Module` case and I expect that further micro-optimizations can close the gap yet more.  But it is with eager anticipation that I join you awaiting an answer that shows a further tenfold improvement.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard see my answer for another speed boost. I have a couple more ideas that I'll add to my post tonight if I get time.

Answer (score 6):

(*Updated my function*)

I think I can offer another 2x boost on top of WReach's attempt.

```
Remove[MapListTelefunken];
MapListTelefunken[f_, dims_] :=
 With[{a = Range[dims], fun = f[[1]]},
  With[{replace = ({#, #} -> fun) & /@ a},
   ReplacePart[ConstantArray[a, {dims}], replace]
   ]
  ]
```

Here are the timings on my machine (Sony Z laptop; i7, 8GB ram, 256 SSD in Raid 0):

```
a = Range@1000;
#^2 & /@ a; // timeAvg
MapList[#^2 &, a]; // timeAvg
MapListWR4[#^2 &, a]; // timeAvg
MapListTelefunken[#^2 &, 1000]; // timeAvg

0.0000296 (* just Mapping the function over a Range[1000] for baseline *)
0.0297 (* the original MapList proposed by Mr.Wizard *)
0.00936 (* MapListWR4 from WReach *)
0.00468 (* my attempt *)
```

Comment: The new function does not give the same results as the two use cases shown for `MapList` (even when `#^2` is changed to `f[#]` in the definition).

Comment: @WReach -- I see my error...was trying to make the function syntax the same as the others and forgot replace the #^2& (in the internal With) with the f_. I think the timings will still be valid. Will fix and update.

Comment: @belisarius - don't worry, the laptop comes with plenty of Sony crapware to slow it down.

Comment: @telef This week my Lenovo friendware alerted about the convenience of buying a new battery to prevent future failures ... three days after the old one died.

Comment: @belisarius - dude... i think lenovo is up to fishy stuff with their batteries. I had been an x41 and x61 tablet user prior to owning this machine and would have purchased again but i think lenovo has some way to make batteries 'play dead' via their battery software---which conveniently also refuses to charge 3rd market refurb batteries consistently (which is total b.s. because it's another company's battery inside their battery case to begin with).

Comment: Using `ReplacePart`, `ConstantArray`, and incorporating `Position` to handle other levelspecs, I still get an increase in efficiency.  Thank you.

Comment: Seems I spoke too soon.  With other structures what I wrote became slower, so the two methods are trading place with different data.  Still, this is an interesting method and I shall continue experimenting.

Answer (score 3):

I think you'd still need to create the 1000x1000 array, and I don't think there's any cleverer way than a constant array. More to the point, your examples are better served with the following definition, although I admit that it lacks the finesse of levels.

```
MapList[f_, list_] := (Table[MapAt[f, #, i], {i, Length@#}] &)@list;
```

The culprit in your own definition is the `Position[]` call, which creates a complex auxiliary structure.

Provide a more complex use case, that will better cover your intentions.

Comment: This is not what I want.  Please look at the second example in the question again.