# How would you do a PivotTable function in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

[PivotTables in Excel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table) (or, [cross tabulations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_tabulation)) are quite useful. Has anyone already thought about how to implement a similar function in Mathematica?

Comment: Aren't pivot tables a combination of filters and projections? Or are you thinking in the excel UI for pivot tables?

Comment: @rcollyer, SelectEquivalents in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/6245166#6245166 would probably be quite useful for this.

Comment: @belisarius, in fact I'm thinking at both but first at obtaining the right data (right being configurable!).

Comment: Agreed, probably useful. I'm not sure if I've done it, although I probably have. Also, I just added the more generic term, cross tabulation, to the post.

Comment: Ideally I would have accepted both you and Sjoerd as you two contributed to your solution; your answer provides an all in one solution that's why I accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am not familiar with the use of pivot tables, but taking the example on the page linked above, I propose this:

```
Needs["Calendar`"]
key = # -> #2[[1]] & ~MapIndexed~
       {"Region", "Gender", "Style", "Ship Date", "Units", "Price", "Cost"};
choices = {
   {"North", "South", "East", "West"},
   {"Boy", "Girl"},
   {"Tee", "Golf", "Fancy"},
   IntegerString[#, 10, 2] <> "/2011" & /@ Range@12,
   Range@15,
   Range[8.00, 15.00, 0.01],
   Range[6.00, 14.00, 0.01]
   };
data = RandomChoice[#, 150] & /@ choices // Transpose;
```

This creates `data` that looks like:

```
 {"East", "Girl", "Golf", "03/2011", 6, 12.29`, 6.18`},
 {"West", "Boy", "Fancy", "08/2011", 6, 13.01`, 12.39`},
 {"North", "Girl", "Golf", "05/2011", 1, 14.87`, 12.89`},
 {"East", "Girl", "Golf", "09/2011", 3, 13.99`, 6.25`},
 {"North", "Girl", "Golf", "09/2011", 13, 12.66`, 8.57`},
 {"East", "Boy", "Fancy", "10/2011", 2, 14.46`, 6.85`},
 {"South", "Boy", "Golf", "11/2011", 13, 12.45`, 11.23`}
 ...
```

Then:

```
h1 = Union@data[[All, "Region" /. key]];
h2 = Union@data[[All, "Ship Date" /. key]];

Reap[
   Sow[#[[{"Units", "Ship Date"} /. key]], #[["Region" /. key]]] & ~Scan~ data,
   h1,
   Reap[Sow @@@ #2, h2, Total @ #2 &][[2]] &
][[2]];

TableForm[Join @@ %, TableHeadings -> {h1, h2}]
```

[image]

This is a rough example, but it gives an idea of how this may be done.  If you have more specific requirements I will attempt to address them.

---

### Here is an update in the manner of Sjoerd's answer.

The `Manipulate` block is largely copied, but I believe my `pivotTableData` is more efficient, and I sought to localize symbols correctly, since this is now presented as usable code rather than a rough example.

I start with the same sample data, but I embed the field headings, since I feel this is more representative of normal use.

```
data = ImportString[#, "TSV"][[1]] & /@ Flatten[Import["http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/datasets/CPS_85_Wages"][[28 ;; -7]]];

data = Transpose[{
    data[[All, 1]], 
    data[[All, 2]] /. {1 -> "South", 0 -> "Elsewhere"}, 
    data[[All, 3]] /. {1 -> "Female", 0 -> "Male"},
    data[[All, 4]], 
    data[[All, 5]] /. {1 -> "Union Member", 0 -> "No member"}, 
    data[[All, 6]],
    data[[All, 7]], 
    data[[All, 8]] /. {1 -> "Other", 2 -> "Hispanic", 3 -> "White"}, 
    data[[All, 9]] /. {1 -> "Management", 2 -> "Sales", 3 -> "Clerical", 4 -> "Service", 5 -> "Professional", 6 -> "Other"}, 
    data[[All, 10]] /. {0 -> "Other", 1 -> "Manufacturing", 2 -> "Construction"}, 
    data[[All, 11]] /. {1 -> "Married", 0 -> "Unmarried"}
}];

PrependTo[data,
  {"Education", "South", "Sex", "Experience", "Union", "Wage", "Age", "Race", "Occupation", "Sector", "Marriatal status"}
  ];
```

My `pivotTableData` is self contained.

```
pivotTableData[data_, field1_, field2_, dependent_, op_] :=
  Module[{key, sow, h1, h2, ff},
    (key@# = #2[[1]]) & ~MapIndexed~ data[[1]];
    sow = #[[key /@ {dependent, field2}]] ~Sow~ #[[key@field1]] &;
    {h1, h2} = Union@data[[2 ;;, key@#]] & /@ {field1, field2};
    ff = # /. {{} -> Missing@"NotAvailable", _ :> op @@ #} &;
    {
     {h1, h2},
     Join @@ Reap[sow ~Scan~ Rest@data, h1, ff /@ Reap[Sow @@@ #2, h2][[2]] &][[2]]
    }
  ]
```

`pivotTable` relies only on `pivotTableData`:

```
pivotTable[data_?MatrixQ] :=
 DynamicModule[{raw, t, header = data[[1]], opList =
    {Mean              -> "Mean of \[Rule]",
     Total             -> "Sum of \[Rule]",
     Length            -> "Count of \[Rule]",
     StandardDeviation -> "SD of \[Rule]",
     Min               -> "Min of \[Rule]",
     Max               -> "Max of \[Rule]"}},
  Manipulate[
   raw = pivotTableData[data, f1, f2, f3, op];
   t = ConstantArray["", Length /@ raw[[1]] + 2];
   t[[1, 1]] = Control[{op, opList}];
   t[[1, 3]] = Control[{f2, header}];
   t[[2, 1]] = Control[{f1, header}];
   t[[1, 2]] = Control[{f3, header}];
   {{t[[3 ;; -1, 1]], t[[2, 3 ;; -1]]}, t[[3 ;; -1, 3 ;; -1]]} = raw;
   TableView[N@t, Dividers -> All],
   Initialization :> {op = Mean, f1 = data[[1,1]], f2 = data[[1,2]], f3 = data[[1,3]]}
  ]
 ]
```

Use is simply:

```
pivotTable[data]
```

Answer (score 10):

A quick-and-dirty pivot table visualization:

I'll start with a more interesting real-life data set:

```
data = ImportString[#, "TSV"][[1]] & /@ 
          Flatten[Import["http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/datasets/CPS_85_Wages"][[28 ;; -7]]
       ];
```

A bit of  post-processing:

```
data =
  {
    data[[All, 1]],
    data[[All, 2]] /. {1 -> "South", 0 -> "Elsewhere"},
    data[[All, 3]] /. {1 -> "Female", 0 -> "Male"},
    data[[All, 4]],
    data[[All, 5]] /. {1 -> "Union Member", 0 -> "No member"},
    data[[All, 6]],
    data[[All, 7]],
    data[[All, 8]] /. {1 -> "Other", 2 -> "Hispanic", 3 -> "White"},
    data[[All, 9]] /. {1 -> "Management", 2 -> "Sales", 3 -> "Clerical", 
                      4 -> "Service", 5 -> "Professional", 6 -> "Other"},
    data[[All, 10]] /. {0 -> "Other", 1 -> "Manufacturing", 2 -> "Construction"},
    data[[All, 11]] /. {1 -> "Married", 0 -> "Unmarried"}
  }\[Transpose];

header = {"Education", "South", "Sex", "Experience", "Union", "Wage", 
          "Age", "Race", "Occupation", "Sector", "Marriatal status"};
MapIndexed[(headerNumber[#1] = #2[[1]]) &, header];
levelNames = Union /@ Transpose[data];
levelLength = Length /@ levelNames;
```

Now for the real stuff. It also uses the function `SelectEquivalents` defined in [What is in your Mathematica tool bag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/6245166#6245166)

```
pivotTableData[levelName1_, levelName2_, dependent_, op_] :=
 Table[
  SelectEquivalents[data,
    FinalFunction -> (If[Length[#] == 0, Missing["NotAvailable"], op[# // Flatten]] &),
    TagPattern -> 
        _?(#[[headerNumber[levelName1]]] == levelMember1 && 
           #[[headerNumber[levelName2]]] == levelMember2 &),
    TransformElement -> (#[[headerNumber[dependent]]] &)
   ],
   {levelMember1, levelNames[[headerNumber[levelName1]]]},
   {levelMember2, levelNames[[headerNumber[levelName2]]]}
 ]

DynamicModule[
 {opList = 
    {Mean ->"Mean of \[Rule]", Total ->"Sum of \[Rule]", Length ->"Count of \[Rule]",
     StandardDeviation -> "SD of \[Rule]", Min -> "Min of \[Rule]", 
     Max -> "Max of \[Rule]"
    }, t},
 Manipulate[
  t=Table["",{levelLength[[headerNumber[h1]]]+2},{levelLength[[headerNumber[h2]]]+2}];
  t[[3 ;; -1, 1]] = levelNames[[headerNumber[h1]]];
  t[[2, 3 ;; -1]] = levelNames[[headerNumber[h2]]];
  t[[1, 1]] = Control[{op, opList}];
  t[[1, 3]] = Control[{h2, header}];
  t[[2, 1]] = Control[{h1, header}];
  t[[1, 2]] = Control[{h3, header}];
  t[[3 ;; -1, 3 ;; -1]] = pivotTableData[h1, h2, h3, op] // N;
  TableView[t, Dividers -> All], 
  Initialization :> {op = Mean, h1 = "Sector", h2 = "Union", h3 = "Wage"}
  ]
 ]
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

There's still a bit of work to do. The `DynamicModule` should be turned into a fully standalone function, with the header stuff more streamlined, but this should be sufficient for a first impression.

Comment: +1 for a full implementation. (I didn't test it, but I trust you.)  One caveat though: it appears you use `SelectEquivalents` and IMO you need to include this definition in your post, since it is nonstandard and there are several versions about.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thought I'd leave it out as there were already some reference to this function in the other posts. I included a link to the toolbag version now.

Comment: I would make it easy on myself ( and the customer's bill ) by using Excel but you nicely show there aren't much limitations to mma as a programming language. - How do we tell that to the world?

Comment: Cool! Been waiting to hear more about `TableView` since its accidential discovery by some folks in MathGroup more than a year ago ( http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Oct/msg00186.html) It still undocumented in Version 8.0.4. Any news/updates/new hacks on this much-needed feature?

Comment: @kguler No, other than its use being signalled during one of the presentations of the recent virtual conference. I used it here for a more Excel-like look. I used `Grid` initially.

Answer (score 4):

@Mr.Wizard's answer is indeed robust and long-lasting as it grounds on ReapSow method suitable for some map reduce jobs in Mathematica. Due to the fact that MMA itself develops, consider a new option as well.

**GroupBy** (introduced in *Mathematica* v.10.0) provides a generalization of the **map reduce** operation.

So, the above `data` job may be implemented as follows (partly an overkill for readability):

```
headings = Union @ data[[All, #]] & /@ {1, 4}
```

> {{"East", "North", "South", "West"}, {"01/2011", "02/2011", "03/2011",
>      "04/2011", "05/2011", "06/2011", "07/2011", "08/2011", "09/2011", 
>     "10/2011", "11/2011", "12/2011"}}

We may use **Outer** to set up a rectangular template for `TableForm`:

```
template = Outer[List, Apply[Sequence][headings]];
```

Main job with **GroupBy** and **Total** as third argument:

```
pattern = Append[Normal @
 GroupBy[data, (#[[{1, 4}]] &) -> (#[[-1]] &), Total], 
 _ -> Null];
```

Finally, inject pattern into template (and apply TableForm headings for beauty):

```
TableForm[Replace[template, pattern, {2}], TableHeadings -> headings]
```

This outputs some:

[image]

**Note**: we have made a total of last column in `data`. (Many other aggregations are, of course, possible.)

Answer (score 3):

Use http://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/excel_link/ , this way you have the best of both worlds. This product creates a flawless link between Excel and mma, 2-ways.

Comment: That product doesn't seem to have been updated for version 8 of Mathematica. I also wonder how it would handle the `.xlsx` format.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I've come up with. It uses the function SelectEquivalents defined in [What is in your Mathematica tool bag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/6245166#6245166). Function1 and Function2 are meant to have different grouping possibilities of criteria1 and criteria2. FilterFunction is here in order to define an arbitrary filter formula on the data based on the header names.

Using the data example of Mr. Wizard here are some usages of this function.

```
criteria={"Region", "Gender", "Style", "Ship Date", "Units", "Price", "Cost"};
criteria1 = "Region";
criteria2 = "Ship Date";
consideredData = "Units";

PivotTable[data,criteria,criteria1,criteria2,consideredData]
```

A neat example

```
function2 = If[ToExpression@StringTake[#, 2] <= 6, "First Semester", "Second Semester"] &;
PivotTable[data,criteria,criteria1,criteria2,consideredData,FilterFunction->("Gender"=="Girl"&&"Units"*"Price"<=100&),Function2->function2]
```

Here's the definition of the function

```
keysToIndex[keys_] :=
   Module[{keyIndex},
      (keyIndex[#1] = #2[[1]])&~MapIndexed~keys;
      keyIndex
   ];

InverseFlatten[l_,dimensions_]:= Fold[Partition[#, #2] &, l, Most[Reverse[dimensions]]];

Options[PivotTable]={Function1->Identity,Function2->Identity,FilterFunction->(True &),AggregationFunction->Total,FormatOutput->True};

PivotTable[data_,criteria_,criteria1_,criteria2_,consideredData_,OptionsPattern[]]:=
    Module[{criteriaIndex, criteria1Index, criteria2Index, consideredDataIndex, criteria1Function, criteria2Function, filterFunctionTranslated, filteredResult, keys1, keys1Index, keys2, keys2Index, resultTable, function1, function2, filterFunction, aggregationFunction, formatOutput,p,sharp},

    function1 = OptionValue@Function1;
    function2 = OptionValue@Function2;
    filterFunction = OptionValue@FilterFunction;
    aggregationFunction = OptionValue@AggregationFunction;
    formatOutput=OptionValue@FormatOutput;  

    criteriaIndex=keysToIndex[criteria];

    criteria1Index=criteriaIndex@criteria1;
    criteria2Index=criteriaIndex@criteria2;
    consideredDataIndex=criteriaIndex@consideredData;

    criteria1Function=Composition[function1,#[[criteria1Index]]&];
    criteria2Function=Composition[function2,#[[criteria2Index]]&];
    filterFunctionTranslated = filterFunction/.(# -> p[sharp, criteriaIndex@#]& /@ criteria /. sharp -> #)/.p->Part;

    filteredResult=
        SelectEquivalents[
            data
            ,
            TagElement->({criteria1Function@#,criteria2Function@#,filterFunctionTranslated@#}&)
            ,
            TransformElement->(#[[consideredDataIndex]]&)
            ,
            TagPattern->_?(#[[3]]&)
            ,
            TransformResults->(Append[Most@#1,aggregationFunction@#2]&)
        ];

    If[formatOutput,
        keys1=filteredResult[[All,1]]//Union//Sort;
        keys2=filteredResult[[All,2]]//Union//Sort;
        resultTable=
           SelectEquivalents[
              filteredResult
              ,
              TagElement->(#[[{1,2}]]&)
              ,
              TransformElement->(#[[3]]&)
              ,
              TagPattern->Flatten[Outer[List, keys1, keys2], 1]
              ,
              FinalFunction-> (InverseFlatten[Flatten[#/.{}->Missing[]],{Length@keys1,Length@keys2}]&)
           ];

        TableForm[resultTable,TableHeadings->{keys1,keys2}]
        ,
        filteredResult
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 1):

I little latter in the game. Here is another self contained solution with object like form.

Using random data created by @Mr.Wizard:

```
    key = # -> #2[[1]] & ~MapIndexed~
       {"Region", "Gender", "Style", "Ship Date", "Units", "Price", "Cost"};
choices = {
   {"North", "South", "East", "West"},
   {"Boy", "Girl"},
   {"Tee", "Golf", "Fancy"},
   IntegerString[#, 10, 2] <> "/2011" & /@ Range@12,
   Range@15,
   Range[8.00, 15.00, 0.01],
   Range[6.00, 14.00, 0.01]
   };
data = RandomChoice[#, 5000] & /@ choices // Transpose;
```

Using an `MapIndexed` and `SparseArray` as key functions, here is the code:

```
Options[createPivotTable]={"RowColValueHeads"-> {1,2,3},"Function"-> Total};
createPivotTable[data_,opts:OptionsPattern[{createPivotTable}]]:=Module[{r,c,v,aggDataIndex,rowRule,colRule,pivot},

    {r,c,v}=OptionValue["RowColValueHeads"];

    pivot["Row"]= Union@data[[All,r]];
    pivot["Col"]= Union@data[[All,c]];

    rowRule= Dispatch[#->#2[[1]]&~MapIndexed~pivot["Row"]];
    colRule= Dispatch[#->#2[[1]]&~MapIndexed~pivot["Col"]];

    aggDataIndex={#[[1,r]]/.rowRule,#[[1,c]]/.colRule}->OptionValue["Function"]@#[[All,v]]&/@GatherBy[data,#[[{r,c}]]&];

    pivot["Data"]=Normal@SparseArray@aggDataIndex;
    pivot["Properties"]={"Data","Row","Col"};
    pivot["Table"]=TableForm[pivot["Data"], TableHeadings -> {pivot["Row"], pivot["Col"]}];
    Format[pivot]:="PivotObject";
    pivot
]
```

That you can use as:

```
pivot=createPivotTable[data,"RowColValueHeads"-> ({"Ship Date","Region","Units"}/.key)];
pivot["Table"]
pivot["Data"]
pivot["Row"]
pivot["Col"]
```

To get:
[image]

I believe that the speed is faster than @Ms.Wizard, but I have to make a better test, and don't have time now.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I believe that this is a nice question to be migrated into MathematicaSE.