# Mathematica fast 2D binning algorithm

Tags: performance, algorithm, wolfram-mathematica, bin, binning

I am having some trouble developing a suitably fast binning algorithm in Mathematica. I have a large (~100k elements) data set of the form 
    T={{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2},....}
and I want to bin it into a 2D array of around 100x100 bins, with the bin value being given by the sum of the Z values that fall into each bin.

Currently I am iterating through each element of the table, using Select to pick out which bin it is supposed to be in based on lists of bin boundaries, and adding the z value to a list of values occupying that bin. At the end I map Total onto the list of bins, summing their contents (I do this because I sometimes want to do other things, like maximize).

I have tried using Gather and other such functions to do this but the above method was ridiculously faster, though perhaps I am using Gather poorly. Anyway It still takes a few minutes to do the sorting by my method and I feel like Mathematica can do better. Does anyone have a nice efficient algorithm handy?

Comment: Please post the code you are already using, otherwise it is hard to know if a solution with e.g. `Gather` is actually an improvement.

Comment: Let me see if I have this right:  you are binning Z values by their corresponding X and Y values, correct?

Comment: Are `x,y,z` reals or integers?  If `z` is an integer, there may be simpler ways: `BinCounts[Join @@ (ConstantArray[{#1, #2}, #3] & @@@ data)]`

Comment: @Szabolcs, I do not understand your comment above.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I mean that *if* the meaning of `z` is a "count" of something, then we might as well multiply each entry `z` times and use the built-in and fast `BinCounts` function.

Comment: @Szabolcs, (1) what if Z values are large? (2) is `BinCounts` really faster?  It used to be very slow.  In v7 it is better, but still not superlative.  How is it in v8?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard If `z` is large then this is simply a bad solution!!  I knew the old, package-provided `BinCounts` used to be pretty slow, but I thought it got fixed in the new version ... I remember I had a custom implementation of 2D bin counting (from the v5 era) that was much faster for my use case than the one from the package, but I can't find it now.  Do you have your own optimized version to test against the built-in v8 `BinCounts`?  I'm curious about this.

Comment: @Szabolcs, no, nothing robust, and not 2D.  It would be interesting to explore this, but not right now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a method based on Szabolcs's post that is about about an order of magnitude faster.

```
data = RandomReal[5, {500000, 3}];
(*500k values*)
zvalues = data[[All, 3]];

epsilon = 1*^-10;(*prevent 101 index*)
(*rescale and round (x,y) coordinates to index pairs in the 1..100 range*)
indexes = 1 + Floor[(1 - epsilon) 100 Rescale[data[[All, {1, 2}]]]];

res2 = Module[{gb = GatherBy[Transpose[{indexes, zvalues}], First]}, 
    SparseArray[
     gb[[All, 1, 1]] -> 
      Total[gb[[All, All, 2]], {2}]]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Gives about {2.012217, Null}

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 System`SetSystemOptions[ 
  "SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> 1}];
 res3 = SparseArray[indexes -> zvalues];
 System`SetSystemOptions[ 
  "SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> 0}];
 ]
```

Gives about {0.195228, Null}

```
res3 == res2
True
```

"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> 1 adds duplicate positions up.

Comment: could you expand a bit on "adds duplicate positions up"? I am having trouble understanding what it does.

Comment: If you have rules {2,3}->1, {2,3}->10 and, say, {2,3}->2 the value at mat[[2,3]] will be 1+10+2; "TreatRepeatedEntries" means to add up the value if position entries are repeated. The default behavior of SparseArray is to not do that. TreatRepeatedEntries"->1 activates that feature - with this you can write very efficient code.

Comment: Why are these kinds of things undocumented?  You showed SparseArray properties before, and I believe I asked if there were other similar useful undocumented features, but this was not forthcoming.  Since these are not in the official documentation, but you are willing to divulge them, would you please consider putting together an index of these hidden but powerful methods?

Comment: You want unfinished options to be documented? No, this is not going to happen. And clearly ->number is not a finished design. But even if that were ->True/False, then still it does not get the full generality conceivable.

Comment: Id did show this on several occasions, at least once on MathGroup: http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Dec/msg00335.html.

Comment: I only noticed this reply now.  I wish this were an option to SparseArray instead of a system option.

Answer (score 5):

I intend to do a rewrite of the code below because of Szabolcs' readability concerns.  Until then, know that if your bins are regular, and you can use `Round`, `Floor`, or `Ceiling` (with a second argument) in place of `Nearest`, the code below will be much faster.  On my system, it tests faster than the `GatherBy` solution also posted.

---

Assuming I understand your requirements, I propose:

```
data = RandomReal[100, {75, 3}];

bins = {0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100};

Reap[
  Sow[{#3, #2}, bins ~Nearest~ #] & @@@ data,
  bins,
  Reap[Sow[#, bins ~Nearest~ #2] & @@@ #2, bins, Tr@#2 &][[2]] &
][[2]] ~Flatten~ 1 ~Total~ {3} // MatrixForm
```

---

Refactored:

```
f[bins_] := Reap[Sow[{##2}, bins ~Nearest~ #]& @@@ #, bins, #2][[2]] &

bin2D[data_, X_, Y_] := f[X][data, f[Y][#2, #2~Total~2 &] &] ~Flatten~ 1 ~Total~ {3}
```

Use:

```
bin2D[data, xbins, ybins]
```

Comment: @Szabolcs, can you suggest how I might make it more readable?

Comment: I will once I figure out why it doesn't give the same result as mine ... those numbers in `bins`, they are the *centres* of the bins, right?

Comment: @Szabolcs, As you can see I am using Nearest, so you can deduce that part yourself, but if I am not mistaken, yes.  Also, it is entirely possible that it is simply dysfunctional. :o)

Comment: My first comment was just a cry of frustration, not directly aimed at you :-)  But seriously, I do think it's objectively hard to read (despite "easy to read" being a subjective and cultural thing, depending on what we're used to).  Take for example the line `Reap[Sow[#1, bins~Nearest~#2] & @@@ #2, bins, Tr@#2 &]`.  There are three occurrences of `#2`, each of which are arguments of a different function.  There's the misleading use of `Tr` as a shorthand for `Total`.  Unorthodox use of inline notation.

Comment: All these put together, plus the need to consult the docs on features I use less often (like the second arg of `Total`), are just too overwhelming.  Of course the refactoring helps.  I still think that deciphering this will pose a considerable difficulty for anyone who's not an experienced user.

Comment: These comments are not about the method, but about the notation.  Breaking it down to pieces always helps (you already did that).  My only suggestion is to describe what `f` does, including both of its arguments, perhaps through a small out-of-context example.

Comment: By all means, do keep the method, just please make it less effort for us to understand what's going on :-)

Comment: @Szabolcs I shall.  You did not respond to my question about irregular bins.  Do you think that based on the question it is reasonable to assume that bins are regular?

Comment: The OP said "array of around 100x100 bins", which *suggests* regular ones, but he also said "based on lists of bin boundaries" which suggests irregular ones.  We have solutions for both, let's wait until he comes back and tells us what he needs.  As I understood, the bin-boundary list was an implementation detail, and not a required input.  Otherwise I think the fastest regular-bin method would be one that can be `Compile`d to efficient C code.

Comment: I'd like to suggest a change. Using `Nearest` is fine, but it must do a lot of preprocessing every time it is used. I'd suggest wrapping everything in `f` with `With[{nn=Nearest[bins]}, ...]` and use `nn[#]` instead of `bins ~Nearest~ #`. This does all the preprocessing required once, and on my machine over 10^6 points it shaves off nearly 7 seconds.

Comment: On my machine, using `NeighborFunction` this takes 10.8 secs (17.6 secs, without `NeighborFunction`). Szalbolcs solutions take 2.56 secs and 1.99 secs, respectively. So, a distinct improvement, but still not in the same class.

Comment: @rcollyer That's a good suggestion.  I forgot about that function.  If you use e.g. `Floor[_, 20]` instead of Nearest, how do the timings compare?

Comment: Now running v.8.0.4, 22.96 secs for original form, 11.21 secs for my form, and 7.33 secs for `Floor` form.

Comment: Slower on version 8 then?  I have seen other timings go up from v7 to v8, which is one of the reasons I still use v7.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard How could I convert your solution into one which calculates the meanvalue instead of the sum?

Answer (score 4):

Here's my approach:

```
data = RandomReal[5, {500000, 3}]; (* 500k values *)

zvalues = data[[All, 3]];

epsilon = 1*^-10; (* prevent 101 index *)

(* rescale and round (x,y) coordinates to index pairs in the 1..100 range *)    
indexes = 1 + Floor[(1 - epsilon) 100 Rescale[data[[All, {1, 2}]]]];

(* approach 1: create bin-matrix first, then fill up elements by adding  zvalues *)
res1 = Module[
    {result = ConstantArray[0, {100, 100}]},
    Do[
      AddTo[result[[##]], zvalues[[i]]] & @@ indexes[[i]], 
      {i, Length[indexes]}
    ];
    result
    ]; // Timing

(* approach 2: gather zvalues by indexes, add them up, convert them to a matrix *)
res2 = Module[{gb = GatherBy[Transpose[{indexes, zvalues}], First]},
    SparseArray[gb[[All, 1, 1]] -> (Total /@ gb[[All, All, 2]])]
    ]; // Timing

res1 == res2
```

These two approaches (`res1` & `res2`) can handle 100k and 200k elements per second, respectively,  on this machine.  Is this sufficiently fast, or do you need to run this whole program in a loop?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the long form of `AddTo` and `Part`?

Comment: I fixed `Part`.  With `AddTo`, it just avoids some parenthesis.  I tend to use this form when I put `Set` inside a `Function`, but I don't have strong feelings about the style.

Comment: This appears to be much faster than what I did, but can you easily handle irregular bins?  (I used `Nearest` for this reason.)

Comment: Total /@ gb[[All, All, 2]] is equivalent to Total[gb[[All, All, 2]], {2}].

Answer (score 3):

Here's my approach using the function SelectEquivalents defined in [What is in your Mathematica tool bag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/6245166#6245166) which is perfect for a problem like this one.

```
data = RandomReal[100, {75, 3}];
bins = Range[0, 100, 20];
binMiddles = (Most@bins + Rest@bins)/2;
nearest = Nearest[binMiddles];

SelectEquivalents[
   data
   ,
   TagElement -> ({First@nearest[#[[1]]], First@nearest[#[[2]]]} &)
   ,
   TransformElement -> (#[[3]] &)
   ,
   TransformResults -> (Total[#2] &)
   ,
   TagPattern -> Flatten[Outer[List, binMiddles, binMiddles], 1]
   , 
   FinalFunction -> (Partition[Flatten[# /. {} -> 0], Length[binMiddles]] &)
]
```

If you would want to group according to more than two dimensions you could use in FinalFunction this function to give to the list result the desired dimension (I don't remember where I found it).

```
InverseFlatten[l_,dimensions_]:= Fold[Partition[#, #2] &, l, Most[Reverse[dimensions]]];
```

Comment: As I mentioned on Mr.Wizard's solution, you'll want to use `NearestFunctions` instead of reinvoking `Nearest` everytime. In other words, calculate `Nearest[xbins]` and `Nearest[ybins]` first, and you get a non-trivial speed-up.

Comment: Also, why `TransformResults -> (Append[#1, Total[#2]] &)` instead of `TransformResults -> ({#1, Total[#2]} &)`?

Comment: Because #1 is a list and I want a "plotable" result.

Comment: Absolutely. I should have seen that myself.

Comment: The OP is talking about lists of bin *boundaries*. You are using lists of bin *midpoints*.

Comment: @Sjoerd I made the same mistake.  But, the OP has not returned to clarify the question, so I still do not know if we are dealing with regular or irregular bins.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I noticed, but your list of comments was already pretty long ;-) BTW did I tell you

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Hah! Got you pondering there, didn't I? Got to get some sleep first. Maybe tomorrow  ;-)

Comment: @Sjoerd I corrected my answer to match the bin definition. Also I managed to use the idea of Mr.Wizard to have a multi-dimensional grouping using the pattern argument of Reap, thus I use one Reap instead of several like Mr.Wizard. I already had this problem in the PivotTable question I had asked, I'm happy to have found how to do it using SelectEquivalents as I tend to often use this function.