# Coefficient function is slow

Tags: performance, wolfram-mathematica, expand

Please consider:

```
Clear[x]
expr = Sum[x^i, {i, 15}]^30;

CoefficientList[expr, x]; // Timing
Coefficient[Expand@expr, x, 234]; // Timing
Coefficient[expr, x, 234]; // Timing
```

```
{0.047, Null}
```

```
{0.047, Null}
```

```
{4.93, Null}
```

Help states:

> `Coefficient` works whether or not expr is explicitly given in expanded form.

#### Is there a reason why `Coefficient` needs to be so slow in the last case?

Comment: Perhaps `Coefficient`'s algorithm trades off speed for space, to be able to work on expressions with an extremely long expanded form?  BTW your computer is 4.5 times faster than mine.

Comment: @Szabolcs I suppose that makes sense; I'll try to test it. I could hope for a more intelligent method selection process if that's the case.  If you are using version 8, can you also try the test in version 7?  I have a suspicion that at least some things are slower in 8.

Comment: I don't have a v7 install handy now ..

Comment: @Szabolcs It's also 4 times slower on mine (v8), so I would guess it's a version difference.

Comment: @Szabolcs I can confirm your hypothesis, at lest in that `Coefficient` is far more memory efficient on `(1 + x)^50000`.  Is there anything reasonable I can do to make a generalized function that calls `Coefficient` faster?  Is there some kind of semi-expanded form, or `Method` option that that would give me a balance between these options?

Comment: With larger expression situation is even worse. With `expr = Sum[x^i, {i, 30}]^20;` there's a factor of 670 between them. I don't notice much difference as far as memory usage is concerned, but the system monitor isn't very sensitive.

Comment: @Sjoerd thanks for testing.   Please try with sample:  `(1 + x)^50000` or similar.

Comment: Did you see the other weird version difference (between 8.0.x and 8.0.4), [here](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/374/river-detection-in-text/682#comment1545_682)?  Belisarius's solution doesn't work as-is on 8.0.4, apparently due to a change in `Radon[]`

Comment: Got 20% to 30% slower results on 8.0.4 when compared with 7.0.1 (but still half the speed of Mr.Wizard...)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Coefficient` will not expand unless it deems it absolutely necessary to do so. This does indeed avoid memory explosions. I believe it has been this way since version 3 (I think I was working on it around 1995 or so).

It can also be faster to avoid expansion. Here is a simple example.

```
In[28]:= expr = Sum[x^i + y^j + z^k, {i, 15}, {j, 10}, {k, 20}]^20;

In[29]:= Coefficient[expr, x, 234]; // Timing

Out[29]= {0.81, Null}
```

But this next appears to hang in version 8, and takes at least a half minute in the development Mathematica (where `Expand` was changed).

```
Coefficient[Expand[expr], x, 234]; // Timing
```

Possibly some heuristics should be added to look for univariates that will not explode. Does not seem like a high priority item though.

Daniel Lichtblau

Answer (score 12):

Here is a hack which may enable your code to be fast, but I don't guarantee it to always work correctly:

```
ClearAll[withFastCoefficient];
SetAttributes[withFastCoefficient, HoldFirst];
withFastCoefficient[code_] :=
   Block[{Binomial},
     Binomial[x_, y_] := 10 /; ! FreeQ[Stack[_][[-6]], Coefficient];
     code]
```

Using it, we get:

```
In[58]:= withFastCoefficient[Coefficient[expr,x,234]]//Timing
Out[58]= {0.172,3116518719381876183528738595379210}
```

The idea is that, `Coefficient` is using `Binomial` internally to estimate the number of terms, and then expands (calls `Expand`) if the number of terms is less than `1000`, which you can check by using `Trace[..., TraceInternal->True]`. And when it does not expand, it computes lots of sums of large coefficient lists dominated by zeros, and this is apparently slower than expanding, for a range of expressions. What I do is to fool `Binomial` into returning a small number (`10`), but I also tried to make it such that it will only affect the `Binomial` called internally by `Coefficient`:

```
In[67]:= withFastCoefficient[f[Binomial[7,4]]Coefficient[expr,x,234]]
Out[67]= 3116518719381876183528738595379210 f[35]
```

I can not however guarantee that there are no examples where `Binomial` somewhere else in the code will be computed incorrectly.

**EDIT**

Of course, a safer alternative that always exists is to redefine `Coefficient` using the  [Villegas - Gayley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/5149656#5149656) trick, expanding an expression inside it and calling it again:

```
Unprotect[Coefficient];
Module[{inCoefficient},
   Coefficient[expr_, args__] :=
      Block[{inCoefficient = True},
         Coefficient[Expand[expr], args]] /; ! TrueQ[inCoefficient]
];
Protect[Coefficient];
```

**EDIT 2**

My first suggestion had an advantage that we defined a macro which modified the properties of functions locally, but disadvantage that it was unsafe. My second suggestion is safer but modifies `Coefficient` globally, so it will *always* expand until we remove that definition. We can have the best of both worlds with the help of  [`` Internal`InheritedBlock ``](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/5686710#5686710), which creates a local copy of a given function. Here is the code:

```
ClearAll[withExpandingCoefficient];
SetAttributes[withExpandingCoefficient, HoldFirst];
withExpandingCoefficient[code_] :=
   Module[{inCoefficient},
      Internal`InheritedBlock[{Coefficient},
         Unprotect[Coefficient];
         Coefficient[expr_, args__] :=
            Block[{inCoefficient = True},
               Coefficient[Expand[expr], args]] /; ! TrueQ[inCoefficient];
         Protect[Coefficient];
         code
      ]
   ];
```

The usage is similar to the first case:

```
In[92]:= withExpandingCoefficient[Coefficient[expr,x,234]]//Timing
Out[92]= {0.156,3116518719381876183528738595379210}
```

The main `Coefficient` function remains unaffected however:

```
In[93]:= DownValues[Coefficient]
Out[93]= {}
```

Comment: +1 for the reverse engineering work and analysis, but isn't this really the same as manually expanding first, but unsafe?  Or is it still more memory efficient than that (i.e. does the internal decision to expand or not to expand refer to the whole expression, or parts only)?

Comment: @Szabolcs I just edited to add the other possibility (expansion) before seeing your comment. It is probably the same memory - wise, and when Coefficient expands, it expands all expression (as far as I can tell). My first solution is more for an illustration. I will add the second one based on Gayley - Villegas trick shortly.

Answer (score 9):

```
expr = Sum[x^i, {i, 15}]^30; 

scoeff[ex_, var_, n_] /; PolynomialQ[ex, var] := 
   ex + O[var]^(n + 1) /. 
    Verbatim[SeriesData][_, 0, c_List, nmin_, nmax_, 1] :> 
     If[nmax - nmin != Length[c], 0, c[[-1]]]; 

Timing[scoeff[expr, x, 234]]
```

seems quite fast, too.

Comment: +1. It is actually several times faster for larger expressions, than solutions based on expanding an expression. Moreover, it is dramatically faster for smaller-index coefficients, since it effectively seems to expand only the part of expression up to a specified term (power).

Comment: SeriesData is really very nicely implemented in Mathematica. So anything one can do with SeriesData is blazingly fast (even faster than FORM (http://www.nikhef.nl/~form/)).

Comment: Rolf Mertig, I am compelled to accept this answer, as it is concise and efficacious.  However, I do not really understand it.  Would you please explain it in the simplest terms possible?

Comment: Specifically I do not understand: `ex + O[var]^(n + 1)`

Comment: It is just a Taylor expansion which makes sense here since the higher powers in x are not needed. The speedup comes from the fact that SeriesData is implemented efficiently in Mathematica. See also: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/O.html

Comment: Thank you.  Pardon me for un-Accept-ing your answer, but I think I found an easier method, inspired by yours.  I will wait for peer review on that answer.

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation following Rolf Mertig's answer, this appears to be the fastest method on the type of expression such as `Sum[x^i, {i, 15}]^30`:

```
SeriesCoefficient[expr, {x, 0, 234}]
```

Comment: Note that this answers somewhat different question from what you originally asked: you asked about the reasons why `Coefficient` is slow (emphasis on `Coefficient` and "why slow"), not what are possible faster substitutes for it.

Comment: @Leonid very good point.  I had forgotten that after reading the various answers.  I suppose Daniel's reply is most direct; should I accept that?  Also, what do you think of this method?  Are there any obvious problems with it?

Comment: Sorry, I can't advise on which answer you accept - this is entirely up to you. Daniel's answer is very good, brief and to the point. As to the method - I don't see obvious problems, but alas have no time right now to play with it.

Comment: @Leonid You are sounding quite diplomatic.  Okay.