# Replacing a sublist with first item in sublist

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm pretty new to Mathematica and am stumped by this problem. I have a list that looks like this:

```
{{1, 1, 1}, {0}, {1}}
```

I want to replace each sublist with its first element. So, the above list should be converted to:

```
{1,0,1}
```

I've looked through the documentation repeatedly and Googled for hours. I'm sure that this is fairly simple, but I can't figure it out. I started with this list:

```
{1, 1, 1, 0, 1}
```

I need to know how many runs of 1's there are, which is obviously 2. So, I used Split to separate the list into groups of consecutive 1's and 0's. By using Length on this list I can get the total number of runs, which is 3. Now, I just need to calculate the number of runs of 1's. If I can convert the list as mentioned above, I can just sum the items in the list to get the answer.

I hope that makes sense. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd do this:

```
Count[Split[{1, 1, 1, 0, 1}][[All, 1]], 1]
```

or

```
Total[First /@ Split[{1, 1, 1, 0, 1}]]
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! I had tried [All, 1] to access the sublists, but I couldn't figure out the pattern to count. So, the pattern is simply the 1, right?

Comment: Yes, in this case the pattern is the literal 1.

Answer (score 12):

The proposed solutions are pretty fast, however if you want extreme efficiency (huge lists), here is another one which would be order of magnitude faster (formulated as a pure function):

```
Total[Clip[Differences@#,{0, 1}]] + First[#] &
```

For example:

```
In[86]:= 
largeTestList = RandomInteger[{0,1},{10^6}];
Count[Split[largeTestList],{1..}]//Timing
Count[Split[largeTestList][[All,1]],1]//Timing
Total[Clip[Differences@#,{0, 1}]] + First[#] &@largeTestList//Timing

Out[87]= {0.328,249887}
Out[88]= {0.203,249887}
Out[89]= {0.015,249887}
```

**EDIT**

I did not indend to initiate the "big shootout", but while we are at it, let me pull the biggest gun - compilation to C:

```
runsOf1C = 
 Compile[{{lst, _Integer, 1}},
   Module[{r = Table[0, {Length[lst] - 1}], i = 1, ctr = First[lst]},
    For[i = 2, i <= Length[lst], i++,
      If[lst[[i]] == 1 && lst[[i - 1]] == 0, ctr++]];
      ctr],
  CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
```

Now,

```
In[157]:= 
hugeTestList=RandomInteger[{0,1},{10^7}];
Total[Clip[ListCorrelate[{-1,1},#],{0,1}]]+First[#]&@hugeTestList//AbsoluteTiming
runsOf1C[hugeTestList]//AbsoluteTiming

Out[158]= {0.1872000,2499650}
Out[159]= {0.0780000,2499650}
```

Of course, this is not an elegant solution, but it is straightforward.

**EDIT 2**

Improving on the optimization of @Sjoerd, this one will be about 1.5 faster than `runsOf1C` still:

```
runsOf1CAlt = 
Compile[{{lst, _Integer, 1}},
  Module[{r = Table[0, {Length[lst] - 1}], i = 1, ctr = First[lst]},
    For[i = 2, i <= Length[lst], i++,
     If[lst[[i]] == 1,
      If[lst[[i - 1]] == 0, ctr++];
      i++
     ]];
    ctr],
  CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
```

Comment: Oooh, clever...  You can get a bit more speed by using `Tr` instead of `Total`. (20% on my Mac.)

Comment: That is impressive. So much so that I'll have to study it to figure out how it works. Fortunately, my lists won't likely exceed several thousand items.

Comment: @Brett Thanks for the hint! I keep forgetting about `Tr`, should move it to my "active" dictionary for Mathematica.

Comment: @TimMayes, don't feel bad, it took me some time to figure it out, also. I'd suggest looking at what `Differences` returns, first, then determining why `Clip` is needed.

Comment: Leonid I still think C is cheating.  If we wanted to write procedural code, why would we be using Mathematica?  (yes, this is officially sour grapes.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, I agree, this is cheating. But if someone goes as far as to be interested in playing with optimizations introduced by my, Sjoerd's or your solutions, one might as well be in need of the fastest one possible in Mathematica. The C one has an advantage that it is straightforward. It took me less than 5 minutes to write and test it, while to come up with other versions would be a lot harder - and this is counting my Mathematica experience. For most people, the C version is simpler. Won't win a beauty contest, that's for sure :)

Answer (score 8):

You have actually two questions, the one from the title and the question lurking behind it. The first one is answered by:

```
First/@ list
```

The second one, counting the number of runs of 1's, has been answered many times, but this solution

```
Total[Clip[ListCorrelate[{-1, 1}, #], {0, 1}]] + First[#] &
```

is about 50% faster than Leonid's solution. Note I increased the length of the test list for better timing:

```
largeTestList = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {10000000}];
Count[Split[largeTestList], {1 ..}] // AbsoluteTiming
Count[Split[largeTestList][[All, 1]], 1] // AbsoluteTiming
Total[Clip[Differences@#, {0, 1}]] + First[#] &@ largeTestList // AbsoluteTiming
(Tr@Unitize@Differences@# + Tr@#[[{1, -1}]])/2 &@ largeTestList // AbsoluteTiming
Total[Clip[ListCorrelate[{-1, 1}, #], {0, 1}]] + First[#] &@
  largeTestList // AbsoluteTiming


Out[680]= {3.4361965, 2498095}

Out[681]= {2.4531403, 2498095}

Out[682]= {0.2710155, 2498095}

Out[683]= {0.2530145, 2498095}

Out[684]= {0.1710097, 2498095}
```

---

After Leonid's compilation attack I was about to throw in the towel, but I spotted a possible  optimization, so onwards goes the battle... [Mr.Wizard, Leonid and I should be thrown in jail for disturbing the peace on SO]

```
runsOf1Cbis = 
 Compile[{{lst, _Integer, 1}}, 
  Module[{r = Table[0, {Length[lst] - 1}], i = 1, ctr = First[lst]}, 
   For[i = 2, i <= Length[lst], i++, 
    If[lst[[i]] == 1 && lst[[i - 1]] == 0, ctr++; i++]];
   ctr], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]

largeTestList = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {10000000}]; 
Total[Clip[ListCorrelate[{-1, 1}, #], {0, 1}]] + First[#] &@
    largeTestList // AbsoluteTiming
runsOf1C[largeTestList] // AbsoluteTiming
runsOf1Cbis[largeTestList] // AbsoluteTiming


Out[869]= {0.1770101, 2500910}

Out[870]= {0.0960055, 2500910}

Out[871]= {0.0810046, 2500910}
```

The results vary, but I get an improvement between 10 and 30%.

The optimization may be hard to spot, but it's the extra `i++` if the {0,1} test succeeds. You can't have two of these in successive locations.

---

And, here, an optimization of Leonid's optimization of my optimization of his optimization (I hope this isn't going to drag on, or I'm going to suffer a stack  overflow):

```
runsOf1CDitto = 
 Compile[{{lst, _Integer, 1}}, 
  Module[{i = 1, ctr = First[lst]}, 
   For[i = 2, i <= Length[lst], i++, 
    If[lst[[i]] == 1, If[lst[[i - 1]] == 0, ctr++];
     i++]];
   ctr], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]

largeTestList = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {10000000}]; 
Total[Clip[ListCorrelate[{-1, 1}, #], {0, 1}]] + First[#] &@
  largeTestList // AbsoluteTiming
runsOf1C[largeTestList] // AbsoluteTiming
runsOf1Cbis[largeTestList] // AbsoluteTiming
runsOf1CAlt[largeTestList] // AbsoluteTiming
runsOf1CDitto[largeTestList] // AbsoluteTiming


Out[907]= {0.1760101, 2501382}

Out[908]= {0.0990056, 2501382}

Out[909]= {0.0780045, 2501382}

Out[910]= {0.0670038, 2501382}

Out[911]= {0.0600034, 2501382}
```

Lucky for me, Leonid had a superfluous initialization in his code that could be removed.

Comment: +1. I had no idea that something can be faster than `Differences`, the latter being essentially `Rest[#]-Most[#]&`. Learned something new today :)

Comment: Ditto what Leonid said.  I would have to get really clever to beat that. :-)  (BTW, I am surprised there is not more difference between the two `Differences` methods; there is on my system.)

Comment: Actually, your method is much slower on v7.  I am going to add timings to my own post for reference.

Comment: @Mr.wizard Interesting. My timings are consistently giving me this 50% gain. Another reason to upgrade I'd say (v9 isn't anywhere near in sight).

Comment: On the other hand, it's slower in places too:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/8243627/618728

Comment: @Sjoerd, Mr.Wizard I updated my answer with a compiled-to-C version. Sorry, Sjoerd :). But you still hold a record for the most elegant of the fastest solutions.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Sjoerd Oops, I did not notice Mr.Wizard's solution based on `BitXor`. Sorry for not mentioning that one.

Comment: @Leonid Close, but no cigar ;-) See my latest update.  I hope we aren't overstaying our welcome...

Comment: Have you tried creating a C version of my Xor method?  I think it should be the fastest of all.

Comment: @Sjoerd Don't be so sure. You also missed one optimization, check my latest update :)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I tried, but it looks like `BitXor` does not compile to bytecode (or C). I did not try very hard though. Ultimately, we can write it in pure C and use the LibraryLink. In any case, I also expect  that it should be the fastest.

Comment: @Sjoerd Damn! I've got that from some older code! Ok, you got me man, I give up for now. But, I will be back :)

Comment: @Leonid, Sjoerd, I don't permit either of you to give up until you've tried a Xor method in C. (grin)

Comment: Thanks, I enjoyed this hilarious, over the top, battle-of-the-nerds.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Just pasting in your code in a Compile only made in take longer. Need to adapt it like Leonid's code.

Comment: @Sjoerd like Leonid suggested, it may take direct implementation in C.  But don't let that stop you... :->

Comment: @Brett Actually, this seems like a perfect problem for those - since we only look at two adjacent list elements at a time, it is easy to parallelize. Too bad my card isn't powerful enough to have real gains. Would be nice to measure on some new Tesla-s with 500 multiprocessors. But, OTOH, this is likely to be data-transfer bound. CUDA works best when the math-to-data-transfer ratio is high,  which is not the case here.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin did you see this: http://weaklyreachable.blogspot.com/2007/06/mathematica-pure-function-scope-problem_2182.html ?

Comment: @Sjoerd Oh yes, sure, I read parts of WReach's blog and found it very interesting. Regarding that particular problem, I have run into it independently several times, particularly expressed here:http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/115b073d95999ae8. His example is exposing the same effect, but is easier to grasp. I also discussed this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920194/using-nested-slots/4922776#4922776

Answer (score 7):

Here is a variation of Leonid's `Differences` method that is slightly faster:

```
(Tr@Unitize@Differences@# + Tr@#[[{1,-1}]])/2 &
```

Compared (using `Tr` for both):

```
list = RandomInteger[1, 1*^7];

Tr[Clip[Differences@#, {0,1}]] + First[#] & @ list //timeAvg

(Tr@Unitize@Differences@# + Tr@#[[{1,-1}]])/2 & @ list //timeAvg
```

```
0.1186
```

```
0.0904
```

---

Since this has become a code efficiency competition, here is my next effort:

```
(Tr@BitXor[Most@#, Rest@#] + Tr@#[[{1, -1}]])/2 &
```

Also, I am getting very different results using Mathematica 7, so I am including them here for reference:

```
largeTestList = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {10000000}];
Count[Split[largeTestList], {1 ..}] // AbsoluteTiming
Count[Split[largeTestList][[All, 1]], 1] // AbsoluteTiming
Total[Clip[Differences@#, {0, 1}]] + First[#] &@largeTestList // AbsoluteTiming
(Tr@Unitize@Differences@# + Tr@#[[{1, -1}]])/2 &@largeTestList // AbsoluteTiming
Total[Clip[ListCorrelate[{-1, 1}, #], {0, 1}]] + First[#] &@largeTestList // AbsoluteTiming
(Tr@BitXor[Most@#, Rest@#] + Tr@#[[{1, -1}]])/2 &@largeTestList // AbsoluteTiming

{1.3400766, 2499840}

{0.9670553, 2499840}

{0.1460084, 2499840}

{0.1070061, 2499840}

{0.3710213, 2499840}

{0.0480028, 2499840}
```

Comment: +1 I actually thought that something like this should be possible, but wasn't persistent enough :).

Comment: I suppose ListCorrelate must have been improved in mma 8.

Comment: @Sjoerd, how does my BitXor method compare on your machine?

Comment: It's 0.1340076 vs 0.1720098 in favor of BitXor

Comment: BTW Why  do you use Tr instead of Total? On my PC the latter is like 1% faster

Comment: @Sjoerd thanks.  `Tr` is fewer keystrokes and faster on packed arrays in v7.

Answer (score 6):

Another approach, using `Count` to look for lists containing some number of repetitions of 1:

```
In[20]:= Count[Split[{1, 1, 1, 0, 1}], {1 ..}]

Out[20]= 2
```

Comment: Thanks Brett. I swear that I tried something very close to that, but I kept getting errors on the pattern. I obviously had something wrong because your solution works.