# Set degrees as default in Mathematica 8

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Is it possible to set the trigonometric functions to use degrees instead of radians?

Comment: I wonder what the form of `Series[Sin[x ], {x, 0, 5}]` would be in that case

Comment: @belisarius, interesting question as the underlying mathematics is based upon radians.

Comment: @belisarius If x is in degrees, then wouldn't it just be `Series[Sin[x Degree], {x, 0, 5}]`?

Comment: @Brett Well, jut consider de `\[Degree]^n` terms that are there ... :)

Comment: @belisarius What about them?  \[Degree] is just a numerical constant equal to Pi/180.  If you prefer you can use `FunctionExpand[Series[Sin[x Degree], {x, 0, 5}]]` or `Series[Sin[x Pi/180], {x, 0, 5}]` instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Short answer**

No, this is not possible.  I'd suggest to define alternative functions, and work with those: `sinDeg[d_] := Sin[d Degree]`.  Or just use `Degree` explicitly: `Sin[30 Degree]`. (Try also entering `ESC deg ESC`.)

**Longer answer**

You can `Unprotect` the functions, and re-define them using the [Gayley-Villegas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5149656/695132) trick, but this is very likely to break several things in Mathematica, as I expect it is using these functions internally.

Since this is such a nasty thing to do, I'm not going to give a code example, instead I'll leave it to you to figure out based on my link above. :-)

Comment: Can I define the ´sinDeg` globally?

Comment: @Tyilo What do you mean by globally?  I'm not sure I follow.  If you want it to be defined on startup, look at [init.m](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/file/init.m.html)  But why not just use `Degree`, really?  Care to tell us your motivation?

Comment: @Tyilo: You could add the definitions into your [init.m](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/file/init.m.html) (or another file that's called by init.m). Then they would be available in every Mathematica session.

Answer (score 2):

I think the output is based on the input. So for example `Cos[60 Degree]` will output in degrees.

Comment: Additionally, you can use the shorthand `\[Degree]` which is replaced with a degree symbol and it may help readability.

Comment: A cosine won't have output in degrees. The output of an ArcCos would be an angle (be it in radians, not degrees).

Comment: @Sjoerd, do you want to continue discussing infix notation, or shall I let that topic rest in peace?