# Mathematica 8.0 efficient way to parse a DateList from a string in the format of yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have the following string: "20110103224832494" it is in the following format: yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS.  Where yyyy is the year, MM is the month, dd is the day, HH is the hour, mm is the minutes, ss is the seconds, SSS is the milliseconds.

I thought that the following would have worked:

```
DateList[{"20110103224832494",  
         {"Year", "Month", "Day", "Hour", "Minute", "Second", "Millisecond"}}
]
```

but returns:

```
DateString::str: String 20110103224832494 cannot be interpreted as a date in 
format {Year,Month,Day,Hour,Minute,Second,Millisecond}. >>
```

And if that worked, would it have been efficient?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Corrected to combine milliseconds with seconds.

You did specify "efficient" and I believe this is two orders of magnitude faster than `DateList`:

```
stringDynP[s_String, p_] :=
  StringTake[s, Thread@{{0}~Join~Most@# + 1, #} &@Accumulate@p]

toDateList[string_String] := 
  MapAt[#/1000` &, #, -1] &[
    FromDigits /@ stringDynP[string, {4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5}]
  ]

toDateList["20110103224832494"]
```

```
{2011, 1, 3, 22, 48, 32.494}
```

`stringDynP` is a string adaptation of [my "Dynamic Partition" function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5433867/618728).

---

#### Warning for *Mathematica 7* users:  the `DateList` method produces a spurious result:

```
{2011, 1, 12, 9, 23, 24.094}
```

---

Presumably in version 8 the following method can be used:

```
DateList[
 {"20110103224832494",
   {"Year", "Month", "Day", "Hour","Minute", "Second", "Millisecond"}},
 DateDelimiters -> None
]
```

Comment: Of course your result isn't actually a date list that can be used by other functions in Mathematica. :-)

Comment: @mmorris apparently the behavior of `DateList` was changed between versions 7 and 8, hence my bewilderment.  Please see my updated answer for what I believe is a correct and fast method.

Comment: Looks like a bug in `DateList` in version 7.  It seems to get confused when you add minutes into the specification...

Answer (score 10):

Use:

```
DateList[{"20110103224832494",  
   Riffle[{"Year",
           "Month", 
           "Day",   
           "Hour", 
           "Minute", 
           "Second", 
           "Millisecond"}, ""]}]
```

Comment: I didn't know about this one.  Nice.

Comment: `DateList[{"20110103224832494",  {"Year", "Month", "Day", "Hour", 
   "Minute", "Second", "", "Millisecond"}}]`  works too figured that out after posting question.

Comment: Why does it require to have an empty string interspersed with the rest of the date/time specification?

Comment: @rcollyer see `DateList` docs > More Information > last line.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I see that, but the question remains. Why isn't `{"Year", "", "Month"}` equivalent to `{"Year", "Month"}`?

Comment: @rcollyer, just above that: "... and can be separated by any non-alphanumeric characters."  If what you are really asking: "Why wasn't this make equivalent" (which is the sort of question I like to ask) then I don't know; perhaps it introduces an ambiguity.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, actually that is what I'm asking. More specifically, I'm asking, why do I need separators when there are none? I can see why it would be frustrating.

Comment: ***This apparently does not work on version 7***  Instead I get: `{2011, 1, 12, 9, 23, 24.094}`

Comment: How does mma know where to split the string?

Comment: @David, standard field length, I suppose?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard To me it was puzzling to intersperse empty strings between elements that were glommed together. But, why not?

Comment: @David, see the update to my answer above.  I find that a less puzzling way to write this.